# What should be learned in a first serious schemes course?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, big-list, schemes

I've just finished teaching a year-long ["foundations of algebraic
geometry" class](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/0910-216/).  It
was my third time teaching it, and my notes are gradually converging.
I've enjoyed it for a number of reasons (most of all the students, who
were smart, hard-working, and from a variety of fields).  I've
particularly enjoyed talking with experts (some in nearby fields, many
active on mathoverflow) about what one should (or must!) do in a first
schemes course. I've been pleasantly surprised to find that those who
have actually thought about teaching such a course (and hence who know
how little can be covered) tend to agree on what is important, even if
they are in very different parts of the subject.  I want to raise this
question here as well:

> What topics/examples/ideas etc. really really should be learned in a 
>   year-long first serious course in schemes?

Here are some constraints.  Certainly most excellent first courses
ignore some or all of these constraints, but I include them to focus
the answers.  The first course in question should be
purely algebraic.  (The reason for this constraint: to avoid a 
debate on which is *the* royal road to algebraic geometry --- this is
intended to be just *one* way in.  But if the community thinks that a
first course should be broader, this will be reflected in the voting.)
The course should be intended for people in all parts of algebraic
geometry.  It should attract smart people in nearby areas.  It should
not get people as quickly as possible into your particular area of
research.  Preferences: It can (and, I believe, must) be hard.  As
much as possible, essential things must be proved, with no handwaving
(e.g. "with a little more work, one can show that...", or using
exercises which are unreasonably hard).  Intuition should be given
when possible.

Why I'm asking:   I will likely edit the notes further, and hope to post 
them in chunks over the 2010-11 academic year to provoke further debate.  Some hastily-written thoughts are
[here](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/0910-216/FOAGevolution.html), 
if you are curious.

As usual for big-list questions: one topic per answer please.  There
is little point giving obvious answers (e.g. "definition of a
scheme"), so I'm particularly interested in things you think others
might forget or disagree with, or things often omitted, or things you
wish someone had told you when you were younger.  Or propose dropping
traditional topics, or a nontraditional ordering of traditional topics.  Responses
addressing prerequisites such as "it shouldn't cover any commutative
algebra, as participants should take a serious course in that subject
as a prerequisite" are welcome too.  As the most interesting
responses might challenge (or defend) conventional wisdom, please give
some argument or evidence in favor of your opinion.

**Update later in 2010:**  I am posting the notes, after suitable editing, and trying to take into account the advice below, [**here**](http://math216.wordpress.com/).  I hope to reach (near) the end some time in summer 2011.  **Update July 2011:** I have indeed reached near the end some time in summer 2011.

Comment: Dear Ravi, while I'm not sure if this _should_ be taught in a first schemes course, but it's something that I'd love to see exposited more fully.  Jim Borger gave an outline of a program to jump straight into algebraic spaces, skipping schemes entirely.  Maybe you could figure out a way to do it? http://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2009/08/06/algebraic-geometry-without-prime-ideals/#comment-6354

Comment: It's also worth linking to the meta discussion that Ravi started to help him craft this question before asking it: http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/446/questioncrafting-what-should-be-learned-in-a-first-serious-schemes-course

Comment: A parsing question: does "first serious schemes course" mean that there could be a prior, not-so-serious course on schemes?  Or do you mean "first, serious schemes course"?  

Comment: Hi Pete, that was deliberately vague.  There's a strong case for a varieties course before a schemes course. And the varieties course could be constructed so that schemes are secretly being set up.  (I tried to do this once, when teaching a one-semester course at MIT.)  Mumford's Red Book is great at this --- the way he does varieties makes schemes quite natural.  But what I really meant was "a first schemes course" and "a serious schemes course" separately:  not a second course where you see fancier things, nor a light introduction to schemes, nor a varieties class.

Comment: You say the students are "from a variety of fields". Did you mean various fields within mathematics or from other fields than mathematics? If the latter, I wonder which fields outside of mathematics make use of algebraic geometry?

Comment: I meant within mathematics.    There are some fields outside of mathematics that use algebraic geometry (or at least share ideas with it), and indeed some students in a class like this have been from either physics (of a theoretical sort) or computer science (of a theoretical sort).  But those students were definitely exceptional and far from typical!

Answer (score 89):

One of the wholly unnecessary reasons that schemes are regarded with such 
fear by so many mathematicians in other fields is that three, largely
orthogonal, generalizations are made simultaneously.

Considering a "variety" to be Spec or Proj of a domain finitely
generated over an algebraically closed field, the generalizations are
basically

1. Allowing nilpotents in the ring
2. Gluing affine schemes together
3. Working over a base ring that isn't an algebraically closed field
   (or even a field at all).

For many years I got by with only #1. More recently I've been interested
in #1 + #3. Presumably someday I'll care about #2, but not yet. 
Anyway I think it's crazy to give the impression that the three are a
package deal that one must buy all of simultaneously, rather than in
much easier installments.

I think it could be useful to explain which subfield of mathematics, or which important example, motivates which of #1,#2,#3 is really a necessary generalization.

Comment: The way I think about it is: #1 is analysis (looking at near-solutions $P_1(x)=\ldots=P_k(x)=O(\varepsilon)$ of equations instead of exact equations $P_1(x)=\ldots=P_k(x)=0$).  #2 is differential geometry (looking at manifolds instead of coordinate patches). #3 is number theory (solving equations over number fields, rings of integers, etc.).  This way I can minimise my exposure to algebra and topology, my two weakest suits. :-)

Comment: Allen, in what sense do you mean you've never cared about #2?  I'd have thought it is the basic ingredient by which one thinks about any non-affine object (akin to manifolds, as in Terry's comment), and so much more intuitive than #1 and #3?  I assume you are implicitly speaking of gluing in the Zariski topology rather than the etale topology (algebraic spaces...), but perhaps I misunderstand. 

Comment: I like these three a lot.  In each case things the new notion is forced upon you by nature.  I like Terry's interpretation (and like to note that certain notions are "geometry" or "arithmetic" --- I'd never used the word "analysis" for similar reasons to Terry's reasons for algebra and topology... :-).

What about #4:   non-closed points?  This could even bump out #2, which is already present in Proj.  Somehow this local-to-global issue is already present in how one thinks of a manifold (and even if people may not know it well at this stage, they have a good intuitive idea of it).

Comment: B, I mentioned Proj, which gets me projective schemes, or more generally schemes that are projective over affine. Basically the order of things for me starts with representation theory, therefore I care about vector spaces, which are more studiable if they're bundled together into rings, which one might then Spec or Proj. I imagine I would feel differently if my entry into the subject had been from e.g. complex manifolds, but if you think of algebraic geometry as a way to study commutative algebra then #2 is somewhat of a stretch. (BTW did you notice we're having a Princeton '92 moment here?)

Comment: A, now I see your point (though even for commutative algebra topics such as local cohomology of modules, non-affine schemes naturally arise as open complements of high-codim. closed subschemes of affine schemes when doing excision arguments -- very reminiscent of topological excision when expressed geometrically, even though the commutative algebraists can work with it purely algebraically). As for "Princeton '92 moment", yes I agree (but it took me a few minutes to remember because I misread '92 as '96). 

Comment: Yes, the class of '92 is everywhere... (I just bumped into Nike yesterday, for instance.)

Comment: @Terry: Oh yes, the number theory meeting at UCLA is going on this week, isn't it?  Nike will be up here in a couple of weeks at a more general math conference, where Ko will also be speaking. I should see if Nike remembers his trick/lemma with the basic open affines that is mentioned in another string of comments on this webpage (I reminded him about it a couple of years ago). In fact, it was Ko who dubbed it "Nike's trick". 

Comment: Excuse me gentlemen, but "Princeton class of '92" means the folks who graduated from there in '92, not who showed up there in '92. :) 

Comment: K, I know, but I'm not in any Princeton graduating class, and had only one character left in that comment.

Comment: The Princeton coclass of '92, then. :)

Comment: Incidentally, Andrei Okounkov (more Princeton!) expressed to me the view that a scheme is "just a ring".  I guess he's a #1+#3 guy rather than a #2 guy...

Comment: As a student who's only beginning to learn about schemes, I really like this division (it might be nice if it somehow found its way into the pedagogy).

I would add that what Speyer mentioned, the fact that the closed points of $Spec(k[x_1,\cdots,x_n])$ are in bijection with the orbits of $A(\overline{k})$ under $\mathrm{Gal}(\overline{k}/l)$ is the perfect motivation for #3. (When I realized this, it reminded me immediately of the definition of $k$-divisors in Silverman, which could include e.g. $(i)+(-i)$ as an $\mathbb{R}$-divisor on the affine line.)

Comment: Also, for #3, it's good to mention that, for example, two plane curves with ideals $I(X),I(Y)$ have a double point of intersection (geometrically, they have the same tangent line at that point) iff the ring $k[x_1,x_2]/(I(X),I(Y))$ contains nilpotents, and various other examples of the scheme-theoretic definition of intersection number.

Comment: Allen, I like this a lot.  The one additional generalization you didn't mention was #4:  "non-closed points".  But I can't think of a field to motivate it in the same way as Terry motivated #1-3. :-(

Comment: @RaviVakil I think of #4 as probability theory: working with "random" or "generic" solutions to a system of equations, rather than a specific (deterministic) solution.  Again, this reflects the fields of mathematics I am more comfortable with, though. (Here, probability has to be interpreted in a qualitative sense rather than a quantitative one: http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2013/11/16/qualitative-probability-theory-types-and-the-group-chunk-and-group-configuration-theorems/ )

Answer (score 56):

As you should, you prove the Nullstellensatz early on, as the statement that the closed points of $\mathbb{A}^n_k$ are in bijection with $k^n$, for $k$ an algebraically closed field. I wonder whether it is also a good idea to say that, for any $k$, the closed points of $\mathbb{A}^n_k$ are in bijection with the Galois orbits in $\overline{k}^n$. This might require too big a digression into Galois theory, but I remember a number of my grad school classmates having confusions about closed points over non-algebraically closed fields which could be immediately answered from this description.

Comment: I definitely second this.  I understood $\mathrm{Spec}\mathbb{R}[x]$ when someone said that it's just $\mathbb{C}$ modulo conjugation.  And I think it's fair to assume that people learning schemes have some Galois theory from grad algebra (just like you assume they know what a topological space is, because if they don't, things have gone horribly awry)

Comment: @David: +1! $  $

Comment: David, great ideas.I currently *state* the Nullst. early on, but because the proof will fall out of things later (Noether normalization), I hold off proving it.  I definitely do the Galois-conjugate thing --- if you don't know what the points are of a space, you can get very confused!  (Aside:  it is interesting that we can quickly describe the primes in $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ for $n=0,1,2$, but for $n=3$ there are weirder sorts of primes --- and there is no way of not thinking of them in terms of geometry.)  Charles, doing the explicit case of $\mathbb{R}[x]$ makes lots of sense.

Comment: @Ravi: Zariski's lemma (Any finitely generated algebra over a field that is also a field is algebraic) gives a remarkably quick proof of the Nullstellensatz.  Lang's algebra gives a version of this proof, or you could look up the original paper of Zariski on this method as well.  In fact, Zariski's lemma is a corollary of Zariski's main theorem (the general form) as well.  

Comment: @Harry: the suggestion to view Zariski's Lemma as a corollary of Zariski's Main Theorem sounds dangerously close to (if not actually) being circular, since I can't imagine developing algebraic geometry even remotely far enough to get to ZMT without already knowing the Nullstellensatz (which is more or less equivalent to Zariski's Lemma, depending on how one defines "Nullstellensatz"). 

Comment: Yes, this was meant as an attempt at very dry humor.

Answer (score 50):

I found differentials hard to understand when I learned this material. Here are two things that helped me which I think are not in your notes:

(1) The description of the Zariski tangent space to $X$ at $x$ as those Hom's from $\mathrm{Spec} \ k[\epsilon]/\epsilon^2$ to $X$ which take $\mathrm{Spec} \ k$ to $x$. This is much closer to my physical intuition for a tangent space than the $(\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2)^{\vee}$ definition. It is also an early example of the power of using rings with nilpotents. Building the vector space structure from this definition is especially pretty.

(2) A careful discussion of the relationship between the infinitesimal objects, *i.e.* the elements of the Zariski tangent and cotangent spaces, and the global objects, *i.e.* derivations and Kahler differentials.

Comment: If it's possible to fit in, a discussion of the cotangent complex would be awesome as well.

Comment: David, thanks.  (1) is there, but you suggest something better:  having this up front at the start, motivating the definition.  And a picture here is worth a thousand words:  a point with an arrow sitting inside your scheme --- certainly the picture of a tangent vector.  This is great.  (2)  I think I understand you (and it is now there):  for example, the fact that the fiber of Omega is identified with the cotangent space for a k-valued point (for a k-scheme), and with a little more work, something similar for other points.  Is that right?

Comment: Harry:  that's farther than I can manage to get in a year without losing people, although it is possible to foreshadow the dualizing complex (as a side remark) and even essentially to define it.

Comment: Regarding (2): That's right, and also that this is not true for derivations and the tangent space. For example, any derivation on $\mathrm{Spec} \ k[x,y]/xy$ will vanish at the origin.

Answer (score 48):

Let me begin with something essentially obvious: students should learn to work with non-closed points.  In practice, this means learning how to use them to simplify life.

Here are some suggestions as to how to do that:

(a) Explain that coherent sheaves are generically free, and use this to prove things
like generic smoothness of varieties (by applying it to the tangent sheaf).

(b) Explain carefully the proof of Chevalley's theorem that the image of constructible
is contstructible.  (Note that this latter result has the advantage of being extremely
useful, and also has likely not been covered in any form in a previous varieties course.)

Note also that one can *deduce* the Nullstellensatz from this result, which kills two
birds with one stone.  (See the discussion in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15611/to-prove-the-nullstellensatz-how-can-the-general-case-of-an-arbitrary-algebraica/15719#15719), and the notes of Mumford and Oda that are linked there.)

(c) one can beef up (a) by looking at say a fibration $X \to Y,$ and then looking at fibres
over a generic point of $Y$, and then extending information to a n.h. of that point.
Incidentally, it was the desirability of this kind of argument that first led Zariski to point out the importance of studying algebraic geometry over non-algebraically closed fields.  For him, these non-algebraically closed fields were not $\mathbb Q$ or $\mathbb F_p$, but rather function fields of varieties (with the initial ground field being a good old fashioned algebraically closed field).

Examples like this last one can really help demystify not just the role of generic points, but also the role of non-algebraically closed fields.  (In particular, they show that the latter are not just of interest in number theory.  Zariski was certainly not a number theorist!)

Comment: Just to add to Emerton's remarks, it good to note that the scheme-theoretic results on open/closed/constructible sets are *stronger* than variety counterparts.  If one knows a constructibility result for a subset of an integral scheme of finite type over an alg. closed field (e.g., locus defined by conditions on fibers of morphism) and can prove generic point lies in there then a classical Zariski-dense open locus of classical points are in there too.  This is what underlies useful instances of the "spreading out" principle in (c). This comes up for rigid-analytic vs. Berkovich spaces too!

Comment: I agree with you Matt.  And I should say that in graduate school I first appreciated Chevalley's theorem only after you explained it to me.

Comment: I agree very much; after taking the class, I still wish I understood generic points better. They make proofs so much easier, in a way unique to algebraic geometry, but I still don't feel that I have a good enough handle to use them. One of my main points of confusion: how should I think of the generic fiber? stalk at a generic point? What's the difference? Also, I still feel unsure of how good the analogy between properties at the generic point and generic properties from differential topology is.

Comment: Ilya, drop by my office (or Ravi's) some time and we can clear it up.  The name "generic point" is very much deserved.  As to why, this is one of those things which is extremely well-developed in EGA and almost invisible in Hartshorne. 

Comment: Ilya (and others):  what might help?  Might it help to say explicitly at the start that often things that are true at the generic point are "generically true", i.e. more precisely there is an open neighborhood which the things are true, and giving an example that a function vanishing at the generic point must also vanish in an open neighborhood?

Comment: Ravi, what helps is to show the "spreading out" principle in practice with multiple examples that can be seen by hand, and mention of others which are clearly much deeper (in the sense of not being obviously captured by equations) but still reassuring to know about. And also counterexamples (such as irreducible vs. absolutely irreducible fibers, as you know). The example of vanishing of a function is a bit too simple to convey the flavor of how such things go. A bare-hands proof of generic freeness for coherent sheaves via linear algebra at the generic point is a better first example.  

Comment: I'm happy with that example; it may as well be a second example, and still mention the first.

Answer (score 43):

Since in 2007-2008 you evoked  [ Class 24, §1.8, *The problem with locally free sheaves*] the equivalence between locally free sheaves and vector bundles on a scheme, the following point, potentially confusing for a beginner, could be mentioned.

A locally free sheaf $\mathcal E$ has a sheaf stalk $\mathcal E_x$ at $x$ but also a vector fibre $\mathcal E[x]=\mathcal E_x \otimes _ {\mathcal O_x} k(x)$. The fact that tensoring is not exact explains the paradox that a locally free subsheaf of a locally free sheaf does not yield a sub-vector bundle of a vector bundle in the above equivalence. The contrasting notation $\mathcal E[x]$ versus $\mathcal E_x$ (that I learned from German mathematicians) may help clarify this subtle point .

I am quite aware that there is nothing grandiose in this technical suggestion, but little points like those can be quite frustrating when learning a new subject

Comment: This is actually fantastic.  (I think the devil in algebraic geometry really is in the details, and things like this make a big difference in assuaging confusion.)  It is indeed confusing that the subscript $x$ is used for both stalks and for fibers.  Am I understanding you correctly that you would propose that if $\mathcal{F}$ is a quasicoherent sheaf on $X$, that $\mathcal{F}[x]$ be used for the fiber over a point $x \in X$?  This would prevent a lot of confusion. 

Comment:  (cont'd) If it is already in use in certain enlightened countries, I think this should sweep the planet.  If no one currently uses it, then it would only confuse people further.  (Opinions anyone?)  The issue that if $x \in X$, then $\mathcal{O}_x$ could mean the stalk of the structure sheaf of $X$ at $x$ or the structure sheaf of $x$ is almost inevitable, but can be avoided by religiously using $\mathcal{O}_{X,x}$ for the former.

Comment: I always write $\mathcal{E}(x)$ for the "locally ringed space fiber", and (naively) thought it was universal notation nowadays (not sure where I got it from).  I agree that a clear distinction of fiber and stalk can be a puzzler early in the education process.  Sadly, Godement's book uses the exact same notation for stalks!  (Neither Godement nor EGA seem to have a special notation for locally ringed space fiber: each explicitly writes out the monstrosity $\mathcal{E}_x/\mathfrak{m}_x \mathcal{E}_x$ every time it is needed.)

Comment: Yes, Ravi, my proposition is indeed to use the notation $\mathcal F[x]=\mathcal F_x \otimes _ {\mathcal O_x} k(x)$ for the fibre of $\mathcal F$ at $x$, which I called the "vector fibre". The reason for my "vector fibre" terminology is that I had forgotten that in English you are lucky to have two words "stalk" and "fibre", whereas in French we use "fibre" in both cases . This regrettable linguistic feature of my mother tongue might explain the phenomenon that BCnrd deplores. But perhaps the redundant expression "vector fibre" might nevertheless be used for the sake of emphasis. 

Comment: $\mathcal F|_x$ is another possibility which avoids confusion with twists and shifts.

Comment: @a-fortiori: $\mathcal{F}|_x$ looks like the topological pullback of $\mathcal{F}$ to the point $x$, so the stalk.  But the stalk is denoted by omitting the bar.  So I have to confess to being unsure which meaning you intend by your suggested notation (stalk vs. fiber).

Comment: For a subscheme $i\colon Z\to X$, the notation $\mathcal F|_Z$ is generally used for the module pullback $i^*\mathcal F$, not the topological pullback. Of course, $\mathrm{Spec}(k(x))\to X$ is not locally closed in general. Using $x$ as a shorthand for this monomorphism is common in the base-change notation $Y_x$ for the fibre $\mathrm{Spec}(k(x))\times_X Y$.

Comment: +1 I also had trouble keeping these ideas straight.

Comment: I'm getting more convinced by a-fortiori's proposal, as I have used this before for closed subschemes.  The use for non-closed points doesn't seem a huge stretch.  (Side remark:  some authors use $\mathcal{F}_{|x}$ instead of $\mathcal{F}|_x$, which seems weird to me.)

Comment: Ravi, the reason I advocate $\mathcal{F}(x)$ for the fiber at $x$ is that just as one writes $s_x$ for the $x$-stalk (in $\mathcal{F}_x$) of a local section $s$ of $\mathcal{F}$, it is nice to write $s(x)$ for the image of $s_x$ in $\mathcal{F}(x) := \mathcal{F}_x/\mathfrak{m}_x \mathcal{F}_x$ because that is suggestive of "evaluating a function" (which literally is what happens when $\mathcal{F} = O_X$!). In other words, the $\mathcal{F}(x)$ notation reminds one of evaluation, which is the difference between "stalk" and "fiber". We can battle it out further in your office later today... 

Comment: Okay Brian, I'm convinced yet again.  (Sam L. made the case too.)  This has te possible advantage of doing away with the notation $\kappa(x)$ for the residue field at a point $x$; instead it is now $\mathcal{O}(x)$.

Comment: Ravi, please do not write $\mathcal{O}(x)$ for residue field; I hope it was meant as a joke.  Stick with $k(x)$ or $\kappa(x)$ for the residue field.  I don't see why getting rid of $\kappa(x)$ is viewed as an "advantage".  It is the standard notation in EGA, for example, and sure looks more like a field than $\mathcal{O}(x)$ (as if one knows what a field "looks like").  

Comment: It wasn't actually a joke, but okay, I won't!  $k(x)$ seems dangerous because $k$ is often the ground field.  I'm currently using $\kappa(x)$.  I realize you won't like what I use for the fraction field and the function field (the same symbol $FF(X)$ or $FF(A)$, not $K(X)$ or $K(A)$).  I'm not wedded to that either.

Comment: Ack, $FF(A)$?!?   Why 2 letters when 1 will suffice? If not $\kappa(A)$ or $K(A)$, perhaps $M(A)$ for "meromorphic" if you want to be non-standard?  Anyway, when discussing curves you'd bound to write $\mathcal{O}(D)$ (surely not Hartshorne's $\mathcal{L}(D)$) for a divisor $D$, so at that time using $\mathcal{O}(x)$ to denote the residue field at $x$ would have come back to haunt you.  

Comment: Clearly, $Q(A)$  is the best notation for the Quotient field (and standard in the nc setting). This also avoids confusion with Grothendieck group and weird associations with Kodaira dimension.

Comment: BCnrd, I really like the "evaluation at x" rationale, but I do not see how $\mathcal F(x)$ is any better than $\mathcal O(x)$. How do you propose to write $0\to\mathcal F\to\mathcal F(x)\to\mathcal F(x)[x]\to 0$ (where $\mathcal F(x)=\mathcal F\otimes\mathcal O(x)$) using parentheses?

Comment: @Victor: Yes, $Q(A)$ is a great idea.  @a-fortiori:  Hmm, you raise an excellent point, that is a problem with my suggested notation.  Goes to show how often I work with points as divisors on curves!

Comment: When I took an algebraic geometry course in France, the lecturer used the word "tige" for stalk (while mentioning that "fibre" was commonly used for two meanings).

Comment: That's interesting, Martin. Who was the lecturer?

Comment: No really clear choice seems to be emerging.  Using $\mathcal{F}|_Z$ for pull back to a scheme $Z$ (used especially if $Z$ is a closed immersion, or an open immersion, or even a locally closed immersion, or a point, or a geometric point...) seems good for most but not all purposes.  (cont'd) 

Comment: Before Victor interceded, I was convinced that reserving flavors of $k$ for fields ($k$ often for the ground field; $K$ for a field in general; $K(A)$ for fraction field; $K(X)$ for function field; $\kappa(x)$ for residue field) would be a good idea, but he's thrown a wrench into that.  $Q(A)$ is certainly nice for that one use.  a-fortiori's example through a wrench in BCnrd's proposal.

Comment: I have the following proposal: $\mathcal{F}_x$ for stalk; $\mathcal{F}|_{x}$ for fiber at a closed point (as it's the quasi-coh sheaf restriction to $x:\rm{Spec \Bbbk}\rightarrow X$); $\Bbbk$ is nice for the ground field; $\textsc{QF}(R)$ for the quotient field of the ring $R$; $\kappa (x)$ for the residue field; (to be continued) 

Comment: (continued) $\mathcal{K}_X$ for the sheaf of rational functions; $\mathcal{K}(X)$ for the ring of rational functions ($\Bbbk (X)$ in case $X$ is irreducible so it's actually a field); $K(X)$ for the Grothendieck group of $X$ (or $K^0(X)$ -resp. $K_0(X)$- if not clear from the context if it's the Grothendieck ring -resp. group- ).

Comment: @Georges, I know that Joseph Oesterlé uses the word *tige*.

Comment: Georges, this is an excellent suggestion, and is now implemented (in 14.4.1 in the version of the notes to go public next, at the usual place:  http://math216.wordpress.com ).

Comment: Dear Ravi,I'm very glad that you like the suggestion. By the way, will there be a notification in the blog of your course that you have modified this old section? 

Answer (score 30):

Toric varieties. They're so easy to define and work with, and to organize examples around. Like blowing up a scheme at a fat point, or blowing up in different orders, or big but not ample line bundles, ... Of course there's the danger that they'll give people the wrong idea about what general schemes are like, but a few curves-of-high-genus examples should help with that.

Comment: Agreed --- and it is possible to say a fair amount in fairly little space, and they are perfectly set up for exercises.

Comment: This is only indirectly related (because "varieties not schemes"). How can a complete variety fail to be projective? I only understood this once I learned toric varieties. 

Comment: Victor, I think that's quite related, and a good point.  I currently do an easy surface example (again requiring flatness), but toric varieties would provide a very pleasant other example.

Comment: How much toric geometry needs to be covered to get to an example, though? I think there's one in "Convex Bodies and Algebraic Geometry", but it's necessarily a threefold, because I seem to recall that a toric surface can't fail to be projective, because toric singularities can't be SO bad.

Comment: Charles: Here is my attempt to sketch the relevant background material to verify that the one of the standard non-projective smooth toric three-folds is such. (1) Show that, if $X$ is a variety and $U_i$ an affine open cover such that all the $U_i$ and all the $U_i \cap U_j$ are UFD's, then the Picard group may be computed from this Cech cover (2) Note that, in the toric examples, all the $U_i$ are affine space and the $U_i \cap U_j$ are of the form $k[x_1, \ldots, x_d, y_1, \ldots, y_e][(y_1 \ldots y_e)^{-1}]$ for some $(d,e)$. (Continued...)

Comment: (3) So all the unit groups in the Cech complex are finite rank abelian groups, and we can compute Picard explicitly. In the standard examples, it is usually rank $1$. (4) Verify that every line bundle has negative degree on some explicit torus equivariant curve.

Comment: Not a lot of theory to my mind, but certainly a very nontrivial application of basic definitions.

Comment: Ahh, the method I had in mind involved proving that the fan couldn't be made into a polytope.  That's much better, and more reasonable.

Comment: I like taking an octahedron, splitting it into northern and southern hemispheres glued along a neighborhood of an equatorial square, and stretching out the top vertex into an interval. Then when you try to glue these two together, the geometry of the top half wants the equator to be a rectangle, but the bottom half requires it to be a square. Hence any line bundle will be degree 0 on the P^1 corresponding to this new top edge.

Comment: Allen --- slick!

Answer (score 23):

I'm not sure if this is the kind of answer you're looking for but...

There is a very useful and simple lemma on sheaves which is (I think) never explicitly stated in Hartshorne. It is [Proposition I-12](http://books.google.com/books?id=FjtDugVYMIMC&lpg=PP1&dq=eisenbud%20harris&pg=PA16#v=onepage&q&f=false) of Eisenbud-Harris. I think you should definitely make sure to explicitly state this. Sheafification was very scary and mysterious to me until I learned this lemma.

Comment: The fact that this is not stated in Hartshorne is one of the reasons why his construction of the structure sheaf of an affine scheme is so ad-hoc.

Comment: My first (limited) exposure to schemes was in a course from Joe Harris which used a draft copy of the book with Eisenbud, and most of which went completely over my head. But when I eventually "graduated" to reading Hartshorne I knew to ignore his mysterious construction of the structure sheaf and followed the "B-sheaf" method from Eisenbud-Harris instead, with the help of Exercise 23 in Chapter 3 of Atiyah-MacDonald. 

Comment: Wow, a reference for that lemma! Thanks, Kevin.

Comment: I think Chapter I of Eisenbud-Harris is really great in general.

Comment: Definitely!  In fact I don't see how to do without this, without going through extreme contortions.

Comment: David Speyer:  another reference is 3.2 in EGA 0$_{\rm{I}}$.  Strange that it is not in Godement's book (as best I can tell). 

Comment: On a related note (also related to Allen's discussion of schemes as gluing together affines):  I have found that using the fact that schemes are affines glued together, rather than just ringed spaces, makes showing facts we care about regarding quasicoherent sheaves much easier.  In particular, in graduate school, it was a revelation when a visiting grad school (who now goes under the pseudonym "BCnrd") pointed out to me the simple fact that the intersection of 2 affines is a union of affines simultaneously distinguished in them both.  This turned a host of Hartshorne ideas from hard to easy.

Comment: He's told me since that he heard this from Nike Vatsal, who later forgot about it and was surprised to hear someone call it "Nike's Lemma".  (Of course no one would claim that it was unknown before Nike.)

Comment: I learned that fact from here: http://www-math.mit.edu/~kedlaya/18.726-spr05/virtual.html

Comment: Kevin, the curious thing is that in the link you give, it is only said that there's *some* open in the overlap that is simultaneous basic open in each piece (which is not useful), rather than that there's an entire open cover by such doubly-distinguished opens (which as you know is quite useful in getting things off the ground).  

Comment: BCnrd: You're right that the full "Nike Lemma" is not explicitly stated there. But the idea is there, no? 

Comment: Another good reference for the equivalence between sheaves and sheaves defined on a basis is [Tag 009H](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/009H).

Answer (score 21):

Why the Spec functor is a natural thing; this is not so clear (at least to me) from the definition in Hartshorne.  Bas Edixhoven made me see the light by saying that Spec is adjoint to the global sections functor from locally ringed spaces to commutative rings: $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{Rings}}(A,\Gamma(X,{\cal O}_X))\cong\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{LRS}}(X,\mathrm{Spec}(A))$.  Exercise II.2.4 of Hartshorne asks you to prove this with locally ringed spaces replaced by schemes, but this is less clarifying.

Comment: Anton Geraschenko's answer here is useful: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/731/points-in-algebraic-geometry-why-shift-from-m-spec-to-spec/756#756

Comment: Interesting follow-up:  this question suggests that Spec is the right thing because "locally ringed spaces" are the right kind of geometric space.  But people may not be initially convinced that locally ringed spaces are natural.  Perhaps Spec could be defined first (hence your question still stands), and the locally ringed spaces next?  It is a bit of a chicken-and-egg thing.  (I'm undecided/agnostic about this.)

Answer (score 20):

Dear Ravi, here is a small suggestion. I think one might emphasize as soon as possible that the subschemes of an affine scheme $Spec A$ exactly correspond to the set of ideals of the ring $A$.( I don't know if this is deep or tautological: probably both.) This allows one to illustrate many of the strange and frightening features of scheme theory as compared to tamer geometric structures (that subschemes are not determined by subsets, that functions are not determined by their values, etc) without adding the complications due to sheaves and gluing. I remember it took me a long time to realize this and when I did I lost some of my fear of schemes.

Comment: I fear that much of the apparent pathology in the theory of schemes comes from the presentation of schemes as locally ringed spaces rather than their presentations as sheaves of sets on the category of affine schemes (and therefore their presentations as the gros slice toposes they represent). For example, the reason the fibre product doesn't make any sense at all (even on the underlying set of the locally ringed space) is that Sch has a faithful (and full?) embedding into LRS. When we compute the fibre product of schemes as abstract sheaves, we compute it pointwise, which gives a right answer

Comment: Harry, if you're not sure whether the functor from schemes into locally ringed spaces is full, you should step back from the etale topos and related formalism and learn more basic things better (and be more humble for the present time about offering advice on how to think about or teach the subject). 

Comment: It's full and faithful, yes.  I just didn't want to say so without checking.

Comment: Harry, you misunderstood my point: the fact that you needed to go back and check this basic fact from the beginning of the theory means you had not internalized it, and so is a reflection of a certain lack of experience on your part (it is one of the first things that one should learn in the theory of schemes, to connect it up with other geometric theories, etc.). You should consequently be more reserved in offering advice to others on how to teach or think about it. It is akin to a real analysis student who needs to go back and check whether or not the Intermediate Value Theorem is true.

Comment: Fine, I accept your rebuke.  Thank you.

Comment: Harry, it was not intended as a rebuke (which I interpret as a somewhat negative word).  It was simply advice to be more reserved, in view of your somewhat limited experience in this area of mathematics. By all means discuss these ideas with your classmates, professors, etc.  Just be less energetic about making suggestions on educational aspects until you have had more time to see where it all goes and how it is used and how more of the deep theorems are proved.

Comment: Then I accept your advice.  Thank you.

Comment: Georges, that's a good point.  I was confused about this very point, because it is a little subtle.  It depends on how you initially define closed subschemes.  (I do something slightly different than some sources.)

Comment: Dear Georges, where is a good place to read about (the subtleties of) this correspondence?

Answer (score 19):

Generic fiber vs. general fiber vs. geometric generic fiber.

Comment: vs. very general fiber vs. special fiber vs. closed fiber vs. geometric special fiber vs. geometric fiber vs. complex fiber vs....(and similarly with "point" replacing "fiber", though "point" also opens up an entirely different issue...)

Comment: Our students aren't getting enough fiber in thier diets,that your point,Allen?LOL

Answer (score 19):

1. (Maybe this is a standard thing to do already but I think it's still worth mentioning:) A proof of Bezout's theorem via Hilbert polynomials of subschemes of $\mathbb P^N$.

   Of course, this isn't fundamentally different than the proof in Hartshorne I.7, but in scheme language it is much much more natural, and might be the best motivation for allowing nilpotents in the structure sheaf.
2. This is extremely vague, but it's something I wish someone should have told me 5 years earlier: Since algebraic geometry is so rigid (few polynomials compared to many differentiable functions), we often have to deal with singularities. E.g. in many cases we can't make intersections transversal, or all interesting families (of certain types) have singular fibers. But since algebraic geometry is so rigid, we also have fairly good tools dealing with singularities, or with degenerate cases.

Comment: I think point 2 here is an extremely important one to make.  One doesn't have to give a song and dance about it, but it should be clearly stated at the beginning of any algebraic geometry course.  
To students who don't yet have much experience with other kinds of geometry, it may not mean so much at the beginning, but as they mature, it will hopefully stay with them as a guide to the difference between algebraic geometry and other geometries.  For those who are used to other geometries and want to learn algebraic geometry, I think it is one of the first things that should be pointed out. 

Comment: It's also a nice heuristic to explain why methods like degenerating techniques, (virtual) localization, ... are so powerful (or why flatness is such an important notion). 

Answer (score 18):

I think analytification and GAGA should be mentioned.

Subsequently I think that it should be mentioned that Serre duality can be viewed as a refinement of Poincaré duality.

Comment: Kevin, this opens up a can of worms, to nail down the compatibility of the coherent trace on ${\rm{H}}^n(\Omega^n)$ and the topological trace on ${\rm{H}}^{2n}(\mathbf{C})$ with respect to the "degeneration isomorphism" between them.  I had a long conversation about it with Serre, and he was very disappointed with the literature. So when "mentioning" to someone that Serre duality is a refinement, one should also mention that there is real work needed to nail down the compatibilities. There's an old .pdf file about it in the "duality" part of my webpage; quite tricky to do rigorously. 

Comment: Thank you for your comments and the reference, Prof. Conrad!

Comment: I'm guessing the above referenced pdf is this one: http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/moreexample.pdf

Answer (score 18):

Victor Protsak suggests this, and I'll endorse it: the careful construction of the Grassmannian. This is a good example for 3 reasons. (1) It is extremely important. (2) It is a situation where it is both natural to work in local coordinates and with a global projective embedding, so students can practice transforming between the two perspectives. (3) It is small enough to do in full detail, but it usually isn't.

Ideally, this would include proving that the Grassmannian represents the functor of flat families of subspaces of a vector space. (Or quotient spaces, whichever you prefer.)

Comment: This would actually *motivate* cohomology and base change:  we can finally make precise our intuition!  Ditto for Victor Protsak's suggestion of the Hilbert scheme of points (even 2 points).  Both are good choices because the (linear) algebra in question is particularly simple, allowing people to focus on the key issues of how you show a moduli space represents the moduli problem.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand how the Grassmannian motivates cohomology and base change?

Comment: Sorry Kevin, I should have been more explicit. First you understand the Grassmannian in terms of quotients of a free bundle, prettily by hand. But you might also want to think of it geometrically, as parametrizing $\mathbb{P}^k$s in $\mathbb{P}^n$, i.e. a special case of a Hilbert functor: a family is a closed subscheme of $\mathbb{P}^n$ over the base, flat, whose fibers are (linear) $\mathbb{P}^k$s. How might you turn it into the linear algebra problem? By pushing forward the restriction map for $\mathcal{O}(1)$. How do you know that the resulting things are locally free? Coho + base change!

Comment: I imagine that when I was younger and foolish-er, I would have found it pretty irritating to hear in a lecture a careful construction of Grassmannians -- I think it would have seemed too many words spent on something too trivial.  Maybe better as an exercise...

Comment: Hi Vivek --- I agree --- or perhaps a series of exercises.

Answer (score 17):

I haven't seen it mentioned yet, so let me suggest it (and I'll be curious to hear people's
responses):  the theorem on formal functions.

In suggesting this, I am certainly taking full advantage of the fact that we are supposed to be discussing a year long course.

Let me now give justification (in case it is needed; I don't know how others will feel
about this suggestion).

First, my own philosophy is that an algebraic geometry course, even one focusing on the theory of schemes, should be about geometry.  So I think that it is important to discuss some geometry, including the basic theory of curves (which is very pretty from the schemes point of view, since one gets the interaction between a more geometric picture, and the more valuation-theoretic function-field picture, by studying the interaction between the generic point and the closed points).

But the theory of curves is not enough concrete geometry for one year; I think some discussion of surfaces adds an enormous level of geometric understanding, just because the theory of surfaces is much closer to the theory of arbitrary dimensional varieties than the theory of curves is.  At the same time, by doing some stuff with surfaces, one does a valuable service for many students in the class: pure geometers will certainly need to know this, but so will arithmetic geometers/number theorists, because a curve over a Dedekind domain behaves like a surface, and one studies bad reduction of curves using ideas from the theory of surfaces (blowing up, minimimal models, etc.).  So even if one doesn't touch directly on the particularities of degenerations of curves (which, however, is also a topic of very general interest and importance!), by saying something about surfaces, one prepares the way.

Hartshorne Ch. V gives a really nice treatment of many of the basics of surface theory,
and the main tool he uses, beyond all the generalities of cohomology and sheaves, is the
theorem on formal functions: both in its application to Zariski's main theorem,
and to the proof of Castelnuovo's criterion.  And these are both beautiful results, the kind
of results that would make a good capstone to a one year course.
(And they are also basic algebraic geometry knowledge --- the kind of things that you
would hope students know after taking a year of the stuff!)

Comment: Ding ding ding!  Bells went off in my head when I read this, as this is a topic I very much wanted to hear people's opinions about.  Matt, I agree with you that this is important, and in particular through ZMT and Castelnuovo's criterion.  I also agree that this is fair game because we are talking about a year-long course, and this would be near the end.  So I think it should be in if all possible.  (Unlike, perhaps, formal schemes, which no one has brought up so far.) cont'd  

Comment: Now many things I used to think were hard, I've since digested and realize are not so hard (e.g. semicontinuity, and cohomology and base change, after reading Mumford's brief explanation in Abelian Varieties, and most other things about cohomology discussed on this page).  But formal functions remains harder in my mind than it probably needs to be.  (I find it amazing that Castelnuovo's criterion is so hard.  And ZMT in some form should be not so bad.)  Are there good pre-digested explanations out there?  (I've not read all the sources; certainly not the original sources.) cont'd

Comment: This is frankly the biggest thing I want to explain that I don't yet know how best to explain.

Comment: Ravi, proof of thm on formal fns in EGA is simpler than version in Hartshorne, and it works directly in the proper case (no mucking around with $\mathcal{O}(n)$'s, etc.).  The argument is due to Serre, and it gives a stronger result than what is claimed in Hartshorne in the projective case.  I wrote up a handout on it for the course I taught with Matt's help way back when.  I can send you the .pdf for it if you don't have it buried in a filing cabinet somewhere. (As an aside, I think it would be a mistake to try to introduce formal schemes, though one could say what the point of it is.)

Comment: Dear Ravi,  In some sense Castelnuovo's criterion (as presented by Hartshorne; I've never read any earlier sources --- it would be interesting to look at Zariski's book and see how he treats it) is
not that bad: one constructs the right linear system to give the blow-down, which at least a fortiori looks very natural.  Even the way the theorem on formal functions is applied is very natural, and quite intuitive.  So I think it is a very teachable result (given the theorem on formal functions).  

As for the theorem on formal functions itself ... (to be continued, possibly)

Comment: BCnrd:  thanks!  Dreams **do** come true!    And Matt (Emerton):  thanks --- I agree that the linear system is clearly the way to go, but it is the smoothness of the contraction that (I seem to recall) is tricky.  But you (in combination with BCnrd's explanation back from the course he taught with your help) have made clear that Formal Functions are less frightening.

Comment: @Ravi There's a resource you may or may not be aware of and I've posted it at Math Online:Last year,Micheal Artin taught a wonderful looking first course at MIT on algebraic geometry using his own notes and William Fulton's ALGEBRAIC CURVES.The only prerequisites were a year long algebra course based on the forthcoming second edition of his classic text.Not only are the notes themselves excellent as a model for what that preliminary "classical" course before yours should look like,he has some very insightful comments there on the teaching of AG. I think you'll find it quite useful.   

Comment: You do not <B>NEED</B> the theorem on formal functions to prove Castelnuovo's criterion.  Smoothness of the target can be proved by considering the multiplicity of the image point.  However, this approach to Castelnuovo's criterion is very close in spirit to Artin's "Algebraization of formal moduli II", cf. also Appendix B.3 of Hartshorne.

Comment: Dear Jason,  Thanks for this.  Is there a standard (or even non-standard) reference, accessible to a reader with a modern (rather than classical) education, that presents the proof you have in mind?  Best wishes, Matt

Comment: Matt -- I don't have Beauville's book in front of me, but I would look there.  The existence of a contraction which is a projective variety follows from the vast generalization by Mori: the contraction theorem (cf. p. 76 of Koll\'ar-Mori).  

Comment: Matt -- The proof begins on p. 21 of Beauville's book (on p. 20 for the second edition).

Comment: Dear Jason, Thanks a lot!  Best wishes, Matt

Answer (score 16):

I actually think that the Hilbert scheme should be mentioned (and, if possible, proved to exist and discussed) as early as possible.  It serves as a good example of a moduli space, and it exists! Plus, the infinitesimal study of the Hilbert scheme allows some deformation theory to be discussed (at least, the deformations of projective schemes inside projective space) which also helps explain, algebro-geometrically, what the normal sheaf really controls.  Add to this the fact that a lot of research relies on moduli spaces these days (In particular, I know that people care about Hilbert schemes of points, and, if some GIT for PGL can be covered, it'll let you actually construct $\mathcal{M}_g$, which finishes the classification of curves that's given in chapter 1 of Hartshorne, though this is a bit more.)

Because you'll be wanting things fundamentally scheme theoretic, the first part of Kollár's "Rational Curves on Algebraic Varieties" might be a good reference for this stuff.

Comment: Let me try to separate this into pieces.  Certainly one wouldn't want to define flatness really early, but one would certainly want to have an idea of what a moduli space is, and to *want* a definition.  I've heard about an excellent first course whose "punchline" was the existence of the Hilbert scheme.  I've managed this in a second course (having only gotten to things like cohomology and base change at the end).  But there are exercises you can do that give intuition for the Hilbert scheme, and that really involve working with the functor (also good foreshadowing).  

Comment: (cont'd)  I also tried from the beginning to sell the functorial point of view --- not as dry formalism, but as something natural and organic.  I think the idea of the right definition of a moduli space is a subtle one, and once the functorial perspective has become second nature, we forget how subtle it once was.  Question:  what are good "baby moduli spaces" that are clearly interesting, but also where existence is provable without too much work.  (Even hypersurfaces in $\mathbb{P}^n$ are a bit tricky, but they are the best I can think of offhand.)

Comment: Do Grassmanians and Hilbert schemes of points count as "baby moduli spaces"?


Comment: Victor:  Great point, and yes, they are good ones. It will be hard to beat that proposal.   One of the many bonus of Grassmannians is that you an interpret it as a moduli space in several different ways.  The Grassmannian is an example of something not often formally defined in a first course, and then not formally defined in a second course. 

Comment: Yes, talking about Grassmannians, especially projective space, as moduli spaces is helpful, and the functorial point of view also helps with fibre products, at the least, the fibre product seems more natural that way.  As for Hilbert schemes, you'd mentioned that this is a year long course, and I think that they're easily within target for a year, depending on how you do things.  I know you don't want to define flatness early on, but I would make sure to foreshadow it: examples of flat and nonflat maps where the students can see that the nonflat ones are somehow pathological, long before(cont)

Comment: the definition is actually stated.  Then introduce flatness is "save the day" as a way to exclude the bad families of objects (say, curves) to make some nice, geometric theorem work.  Maybe then some technical details of flatness, and then build up to the Hilbert scheme, while doing everything else.

Comment: Speaking of flatness:  is there a "best explanation" of the local criterion for flatness?  Perhaps not a proof from the book, but at least something either (i) incredibly fast, or else (ii) incredibly enlightening?

Comment: Update in response to Victor Protsak's excellent point of June 18 2010:  I wanted to add Hilbert schemes of points, and to do it on affine space (and from there you can do varieties in general in a straightforward way).  The problem was:  the elementary approach I had in mind required taking a quotient by GL (see e.g. Nakajima's great book), and rigorously establishing this theory would have removed the advantage of this example (of a complete rigorous example done quickly).  *Does anyone have a completely elementary approach, without handwaving or black boxes?*

Comment: Follow-up to previous comment:  currently the only nontrivial moduli problems I've done are Grassmannians and hypersurfaces in projective space (both in 25.10 in the current = August 2012 version).

Answer (score 16):

**Stalk-local detection of irreducibility** on locally Noetherian schemes, which I [prove directly here](http://www.acritch.com/media/math/Stalk-local_detection_of_irreducibility.pdf) with no primary decomposition tricks.  It helps with a lot of exercises, and intuition.

**Sheafification of base-presheaves** (presheaves defined only on a base of open sets).  I see from your TOC that you cover the unique extension of base sheaves to sheaves as per [Kevin Lin's answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/28496/what-should-be-learned-in-a-first-serious-schemes-course/28545#28545) (E-H's [Proposition I-12](http://books.google.com/books?id=FjtDugVYMIMC&lpg=PP1&dq=eisenbud%2520harris&pg=PA16#v=onepage&q&f=false)).

When I took Arthur Ogus' algebraic geometry class, he was very insistent about teaching us this, and it really paid off for the remainder of the course, particularly in exercises.  It categorically exclaims (pun intended) the credo *always start with the affine opens*, so one sees explicitly how special and critical they are to the theory.

**The sheaf of meromorphic functions** $\mathcal{K}_X$ on $X$ can be defined by sheafifying the naive base-presheaf $\mathcal{K'}(U)=Frac(\mathcal{O}(U))$ on the base of open affines.  This formula *doesn't define a base-sheaf* on affines, and as Georges Elencwajg and BCnrd [explain here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/28553/extra-principal-cartier-divisors-on-non-noetherian-rings-answered-no), it *doesn't even define a presheaf* when applied to arbitrary opens.   I suggest at least mentioning these three facts, to save people from re-wasting the time that I and many others have in wondering what the resulting sheaf looks like.

**Locally representable means representable**, i.e. if $F:Sch^{op}\to Set$ is a sheaf when restricted to a base of (Zariski) opens on every scheme, and $F$ has a covering by representable [open subfunctors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subfunctor) $F_i$, then $F$ is representable (very much along the lines of EGA 1 (1971), Chapter 0, Proposition 4.5.4).  I advocate this because the work that goes into the proof is essentially the same work we inevitably do to prove [fibered products of schemes exist](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/0708-216/216class1516.pdf), so it gives fibre products as a special case, but also offers up a rigorous-but-quick route to other constructions like global Spec and global Proj.

**The general definition of quasicoherence and coherence** for modules on local ringed spaces / non- locally Noetherian schemes... not as a gratuitous generality, but as a foreshadowing/reminder that presentations, not just surjections, are what make coherence work.

**Basic Dedekind domain theory**, along the lines of Lang's Algebraic Number Theory, chapter 1.  I found curves and their divisors — even in characteristic 0 — impossible to understand until I read that.

**Quasiseparatedness** is something I'm glad to see you including, because using it explicitly is the key to a lot of proofs, so having it in mind as a word helps me remember how to do them.

**Your [affine communication lemma](http://math.stanford.edu/~vakil/0506-216/216class09.pdf)** is a must-have, for anyone else reading this answer!

Comment: Andrew, what you (and Ravi in his notes) call the "affine communication lemma" is precisely the "Nike trick/lemma" alluded to in the comments for Kevin Lin's answer above. But "affine communication lemma" is a more informative name.  (It is also buried in EGA in the middle of some arguments, but never stated there as an isolated fact on its own.) 

Comment: Andrew, many nice ideas.  Stalk-local detection of irreducibility:  nice argument!  I agree with everything (and have attempted everything) except for one:  I propose dropping the sheaf of meromorphic functions.  I find it confusing, and not leading to any theorems (that you would use in a first course).  Hartshorne indeed introduces it, but doesn't really use it in any essential way.  I realize this even means dropping Cartier divisors (!) in favor of just talking about line bundles on one hand, and Weil divisors on the other.  *Effective* Cartier divisors are useful though.

Comment: Ravi, Hartshorne does something nice with meromorphic fns on reduced loc. noetherian scheme. If $M$ is sheaf of mero. fns, any qc $M$-module of f.t. is *canonically* direct sum of pushforwards of  generic stalks (buried in Hartshorne's discussion). Using "sheaf of mero. sections" $F \otimes M$ (good for cx-analytic geom. too!), clarifies data (basis of generic stalk) underlying homomorphic relation b/w line bundles & Weil divisors on integral loc. factorial base. Applied to Dedekind base, get passage between Pic gp of line bundles and class gp of fractional ideals via *generic stalk basis*.

Comment: Andrew, for stalk-local criterion for irred., here's pf inspired by EGA principle of resisting passage to affine case for as long as possible (or entirely!). On loc. noeth. top. space, collection of irred. components is loc. finite (work locally, so noeth. case). So linked chains of irreds characterize conn'd components (akin to path-conn'dness arguments), so in conn'd case any irred. component is linked to any other. If conn'd but not irred., some irred. components meet at some $x$. Then Spec($O_x$) not irred since its min. primes "are" the generic pts of irred. components through $x$. QED

Comment: Andrew, another pf of stalk-local irred. criterion in "non-affine" terms! Let $X'$ be (maybe non-noeth) normalization of $X_ {\rm{red}}$ for loc. noeth. $X$. Formation of $X'$ compatible with localization on $X$, so $X' \rightarrow X$ bijective between generic pts since fields are normal and domain with field normalization is field. So $X$ irred iff $X'$ irred iff $X'$ conn'd (since $X'$ loc. irred. by construction!). If $X$ conn'd and $\{U,V\}$ separation of $X'$, their *closed* images in $X$ must meet at some $x$. Then Spec($(O_x)_ {\rm{red}}$) has disconn'd normalization, so not irred! QED

Comment: @Andrew: What do you mean that a functor with an open covering by representable subfunctors is itself representable? At least for sheaves on CRing^op with the étale topology, this isn't true at all. For example, any scheme has this property (open cover of affines), but not all schemes are affine.

Comment: Thanks, I just edited the answer to clarify... I'm talking about sheaves on the category of schemes with the Zariski toplogy (see my revised statement).

Comment: @AndrewCritch The first link appears to be broken. Is the document still available online?

Answer (score 12):

If you decide to teach a more arithmetically flavoured algebraic geometry, students should be made aware that schemes over a ring $A$ are stranger than they might think.

For example $A$-rational points of $\mathbb P^n_A$ are far from being  given by non-zero $(n+1)$-tuples of n elements of $A$ modulo tuples of invertible elements, but are described by rank-$n$ projective summands of $A^{n+1}$. More generally morphisms to projective space are described in terms of line bundles and their sections and might be seen as an interesting illustration of these concepts.

Incidentally, a sufficient reason for introducing a little arithmetic geometry is to have the pleasure of reproducing Mumford's incredibly enlightening drawing of the arithmetic surface $\mathbb A^1_{\mathbb Z}$ (in his Red Book), with its points  having each a diferent personality and its curves. ( I concede that although Mumford's picture is beautiful, the artistic competition was not so great when he wrote his notes: the EGA's strongest point is not its illustrations...)

Comment: In particular, it would help with the issue from this question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/28485/integral-points-on-varieties

Comment: Spot on, Charles: it  was indeed that question which motivated this answer

Comment: Georges: the common "surprise" about points of projective space or of affine space minus 0-section valued in a ring (or scheme) has always seemed best to explain by analogy with how the same issue comes up in differential geometry, or even alg. geom. using only varieties and not schemes.  The meaning of a map from a manifold to real projective $n$-space works out exactly as with schemes, and likewise for affine space minus the 0-section, so it is good to stress to students that none of this is peculiar to working with schemes or is a phenomenon special to the "arithmetic" case. 

Comment: Agreed.  And further, it seems essential (in a literal sense, not just polemic sense) to know that maps to projective space are what you say.  And helpful (and nearly essential) to recognize this as a functorial description of projective space (by universal property).  Also related to your discussion:  I see little advantage to restricting to working over an algebraically closed field, or even a field.  It makes very few arguments simpler.  It is true that working over $\overline{k}$ can be help reduce anxiety.  But comfort levels can be stretched by working with beautiful curves like Spec Z.

Comment: I strongly disagree with you about EGA.  Every single picture in EGA is incredibly enlightening, and beautifully rendered. :-) [Anyone who has looked at EGA will realize I'm actually agreeing with Georges, but that my "Every single picture" comment is also true...]

Comment: I am very proud of your endorsement, Ravi: thank you.
Contrariwise, my heart missed a beat when I read your sentence "I strongly disagree with you about EGA" but fortunately, reading on, I realized that the rich resources of the empty set were coming to my rescue :-)

Comment: @BCnrad: you are right. I have noticed that if I think hard enough, sometimes surprises in algebraic geometry start to seem less mysterious. But unfortunately this doesn't happen very often to me. Maybe it is a general phenomenon: understanding means you are no longer surprised ?

Comment: Ravi & Georges: in the same spirit, the pictures in Mumford's book on abelian varieties are not as good as the ones in EGA. :)

Comment: Obligatory: http://www.neverendingbooks.org/index.php/mumfords-treasure-map.html 

Comment: Obligatory indeed, Kevin. Whoever reads my old friend Lieven Le Bruyn's brilliant exegesis will be delighted by his detailed explanations. As a bonus one gets a picture of $\mathbb A^1_{\mathbb Z}$ and one of Mumford on the same page.

Comment: Speaking of Mumford and arithmetic approaches, it seems the fabled "Mumford-Lang" type-script has been subsumed by notes of Mumford/Oda (Lang is not mentioned as a coauthor here). In these notes they discuss Galois theory for schemes. Cf. especially Chapter 4 (Part I) of

http://www.math.upenn.edu/~chai/624_08/math624_08.html

For a student with a background in algebraic number theory, Grothendieck's version of Galois theory may provide for added motivation to learn about schemes


Answer (score 11):

Serre's criterion for normality, the valuative criterion for normality, normality vs. S2, maybe even seminormality.

Added by request: here's how I think about Serre's criterion. Call a rational function pretty good if it doesn't blow up in codim 1. Call it very good if it's actually well-defined in codim 1. Then a normal space is one for which pretty good rational functions are actually functions, whereas an S2 space only asks that very good rational functions are actually functions. To see the difference, look at x/(x+y) on {xy=0}, to see that the latter is not normal despite being S2. So how can normality fail -- how can f's value be ambiguous in codim 1? If there are 2 ways to approach some divisor -- non-R1ness.

Comment: Somewhat related to this:  is the notion of Cohen-Macaulay something people really should see early on?  Advantages:  it doesn't take long.  You get to see the Koszul complex.  Then you get to see that the normal sheaf to a local complete intersection is locally free.  There is a handy flatness theorem (very roughly, a map from CM to nonsingular is flat iff the fibers are equidimensional; and a flat map to a nonsingular has CM source). Then S2 could go here, perhaps later than it needs to be.  Disadvantage:  yet more definitions to clog up your brain.

Comment: One of the things I regret is that none of my teachers ever taught me what "Cohen-Macaulay" means.  Depending on what you do, it can show up pretty much first thing as you set out into the literature, with the assumption that you know it cold already.

Comment: @Charles: wouldn't such an experience simply provide motivation to go back to the commutative algebra books or elsewhere to learn about it (if it wasn't learned when doing Serre duality)? I do agree that CM is a very good notion to see in a course, if time permits.  But virtually everything I know about modern algebraic geometry I had to teach myself, often in the service of trying to understand other things which I cared about. But that's part of doing math: having to struggle with learning stuff on one's own, for which external motivation is always a good thing. 

Comment: I like Serre's criterion, purely as a piece of commutative algebra,
but if one is going to teach it in a course on geometry, to make it reasonable, you are going to have to commit to explaining some applications of normality (to make the investment in understanding it worthwhile), and some applications of Serre's criterion (e.g. the lemma of Enriques--Severi--Zariski, and *its* applications to things
like completeness of linear systems induced by intersecting with a linear system of hypersurfaces).



Comment: BTW here's how I think about Serre's criterion. Call a rational function _pretty good_ if it doesn't blow up in codim 1. Call it _very good_ if it's actually well-defined in codim 1. Then a normal space is one for which pretty good rational functions are actually functions, whereas an S2 space only asks that very good rational functions are actually functions. To see the difference, look at x/(x+y) on {xy=0}, to see that the latter is not normal despite being S2. So how can normality fail -- how can f's value be ambiguous in codim 1? If there are 2 ways to approach some divisor -- non-R1ness.

Comment: Hi Matt (Emerton)--- I agree that Serre's criterion should be justified.  I think normality can be seen to be useful earlier on (getting at line bundles using Weil divisors; and Hartogs' theorem), so people may be convinced already about that.  So what about the fact that local complete intersections are normal iff they are regular in codimension 1?

Comment: @Emerton: normal => S2 => hyperplane sections are S1 => if each component has a reduced point, then the hyperplane section is reduced. Which I think is pretty cool.

I used a similar implication in http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0306275 , namely that a generically reduced complete intersection is in fact reduced (really, that CM => S1).

Comment: @Allen Knutson:  Your comment from Jun 20, 2010 at 1:19 is great, and I think should be in an answer, if only to make it more visible.

Answer (score 10):

To prepare well for what comes after a first course, a more extensive discussion of étale morphisms than Hartshorne gives should be part of such a course, in my opinion.

Comment: Full coverage of the structure theory for (formally) (essentially) smooth, unramified, and étale morphisms (Zariski's main theorem, the jacobian criterion and all of the commutative algebra concerning minors, etc.) can take a significant amount of time to cover (it can easily take 8-10 classes, even at a decent pace), as some of it is pretty deep. 

Comment: Agreed:  the properties of \'etale morphisms are important for most users of such a course.  Incidentally, I find it interesting (and challenging) that so many roads lead through flatness.

Comment: Harry, I am well aware of that and it is not at all at odds with my suggestion. In fact, in a first course, I don't think that it would be advisable at all to drop noetherian and loc. fin. type hypotheses.

Comment: I'm intrigued to find:  No one has yet proposed etale (or flat) descent.

Comment: Ravi, if the course doesn't do much with flatness and only scratches the surface with etale morphisms, it wouldn't make sense to discuss descent theory since there won't be time to do anything serious to show why it's useful. (Wouldn't hurt to *mention* that etale maps can be promoted to a "topology", supporting analogy with complex-analytic case, but there's no time if one keeps making little digressions into every interesting technical side-topic.) It is also very illuminating to mention the Artin approximation theorem as "justification" for intuition with the etale topology. 

Comment: Actually covering Artin approximation seems like it would take one rather far afield of the theory of schemes, but I agree that it wouldn't hurt to mention it.

Comment: Dear Harry,  Artin approximation is the result which justifies the fact that if a point on a curve (say) has a reducible formal completion, than it has a reducible etale neighbourhood.  This is a basic fact often used in the literature, and (in my experience) not always well explained (and hence confusing the first time you see 
it claimed).  On the other hand, I'm not sure whether it would fit into a first course, just because there are so many other, more basic,
things that one is also trying to fit in.

Comment: Dear Harry: In my first course on schemes the instructor told us about it briefly near the end (when telling us that for moduli problems one has to go beyond schemes, and that a crucial engine that made it all work was Artin approximation, as you must know). Beyond relevance to moduli, which I couldn't appreciate in a serious way at that time, I found it a very compelling justification for why etale maps are like local analytic isomorphisms (cf. inverse function theorem for manifolds, which is also a "formal" criterion), and kept it in mind as I learned more about the etale topology later. 

Comment: I've been introduced to all of these concepts through the lens of commutative algebra, and since I know only the rudiments of scheme theory (and none of the motivating problems!), I guess I have a hard time seeing the geometric relevance of the whole thing.

Comment: Oh my.  Harry, I don't know what has led you to exert so much time on higher topos theory in lieu of getting more experience with schemes first (the motivating problems, the geometry, the insights from the etale topology, etc.), but you would benefit from seeking more guidance from experts at UM. The (very geometric!) inspiration for algebraic spaces comes from Artin approximation. Even Jacob Lurie learned the basic theory of schemes thoroughly (in a course run by me and Emerton, with no topoi but lots of balance of theory and examples) before going on to the etale site and stacks. Good luck.

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps this should be attached to Charles Siegel's answer about the Hilbert scheme, but some concrete examples of degenerating flat families could be helpful.  Some easy examples include conics turning into a fat line, skew lines colliding to produce an embedded point, and pairs of points on a line colliding to become fat.  There are some nice relationships between these objects and families of constant coefficient linear differential equations via spectral schemes, e.g., the colliding points example says something about the behavior of solutions to  $(\frac{d}{dz} - a)^2 - \lambda^2 = 0$ as $\lambda$ hits zero.

Comment: Well, I didn't want to be the one who said "D-modules"...

Comment: I hadn't realized it was a bad word (and I've been saying it in front of children).  More seriously, I was hoping this would be a sufficiently special case that one wouldn't have spend time on the full machinery.

Answer (score 8):

I am  surprised that no one mentioned this so far; I am only imagining that everyone thought it so natural that it escaped their mind.

Most "standard courses" would be following Hartshorne's book, I assume. It is a great loss that this book does not mention the "functor of points" view at all. It would maybe take 10 or 15 minutes to state and prove the Yoneda's lemma, and a little more time to mention the functor of points and the advantage of this point of view for applications to arithmetic geometry(points with values in a certain ring, base change, etc.), and more importantly for moduli problems. One could also give a definition of a fine moduli space and coarse moduli space, and as examples just mention the the moduli space of curves with marked points(but without proofs, of course).

Comment: Ok, now I see that Charles Siegel's answer that the Hilbert scheme should be mentioned, is almost like this answer. But my version is a weaker version and so might be more appropriate for a first course.

Comment: This sounds very sensible to me!

Answer (score 8):

In reference to why the spec functor is a natural thing, (low tech answer): isn't this essentially what the nullstellensatz says?  Or rather it generalizes the nullstellensatz.  I.e. spec is a good thing because it lets you make a construction that gives you some "geometry" associated to a given ring.

Perhaps the main thing beginners should learn about schemes is that they are needed. I.e. schemes should be motivated. In books which try to restrict to varieties such as Shafarevich's BAG, schemes still raise their heads sometimes unnoticed.  E.g. Shafarevich states in chapter I sections 4.4 and 6.4 that the set of hypersurfaces of given degree in a given projective space are parametrized by a projective space, which is not true unless one considers more than the variety defined by a polynomial.

If one is guided on what to include by the section headings of chapter 2 of Mumford's red book, in addition to fields of definition and the functor of points, one finds there a section called specializations, which also contains one of his exotic illustrations.

Even in a classical book like Walker's algebraic curves, schemes arise when studying singularities.  The tangent cone to a cuspidal plane curve requires more structure than a variety.  Even the fundamental theorem of algebra does not count the roots of a polynomial correctly unless multiplicities are considered.

Some of these examples require only cycles or divisors rather than schemes, but more general tangent cones should provide more general schemes.  One can also consider the problem of varieties varying in families and try to fill in something over the limit point of the parameter space.  Sometimes non reduced objects will force themselves on us.

The best motivation for differentials may be learning the classical Riemann Roch theorem for curves.

Of course this is probably obvious and taken for granted by most people, but it seemed worth mentioning as a guide to choosing first examples of schemes.  I.e. we should not take schemes for granted and choose what to teach based solely on the needs of experts, but we should assume that schemes may be quite strange to beginners and spend some effort showing that they are natural.

Answer (score 7):

I expressed my frustration with Hartshorne's book a bit here:

[Motivation for concepts in Algebraic Geometry](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12436/motivation-for-concepts-in-algebraic-geometry)

The point is that many definitions in algebraic geometry are basically obtained by taking definitions from topology or algebra, translating them into "purely category theoretic language" and then using that definition as a substitute in the category of schemes.

In particular I unravel the definition of a separated morphism:

"A seperated morphism of schemes is one where the image of the diagonal is closed."

If we just replace "schemes" with "topological spaces", then this property for spaces says (after a little definition chasing)

"Any two distinct points which are identified by the morphism can be separated by disjoint open sets in the domain"

Thus a space is Hausdorff as a topological space iff the unique map to the one point space is separated.  Before I worked through this I had no real reason to believe that separated morphisms were a natural concept.  Why don't people ever talk about the topological analogue?

Another point of much confusion for me was the definition of derived functor cohomology.  Why should we care about injective resolutions?  Anton gives a great answer here:

[Sheaf cohomology and injective resolutions](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1151/sheaf-cohomology-and-injective-resolutions/1165#1165)

Anton's line of thought is also beautifully developed in Gunter Harder's book "Lectures on Algebraic Geometry 1".  The quick and dirty version is that cohomology should have nice properties (ses gives rise to les, etc) and acyclic resolutions compute cohomology.  Hey!  Injective objects are always acyclic (this is reasonable because they make ses's split). Thus injective resolutions are a nice generic thing to use.

Comment: I agree with your frustration; certainly students tell younger students this fact.  (And I also included it as an exercise.)  I don't think Hartshorne's discussion of separatedness is representative; the description in EGA is clearer (although of course sans motivation).  I haven't checked, but perhaps only Hartshorne (among the major references) uses the valuative criterion to prove things that can be more easily proved by hand.

Comment: On a related note, I conjecture that the reason that recent generations learn the valuative criterion so early is that Hartshorne does this.  Inflammatory comment:  It is not clear to me that anything one might reasonably see in a first course can be more easily proved with the valuative criterion than directly, taking into account the cost of proving the valuative criterion.  Any counterexamples?  (Although certainly the statement is worth seeing early.  But the proof can go, to make room for other things.)

Comment: On derived functor cohomology:  one approach I've experimented with is the following.  The theory of Tor is quite hands on:  define it with a free resolution, then show it is independent of the free resolution.  What did we use about free modules?  Just that they satisfy this property we call "projective".  What did we use about $\otimes$?  Just that it was right-exact.

Comment: Another inflammatory comment:  derived functors are beautiful, but confuse the issue for quasicoherent cohomology the first time you see it.  Almost everything you want to know follows from Cech cohomology.  Some exceptions:  the Leray spectral sequence.  Proving that the (higher) pushforward of coherents are coherent for *proper* morphisms (with minor hypotheses) using Chow's Lemma.  And you need it to define Ext, and then to prove Serre duality.

Comment: OK Ravi, I'll bite: doesn't the proof of universal closedness of projective space (over Z) via val. crit. demonstrate the elegance of functorial criteria (in comparison with elimination theory)?  There's also something likewise cool about using it to prove that the map from Grassmannian to projective space is closed immersion (esp. comparing it against the more explicit traditional proof, which is also concrete and worth seeing). Basically, it provides simple examples of the power of functorial criteria (if not overdone!). That is surely something to be appreciated in a first course. 

Comment: I agree that the functorial criteria is elegant, and also more elegant than elimination theory.  Also, I find the trick in the argument in the fundamental theorem of elimination theory to be surprising and less motivated than I'd like.  (Perhaps someone has a digested enough so it is in retrospect obvious.)  But I still find elimination theory short, constructive (it computes scheme-theoretic image), and shows where the equations come from.  The valuative criterion would win if I didn't have to prove it first.  (cont'd)

Comment: For the Grassmannian:  it's nice to see, but I'm less convinced. By construction, the map to projective space is a locally closed immersion, so all one really needs is the "valuative criterion for closed sets".  But in short:  this is reasonably open to debate.  But nothing essential seems lost in telling people the statement and letting them read the proof if they want, on their own time.  I'd happily trade the proof of the valuative criterion for the proof of Chevalley.  Or Koszul complexes.

Comment: @Ravi For the record,from most of the AG graduate students who have both been in your class and are using the posted notes online that I've spoken to,your notes are proving an invaluable resource for them in the learning of schemes and modern AG. Many of them in fact have dumped Hartshorne in favor of your notes.Thier continued evolution and availabilty on the web has gained a growing grass-roots support.I think I can speak for all of them when I say this ongoing project is a noble undertaking and it's continuation is fervently hoped for.  

Comment: I'm going to say this. I find sheaf cohomology a much better motivation for derived functors than Tor is. Look at deRham cohomology, and at singular cohomology on a locally contractible space. Both of them take a sequence that is "locally exact," and test to what extent this "local solvability" fails globally. And they give the same answer. Why? Well, any "nice enough" resolution gives the same answer.

Comment: On the derived-functors versus Cech-cohomology-only question:
I think an interesting middle ground is to do cohomology only for quasi-coherent sheaves on separated schemes. One can construct injective resolutions via an affine covering and I-twiddles of injective modules I for each open set. Then one can prove e.g. the agreement with Cech cohomology without ever using words like "flasque" or "$O_X$-modules".

(My feeling is that at least some of the obfuscation comes from the fact that Hartshorne's approach leaves the category of quasi-coherent sheaves before taking injective resolutions.)

Comment: @ABayer:  Arend, I agree with you, and this is the way I present it.  Or at least almost so:  I first do cohomology for quasicoherent sheaves on separated schemes, using Cech cohomology, which ends up being quite direct (unlike Cech cohomology on more traditional spaces).  Almost everything you might want to know about cohomology of quasicoherent sheaves follows most easily from this point of view.  (A first exception:  Leray.  A second:  Ext.)  I get to the more general definitions, but later.

Answer (score 7):

A small suggestion : the deformation to the normal cone is a nice construction that I would have liked to see in a first course. It illustrate the use of blow-ups, the degeneration of a family with constant fibers (an highly non-obvious concept the first times you see it) and how important intuitions from differential geometry - tubular neighbourhoods - have a non-trivial translation to algebraic geometry.

Comment: Please call it "degeneration to the normal cone", though, reserving "deformation" for the general fiber and "degeneration" for the special fiber, of a flat family.

Comment: (I realize that common usage lets "deformation" work either direction. But we already have "degeneration" for one of the directions.)

Answer (score 6):

I think that base change is a very important and subtle idea which should certainly be included in a first course.  In particular, one should discuss properties that are stable under base change and those that are not.

In a similar vein, in discussing cohomology, the difference between the coefficients of the motive and the base should be emphasized.  This was confusing to me as I learned the subject.

Comment: I agree with your first paragraph.  I don't understand your second ("coefficients of the motive") --- could you please elaborate?  (I realize you aren't proposing that motives be in a first course.)

Comment: Well, I think that I'll elaborate with an example.  If $X=Spec(F)$ is a variety over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $F$ is a number field then $H^0_B(X(\mathbb{C}),\mathbb{Q})$ is isomorphic to the group ring $\mathbb Q[G]$ where $G$ is the Galois group of $F$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.  If I would like to decompose this into the irreducible representations of $\mathbb{Q}$, then I need to extend \em{coefficients} to a field $E$ over which the idempotents are defined.  So I would be looking at $H^0_B(X(\mathbb{C}),E)$.  If I wanted to look at a subgroup of $G$, I would need to change the base.

Comment: For me, it was another one of those things that is easy once you understand what is going on, but very easy to screw up before that!

Comment: Another example: an $\ell$-adic sheaf on $X$ is a motive over $X$ with coefficients in $\mathbf{Q}_{\ell}$ (or rather a realization of one). The most interesting cases are when there's a relationship between the coefficients and the base, e.g. Hodge theory and $p$-adic Hodge theory.

Answer (score 5):

Resolution of singularities.

That isn't really an answer to the question - I don't think it's necessary in a first course, but I do think resolution should be rotated in on a regular basis, which requires the annual core to be small enough to make room for it. I think it's valuable not just to teach the material somewhere in the curriculum, but to put it in an introductory course, to emphasize that it is elementary and not impossibly difficult. Also, to contrast with the Grothendieck-flavored majority.

Comment: Do you mean a proof of resolution of singularities?  (And I presume you mean in characteristic $0$.)  At Brown, there was a topics course on this, using Koll\'ar's explanation; but it took a semester.  Somehow I find resolution of singularities harder than most of Grothendieck's foundations.

Comment: Yes. I was in this course at Brown. It was (only) half a semester. I said it was difficult and time-consuming! There were three second-year students for whom this was the beginning of the second term of algebraic geometry. I should ask them how well it worked (my current assessment that it worked is based on watching them present the material). Probably one should practice this in topics courses before pushing it earlier.

Comment: First, I took Ravi's course this year and it was great! But relevant to Ben's suggestion, I do think more discussion and examples of blowing up (and down) would be appropriate and useful. This would fit in after the discussion of projective morphisms. However, as the course proceeded this year there was an awful lot of stuff to discuss in the spring quarter, so maybe squeezing this in too would be tricky.

Comment: I should say, the things about blowups I wanted to hear more about -- namely the general construction and intuition about blowing up general not-necessarily-reduced subschemes, as well as arithmetic examples -- are all discussed in Eisenbud-Harris. So the above suggestion is more in the spirit of stuff to say in class and maybe add to the exercises, rather than stuff to state and prove theorems about.

Comment: If one really wanted to go in that direction, maybe it is a better idea to discuss de Jong's theorem on alterations, perhaps accepting certain facts about moduli spaces of curves as a black box. This would certainly give lots of applications of the techniques learned, and except for moduli of curves it doesn't really use a lot of high tech, as far as I understand.

Comment: Sam's point is good:  I didn't get to it because of a too-brutal triage, and because the notes on that weren't yet polished.   I think it is important to be able to actually compute blow-ups in basic cases --- if you can't, then you don't understand it. This relates to Allen's toric varieties comment too.  (To Sam:  the notes now in your mailbox actually have all this, in precisely the location you describe, after sheaf proj.  Not there yet:  "blow up smooth in smooth is smooth", which is waiting for me to decide what Koszul  ideas I should include.)

Comment: Lars, deJong's alterations is a great topic for using all of the machinery (like Mumford's book on abelian varieties), but my experience is that this takes an entire course to develop nicely.  I have taught it twice, and will do so again next year, though it will take some care to squeeze it (with background stuff) into 10 weeks rather than an entire semester (damn quarter system...).  Putting good discussion of it into a first course on schemes seems too much (though *mentioning* it is a good idea) -- better for students to get familiar with how to compute some blow-ups in the first course. 

Comment: As far as learning blowups goes, a good (albeit tedious!) exercise that really got me comfortable with them was resolving the ADE surface singularities.

Comment: @Brian: I agree that this is not a subject for a first course. My point was simply that I think alterations are more suitable for an early course than "classical" resolutions of singularities.

Answer (score 5):

1.$ $ This is really about commutative algebra more than algebraic geometry as such, but something I found incredibly frustrating for a while was what to do when I need to compare $M \otimes_A N$ with $M \otimes_B N$. I finally discovered the following illuminating lemma:

If $M$ and $N$ are $B$ modules, then for every ring homomorphism $A \to B$, there is a natural map $M \otimes_A N \to M \otimes_B N$.  Moreover, this map is an isomorphism for all $M, N$ iff it is an isomorphism for $M = N = B$ iff $A \to B$ is an epimorphism of rings.

In particular, the last condition holds if $B$ is obtained from $A$ by some combination of localization and taking a quotient ring, or if $\operatorname{Spec} B \to \operatorname{Spec} A$ is any kind of immersion. The same "abstract nonsense" shows that if $Z \to Z'$ is a monomorphism of schemes (in particular, any kind of immersion), then the product of two $Z$-schemes over $Z$ is naturally isomorphic to their product over $Z'$.

2.$ $ I found the usual description of gluing schemes and morphisms (i.e., requiring things to agree on $U_i \cap U_j$) frustrating to use sometimes, because in general, $U_i \cap U_j$ might not be affine even if $U_i$ and $U_j$ both are.  To glue morphisms only, one can require that the morphism be defined on every set of an open cover, such that whenever $x \in U \cap V$, then $x$ has a neigborhood $W \subset U \cap V$ such that $f_V|W = f_U|W$.

For gluing schemes, one can use a commuting poset of open immersions. Given such a diagram, with objects $\{U_i\}$, there exists a scheme $W$, together with open immersions $U_i \to W$ commuting with the diagram, such that the $U_i$ cover $W$, and $x \in U_i$, $y \in U_j$ map to the same point in $W$ iff they may to the same point in some $U_k$. When this is combined with the statement on gluing morphisms, one sees that $W$ is actually the colimit of the diagram; and, in fact, the statement that "any such diagram has a colimit" more or less encapsulates both glueing schemes and glueing morphisms. Realizing this was also the first time I felt like I understood colimits.

For a more streamlined, if less general, version of the above, one can use a version of the cocycle condition with $U_i \cap U_j$ replaced by a cover of $U_i \cap U_j$ by simultaneously distinguished affines, assuming the cover $\{U_i\}$ is by open affines.

In either formulation, this combines with the previous point to give a very quick construction of the fibre product: simply take the colimit of the diagram consisting of maps $$\operatorname{Spec} (A \otimes_C B)_{f \otimes g} \to \operatorname{Spec} A \otimes_C B$$
such that the images of $\operatorname{Spec} A$ and $\operatorname{Spec} B$ lie in $\operatorname{Spec} C$. (If these images in fact lie in a distinguished open subset $C_h$, we get the tensor product over that for free by point 1.) Of course, one still has to verify that this colimit behaves as desired; but this is not hard using the more general "gluing morphims" to show existence and uniqueness.

Note: if it's not clear already, my perspective is that of a student rather than an expert.

Comment: @Charles In point 2 you say:
In general $U_i\cap U_j$ might not be affine even if  $U_i$   and $U_j$    both are. Then maybe you are too general for a first serious course. Exercise II 4.3 in the book of Hartshorne tells that in a separated scheme the intersection would be affine.

Comment: Even in a separated scheme, I do not think that the intersection of two open affines is necessarily a distinguished open subset of both of them.  In my formulation, the only open subsets that need to be considered are inclusions of distinguished open subsets.

Answer (score 5):

Dear Ravi,

Here is my suggestion for a list of topics in an intro schemes course: open the table of contents of Hartshorne's book.  That is the list of topics that should be covered in a first schemes course.  And although the many alternatives to Hartshorne's book all have their selling points, I still feel the best choice for an introductory text is Hartshorne's book.  I am not writing this to be contrary to your goal of writing a better foundations book.  But I honestly and earnestly believe AG students must learn Hartshorne, and (usually) the earlier the better.

Answer (score 4):

First off, I wanted to commend you on this whole project, Ravi. Algebraic geometry and the theory of schemes is a notoriously difficult subject to internalize for any advanced student and it's clear you've given a lot of serious thought on how to make it more digestible. I've browsed the old version of the notes and found them very readable and highly thought out. I firmly support this project and hope it goes through many revisions and drafts, evolving into a future classic. Algebraic geometry is a subject I haven't seriously begun broaching yet and I hope to use one of the newer versions when ready,

Secondly-I sympathize with your hesitancy to convert them into a book. What you might consider is creating an online text that will constantly be revised and will never be in "final" form. My old biochemistry professor Burton Tropp did this for many years and it worked out for him very well: The first edition WAS published, but all subsequent editions (and there was nearly a dozen before he retired last year) were online and subject to constant revision and improvement. I think this kind of format will work very well for you.

Thirdly -- **history is so important in learning a new,conceptually difficult field.** Some good historical notes would make the notes a lot more interesting to read no matter how good the exposition is. Students want to know how they came up with this crazy stuff -- if you know how the original source authors came up with these concepts and why, it'll make it a lot easier to not only internalize, but also to form thier own opinions on the subject.

Fourthly -- I think inserting references and research assignments relying on significant papers, such as Grothendiek's original schemes paper -- will give your students some much needed research experience in a very active field. These are advanced students and the more such experience they get,the better off they'll be.

Lastly -- I wanted to commend your humility and determination in asking other mathematicians and students for opinions and input on this project. It shows how committed you are to this project and experts should be chomping at the bit to give you thier feedback and opinions. I would, but my lack of expertise precludes that. Hopefully those with much more knowledge then I will jump at the chance to assist you with this wonderful project.

Good luck with this exciting project and looking forward to future versions!!!

Comment: For your third point Dieudonne has written "History of Algebraic Geometry", which starts at the very beginning (having separated the development of the subject into epochs), is a pleasure to read, and leads the reader to the modern problems. Unfortunately it appears to be rare, and I'm not sure if one would be able to distribute scanned pages among students.

Comment: @pmoduli I don't see the problem with photocopying pages from a copy as long as full credit is given to the source and it's documented for use in an academic setting. But if the lawyers are going to screw THIS time-honored practice as well for the sake of the almighty buck,then you can simply compose your own notes or ask someone else to. End of problem.

Answer (score 4):

At a relatively late point in the course, I believe that the idea of descent should be explained, with two examples: Zariski-descent, or gluing, and faithfully flat descent.
The latter should then be applied, for example to prove that some examples of functor of points are representable.

Answer (score 4):

As David and Anweshi told before,  think it could be very interesting to deal with functor of points, with main example being subfunctors of Grassmannians. I would make some general statements on functor of points (Yoneda lemma, definition of functor of points, vector bundles) and then begin to study as soon as possible classical examples, such as Grassmanians, Severi-Brauer varieties and their tautological vector bundle, varieties of flag of subspaces...

Finally it would lead to a glimpse on group schemes and algebraic groups.

Comment: This sounds sensible to me.  I've managed to get to these things later than I would have liked, largely because I didn't make a bee-line for them (notably Grassmannians) from the start.

Answer (score 3):

Being a differential geometer, it might be nice if you can point out analogies (perhaps even make them rigorous ?) to differential geometry. Like a scheme being flat over another is perhaps akin to a fibre bundle. A scheme itself is like a manifold, etc. This might make the subject slightly less scary for geometric analysts.

Answer (score 0):

Scheme theory is abstract. I think motivating and concrete examples are important, e.g. elliptic curves and their arithmetic (Weil conjectures for elliptic curves, for example, or other topics from the two books of Silverman on elliptic curves).