# Suggestions for good notation

Tags: notation, big-list

I occasionally come across a new piece of notation so good that it makes life easier by giving a better way to look at something. Some examples:

- Iverson introduced the notation [X] to mean 1 if X is true and 0 otherwise; so for example Σ<sub>1≤n<x</sub> [n prime] is the number of primes less than x, and the unmemorable and confusing Kronecker delta function δ<sub>n</sub> becomes [n=0]. (A similar convention is used in the C programming language.)
- The function taking x to x sin(x) can be denoted by x ↦ x sin(x). This has the same meaning as the lambda calculus notation λx.x sin(x) but seems  easier to understand and use, and is less confusing than the usual convention of just writing x sin(x), which is ambiguous: it could also stand for a number.
- I find calculations with Homs and ⊗ easier to follow if I write Hom(A,B) as A→B. Similarly writing B<sup>A</sup> for the set of functions from A to B is really confusing, and I find it much easier to write this set as A→B.
- Conway's notation for orbifolds almost trivializes the classification of wallpaper groups.

Has anyone come across any more similar examples of good notation that should be better known? (Excluding standard well known examples such as commutative diagrams, Hindu-Arabic numerals, etc.)

Comment: In set theory we write ${}^B A$ for the set of functions from $B$ to $A$. 

Comment: Knuth made an argument for Iverson's notation in http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9205211 .

Comment: I've always assumed that the notation $A^B$ is because of the "exponential law" $(A^B)^C = A^{B\times C}$ ...

Comment: I guess, in terms of lambda calculus, this is called "currying" ...

Comment: Yes, among other things. Also $A^B\times A^C=A^{B+C}$, where $+$ is disjoint union. But all the great reasons for it don't help for our mind thinking that maps start with the source and end with the image, not the other way round.

Comment: I still find it terribly annoying that I have to write things like "where $[Q]$ is an Iversonian bracket" every time I use it. I wish it reaches the point where it should only have to be explained in introductory work. On the other hand, since brackets get used a lot for other things as well, maybe someone should develop specific enclosures like what was done for floor and ceiling I suppose...

Comment: (a version of) the Iverson bracket notation is common in categorical logic: we write them like $[\![ \mathrm{this} ]\!]$, i.e. [\![ … ]\!], and call them “Scott brackets”.  Besides the examples already given, it extends beautifully to more general models with some other lattice of truth-values; but I guess that's of less general interest :-)

Comment: Arabic numerals ?  Ah yes, they were transmitted to Europe by the Arabs.

Comment: Isn't $x \mapsto f(x)$ commonplace? As for homomorphisms, they are not simply maps, and $\mathrm{Hom}(A, B)$ denotes the whole class, while $A \to B$ denotes a single mapping.

Comment: For those who missed the point of Chandan's comment: it's "*Hindu*-Arabic numerals". ;)

Comment: @Peter: I've always heard them called "Oxford brackets" -- I've never heard the name Scott brackets before. I wouldn't mind attributing them to Scott though, if he invented them. 

Comment: How about the notation $x^n$ itself?  Initially for positive integers $n$ (and even then Euler still wrote $xx$ and $xxx$ on occasion) but suggesting fruitful generalization where $n$ might be negative, fractional, etc. and eventually even $x$ might "live" somewhere other than the real or complex numbers.

Comment: I would say the second bullet is completely standard.

Comment: @Peter LeFanu Lumsdaine, there's no need to do that spacing manually; stmaryrd (http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/stmaryrd) includes `\llbracket` and `\rrbracket`.

Comment: (1) I only know the Kronecker delta with *two* indices, yielding $\delta_{ij} = [i = j]$ - but this is better anyhow!
(2) I always found the notation $A^B$ useful since the *number* of functions from $B$ to $A$ is - in the finite case - just $|A|^{|B|}$
(3) I believe it's a matter of taste: for me $A\rightarrow B$ indicates *one* morphism from $A$ to $B$, not *all* of them.

Comment: Well, if X is a set, then the Cartesian product $X^n$ is the set of functions from $[n] = {1, 2, \ldots, n}$ to X, so naturally $X^A$ is the set of functions $A \to X$.

Comment: Re the comments on $B^A$: like you are likely to know, a useful and usual alternative notation for $B^A$, coming from category theory, is $[A,B]$, often referred to as the "internal-hom". In the category $\mathsf{C}$ of sets, we have $B^A = \mathsf{C}(A,B) = [A,B]$. The notation somewhat clashes with Iverson brackets, of course; and then again...one can perhaps reconcile the two with a suitable interpretation.

Comment: I invented my own function $\delta(n, k)$ which simply means *the sum of the digits of $n$ in base $k$* since $\delta$ looks like an $S$ in english but corresponds to a $d$ in greek ..... until I read this post and found out there was already a similar delta function (sigh).

Comment: I don't have enough reputation on this one to post an answer, so I'll do mine as a comment:

1) The second derivative written so that it can be used as a fraction:
$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} - \frac{dy}{dx}\frac{d^2x}{dx^2}$.  See https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.09553 for more details on this approach.

2) Partial differentials written so that they can be used as a fraction:  The partial derivative of $u$ with respect to $x$ where $x$ is the only variable allowed to independently vary written as $\frac{\partial_x u}{dx}$.

Both of these allow differentials to more freely be used as fractions.

Comment: I also don't have enough reputation on this one to post an answer, so I'll do mine as a comment:
In basic linear algebra, N.Vavilov suggests $[u\leadsto v]$ for the transition matrix from basis $u$ to basis $v$. That makes much easier and more natural and more memorizable formulas like $u[u\leadsto v]=v$ and for coordinates columns $x,y$: $a=ux=vy=(u[u\leadsto v])y=u([u\leadsto v]y)=ux$. Sure $[v\leadsto u]=[u\leadsto v]^{-1}$, and one never needs a transpose matrix.

Comment: The notation $\delta_P$ is also used for a formula $P$, and if $A$ is a set then $\delta_A$ is the characteristic function of $A$. So $[n]=\delta_{n=0}=\delta_0(n)$. In comparison to $[n]$, this makes it easier to view this as a function. This is also more general than the traditional $\delta$.

Comment: If you want an undergraduate to understand why you call a function $x\mapsto x\sin x$ instead of just calling it $x\sin x,$ point out that $x\mapsto(x+2y)^2$ and $y\mapsto(x+2y)^2$ are two different functions. $\qquad$

Answer (score 119):

Among recent introductions, I like the notation and names (introduced by Kenneth Iverson and popularized by Donald Knuth) for the ceiling function  $\lceil x\rceil$ and floor function $\lfloor x\rfloor$. Compare with the heavy "approximation by excess/defect"...

Comment: According to Knuth, this notation and these names were introduced by Iverson in his book "A programming language" in 1962.

Comment: But I have also seen some people call these "Gaussian Brackets" --- any reason why that is so?

Comment: @Suvrit: I have learned (in a German school) that Gauss used ordinary brackets [x] to denote the floor function, thus called Gauss bracket. However, I know of no source but guess that it is easily found in Gauss' works.

Comment: They are life-savers...

Comment: To add, I also like the notation $\lfloor x\rceil$ for rounding $x$ to the nearest integer $($but mainly because I use $\left\lbrack x\right\rbrack$
 to denote $\{1,2,\ldots,x\})$, but I have seen $\| x\|$, however $\|$ can mean other things $($I mean, I have used the command `\|` to generate it, but another command is `\parallel`$)$ :P

Comment: I have had occasion to use the notation $$ \begin{align} & \lfloor k \rfloor_\text{even} \\ {} \\ = {} & \text{the “even floor” of } k \\ {} \\ = {} & \text{the greatest even integer not exceeding } k \\ {} \\ = {} & 2\lfloor k/2\rfloor. \\ {} \\ {}  \end{align} $$

Comment: @MrPie : The commands `\|` and `\parallel` do not yield identical results. Consider $a\|b$ versus $a\parallel b.$ The latter has the horizontal spacing appropriate to a binary relation symbol. To fail to object to the former is akin to being insensitive to gross spelling errors.

Comment: While people commonly complain about running out of letters (despite having Roman, Greek, Cyrillic, and Hebrew to get started with), one much more quickly runs out of delimiters (), [], {}, <>. It is fantastic that a new pair has been invented.

Answer (score 104):

I like notation such as $2^X$ for the set of subsets of $X$ and ${X\choose k}$ for the set of $k$-element subsets. Also $[x^n]F(x)$ for the coefficient of $x^n$ in the power series $F(x)$, and multivariate notation like $x^\alpha$ for $x_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots x_n^{\alpha_n}$, where $x=(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ and $\alpha=(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$.

Comment: I find the projection $[x^n]F(x)$ indeed very useful.

Comment: And, in the spirit of the latter notation, the multivariate version $[x^\alpha]F(x)$ for polynomials in several variables.

Comment: I particularly like $X \choose k$ when X is say an algebraic variety and so $\chi {X \choose k} = {\chi(X) \choose k}$, where $\chi$ is the Euler characteristic...

Comment: I find the notation $[x^n]F(x)$ incredibly prolix, cumbersome, and difficult to understand. Far superior is inner product notation, $(x^n, F)$, which has several advantages: it is symmetric and bilinear, and is actually correct when dealing with pre-Hilbert spaces of polynomials and the natural inner product.

Comment: @DavidHandelman: perhaps it is just a matter of taste or context. I think of $[x^n]$ as a linear operator on the space of power series. If $A\colon V\to W$ is a linear transformation and $v\in V$, is it always preferable to write $(v,A)$ rather than $A(v)$ or $Av$? A nitpicking further point: why is the notation prolix? $[x^n]F$ uses one less character than $(x^n,F)$.

Comment: The only problem I have had with this notation is the inflexibility of some combinatorialists in not accepting the standard hierarchy of bracketing $ \; \; [ \; ( \cdots) \;]$ for readability of semi-complicated expressions.

Comment: More generally in structural Ramsey theory one writes $\binom{A}{B}$ for the set of substructures of $A$ isomorphic to $B$

Answer (score 88):

[Bourbaki dangerous bend symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourbaki_dangerous_bend_symbol) [image] to mark dangerous or difficult ideas.

Comment: Haha. I didn't know this was due to Bourbaki, I learned it from Knuth's "The TeXbook".

Comment: Perhaps this should be on every line in the Bourbaki text.

Comment: The signage is probably more familiar to Europeans than elsewhere. When I first read Knuth's book, I wondered what all the weird Z's were about.

Answer (score 87):

I like $A \hookrightarrow B$ and $A \twoheadrightarrow B$ for "$A$ injects into $B$" and "$A$ surjects onto $B$" respectively.

Comment: I like this but I am confused what to use for bijections.

Comment: A two-headed hooked right arrow.  I don't know how to do it in normal LaTeX but you can easily do it using the xymatrix package, and obviously it's easy to write on a chalkboard.

Comment: These two commands work for me for the "bijetion"-arrow described by Tom: 
    \newcommand*\longbijects{\ensuremath{\lhook\joinrel\relbar\joinrel\twoheadrightarrow}}     \newcommand*\bijects{\ensuremath{\lhook\joinrel\twoheadrightarrow}}

Comment: @Marcel - $\stackrel{\sim}{\to}$, a combination of the map and the isomorphism sign.

Comment: This is also useful to denote epi/mono, and in general factorisation systems, e.g cofibrations/fibrations in homotopy theory.

Comment: Add to this the notation $\looparrowright$ for immersions.

Comment: What about `\mathbin{\rightarrowtail \hspace{-8pt} \twoheadrightarrow}`, i.e. $\mathbin{\rightarrowtail \hspace{-8pt} \twoheadrightarrow}$? :D

Comment: See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/344464/notation-for-the-set-of-all-injections-from-a-into-b for a discussion regarding notation for injections.

Answer (score 73):

$D_j f$ to denote the partial derivative of a function between Euclidean spaces, w.r.t. the $j$'th coordinate. For some reason Jacobi's notation $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j}$ has become more popular. Jacobi's notation tends to cause much ambiguity and confusion, a point which is emphasized in the book "Multidimensional Real Analysis" by Duistermaat & Kolk. For instance (this example is taken from their book), let $e_1,e_2$ be the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$ and define a new basis by $e'_1 = e_1 + e_2, e'_2 = e_2$. The passage from one basis to another is as follows: If $x_1 e_1 + x_2 e_2 = y_1 e'_1 + y_2 e'_2$ then $y_1 = x_1, y_2 = x_2 -x_1$. Now the meaning of $\frac{\partial y_2}{\partial y_1}$ is ambiguous: If one interprets $y_1$ and $y_2$ as independent coordinate functions, then $\frac{\partial y_2}{\partial y_1} = 0$. On the other hand, $\frac{\partial y_2}{\partial y_1} = \frac{\partial (x_2 -x_1)}{\partial x_1} = -1$, right? This was the source of much confusion for me when I was taught multivariate calculus and the notation $D_j f$ would have eliminated this confusion entirely.

Comment: Another reason to prefer $D_j$ or $\nabla_j$ over $\partial/\partial x_j$ is that when you're expressing tensors using the Einstein "index gymnastics notation," the derivative $\nabla_j$ has a lower index, as it should, whereas the same operator in Leibniz notation is $\partial/\partial x^j$, which looks like it transforms as an upper-index tensor.

Comment: Regarding differential geometry: If $f:M\to\mathbb R$ is a smooth function on a manifold and $x:M\to\mathbb R^n$ is a chart, I prefer $\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right)_j$ or $\left(\frac\partial{\partial x}\right)_j f$ (or even $\partial_j f$ if the choice of the particular chart is clear or irrelevant). Because the notation $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^j}$ suggests that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial g}$ could be defined using only $g$, and in fact you need to know that you are restricting to the curve along which the other coordinates $x^i$ are constant.

Comment: @Ben, the index in the coordinate expression $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^j}$ for the 1-form $df$ is clearly in the low position! In fact, this is the main reason that I see for having to put the indexes of the coordinates in the high position as we do, instead of doing everything in the opposite way, which would be better in some way: we could write $f=x_1^2+x_3$ instead of $f=(x^1)^2+x^3$.

Comment: Jacobi was aware of this problem when he introduced the $\partial$ notation. Unfortunately [his choice of notation for avoiding this ambiguity](https://mathoverflow.net/a/278927/745) might have led to more confusion.

Comment: In PDE, one often uses $\partial_j$, and $\partial^\alpha=\partial_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots \partial_n^{\alpha_n}$ for a multi-index $\alpha$. (They reserve $D_j$ for $-i\partial_j$ which is convenient for Fourier transform.) In some cases I seem to like writing $D_\xi$ for $\xi\in V$ (without choosing a basis), and it acts on $f(x)$ where $x$ somehow is an element of $V^*$.

Comment: How would $D_j$ eliminate any confusion? You seem to assert that $D_1 y_2$ would be somehow unambiguous. But it is just as ambiguous as $\partial y_2 / \partial y_1$. If $D_1$ means differentiation with respect to $y_1$, holding $y_2$ constant, then $D_1 y_2 = 0$. If $D_1$ means differentiation with respect to $x_1$, holding $x_2$ constant, then $D_1 y_2 = -1$. More generally, there is no symbol or notation involving only *one single coordinate function* --- not $D_1$, not $\frac{\partial}{\partial y_1}$, nothing --- that can possibly convey full information about a coordinate chart.

Answer (score 60):

[String diagram-notation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=USYRDDZ9yEc)
makes for example adjoint functors, monads, tensor categories,... much clearer.

Comment: And it also connects monoidal categories to braids, knots, links, tangles...

Answer (score 52):

I recommend the notation
$$
    a \equiv_n b
$$
in place of $a \equiv b \pmod{n}$.
It's much less verbose. The meaning is clear. And the $n$ is where it really belongs, next to the $\equiv$ it is describing.

We're stuck with $a \equiv b \pmod{n}$ as the standard notation (for now!), because that's what Gauss came up with. I've got nothing against Gauss for not using a subscript $\equiv_n$. It seems to me that *Disquisitiones Arithmeticae* doesn't have subscripts *anywhere*. Subscripts must have been outside the graphic design space or something. So I don't blame him for resorting to $a \equiv b \pmod{n}$. Gauss did a great thing by popularizing $n \mid a-b$ as an equivalence relation of $a$ and $b$. But if we were to invent the notation today, I dare say $a \equiv_n b$ would be the modern choice. ([See this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/555939/122187) on Math.SE, where Alexander Gruber suggests the same thing in a comment.)

Of course, if there's no ambiguity, you can still just write plain $a \equiv b$. I'm talking about the cases where you need to or want to indicate the modulus $n$. It may not seem like much, but "(mod n)" is surprisingly verbose to physically write. If you're hand-writing pages or blackboards full of congruences, chances are you've already succumbed to abbreviating "(mod n)" somehow. I've seen lots of different shorthand, based on dropping the parenthesis, or some or all of the text "mod" (which is itself an abbreviation of "*modulo*", or if you really go by Gauss's Latin, "*secundum modulum*" - be thankful you're not writing *that*):
\begin{align}
    a &\equiv b \quad \mathrm{mod}\ n \\
    a &\equiv b \quad (\mathrm{m}\ n) \\
    a &\equiv b \quad (n) \\
\end{align}

I've seen all of these used before, as well as $a \equiv_n b$. Certainly $a \equiv_n b$ is the cleanest notation.

As a free bonus, you get a cool-looking Fermat's theorem:
$$
    a^p\!\equiv_p\!a.
$$

Comment: this notation has the advantage that it chains nicely:  although we all know what it means, there is (I think) no logical sense in which $a \equiv b \equiv c \pmod n$ is the result of concatenating $a \equiv b \pmod n$ and $b \equiv c \pmod n$; whereas $a \equiv_n b \equiv_n c$ clearly is.  One drawback:  It may lead to useless chains like $1 \equiv_2 5 \equiv_3 2$.

Comment: I still like this though... :)

Comment: That is indeed a cool looking Fermat's theorem.

Comment: Similar notation I've used is to put the (n) over the congruence symbol.

Answer (score 49):

I like $f\colon\thinspace M\looparrowright N$ to denote an immersion of smooth manifolds.

Comment: I use exactly this arrow to denote an operation of a group M on a space N.

Comment: I prefer the notation $\alpha: G \curvearrowright X$ for an action $\alpha$ of $G$ on $X$ (see my answer).

Comment: ... And I also like the "self intersecting arrow" to denote immersions that are possibly not embeddings.

Answer (score 49):

The notation $M^{\oplus n}$ and $M^{\otimes n} $ to denote, respectively, nth direct sum and nth tensor product.

The notation $X \mathbin{\pi} Y$ to denote product of objects in an abstract category, and the analogous with the "upside down $\pi$" for coproduct. I once have seen this being used by B.Keller in a talk.
It'd be nice to have a *smaller* $\Pi$ (resp. $\amalg$) symbol instead.

Comment: $\sqcap$ resp. $\sqcup$?

Comment: You can get your smaller Π sign with a bit of a hack. This isn't exactly robust, though, since the size is constant relative to the surrounding size (but can be fixed if one looks up the right command): $X \mathbin{\scriptsize{\Pi}} Y$ and $X \mathbin{\scriptsize{\amalg}} Y$

Comment: I prefer to use the same notation as in arithmetic: $\times$ for binary product, $\prod$ for product of an arbitrary family, $+$ for binary coproduct, $\sum$ of coproduct of an arbitrary family.  A small pi-like symbol for binary product seems to me to be a step in the wrong direction.  

Comment: Yeah I agree; I much prefer $\times$ and $+$ for categorical product and coproduct.

Comment: I also use $×$ and $\prod$ and $+$ and $\sum$, but whenever a category has a sufficiently nice functor to $\mathrm{Set}$ preserving / reflecting / creating colimits, I switch to $\coprod$. For example I don’t use $+$ in $\mathrm{Top}$ or $\mathrm{Meas}$. (And I’d probably also use $\coprod$ for toposes …)

Comment: Actually, though the small ⊓ and ⊔ are kind of cool, I think I too prefer the notation suggested by Tom Leinster (except maybe the $+$)

Answer (score 49):

I am fond of subscripting asymptotic notation with the parameters that the implied constant is allowed to depend on (and on the asymptotic parameter, if needed).  e.g.

- $X = O_k(Y)$ (or $X \ll_k Y$, or $Y \gg_k X$) means that $|X| \leq C_k Y$ for some $C_k$ depending only on $k$.
- $X = o_{n \to \infty; k}(Y)$ means that $|X| \leq c_k(n) Y$ for some function $c_k(n)$ of both $k$ and $n$, which goes to zero as $n \to \infty$ for fixed $k$.
- (Rarer) $X = O_{n \to \infty; k}(Y)$ means that $|X| \leq C_k Y$ whenever $n \geq N_k$, for some $C_k$ and $N_k$ depending only on $k$.

Of course, if there is a parameter that influences all the constants (e.g. the ambient dimension) then it is better to explicitly state at the beginning that all constants will depend on this parameter so that one does not have to put in the explicit subscripts in all the time.

It can be instructive to rewrite some basic notions in analysis in this sort of notation, just to get a slightly different perspective.  For instance, if $f: {\bf R} \to {\bf R}$ is a function, then:

- $f$ is continuous iff one has $f(y) = f(x) + o_{y \to x; f,x}(1)$ for all $x,y \in {\bf R}$
- $f$ is uniformly continuous iff one has $f(y) = f(x) + o_{|y-x| \to 0; f}(1)$ for all $x,y \in {\bf R}$
- A sequence $F = (f_n)_{n \in {\bf N}}$ of functions is equicontinuous if one has $f_n(y) = f_n(x) + o_{y \to x; F,x}(1)$ for all $x,y \in {\bf R}$ and $n \in {\bf N}$ (note that the implied constant depends on the family $F$, but not on the specific function $f_n$ or on the index $n$)
- A sequence $F = (f_n)_{n \in {\bf N}}$ of functions is uniformly equicontinuous if one has $f_n(y) = f_n(x) + o_{|y-x| \to 0; F}(1)$ for all $x,y \in {\bf R}$ and $n \in {\bf N}$
- $f$ is differentiable iff one has $f(y) = f(x) + (y-x) f'(x) + o_{y \to x; f,x}(|y-x|)$ for all $x,y \in {\bf R}$;
- (similarly for uniformly differentiable, equidifferentiable, etc.)

(These formulations are close to the nonstandard analysis formulations of these concepts, which uses similar but not quite identical asymptotic notation, but that is another story.)

Comment: The subscripts seem a little bulky.  Couldn't you just write, e.g. $f(y) = f(x) + o_{y \to x; f,x}(1)$?  I guess it's not really changing much.

Comment: Fair enough.  I did it the other way initially to compare the uniform and non-uniform notions, but I've edited the non-uniform notions to reflect the more intuitive subscripting you propose.

Comment: Maybe it's time for you to go to *really big-O* notation: $X=\underset{n\to\infty}{\overset{k}{\LARGE\mathcal O}} Y$ for $O(\cdot)$ and then $f_n(y)=f_n(x)+\underset{|y-x|\to 0}{\overset{F}{\LARGE\mathrm O}} 1$. for $o(\cdot)$. :D

Comment: The "really" big-O notation is a little bit confusing; since normally we write summation like this with $Y$ depends on the parameter $k$, but here we have the constant $C_k$ depends on it instead.

Comment: Chang: definite sums can depend on their upper index.

Comment: I think O-o notation is one of the worse. It does not worth to improve --- better to start from scratch.

Comment: Why does the sense of the big-$O$ notation switch between $X = O_k(Y)$ ($\lvert X\rvert$ is *majorised* by a constant multiple of $Y$) and $X = O_{n \to \infty; k}(Y)$ ($\lvert X\rvert$ is *minorised* by a constant multiple of $Y$)?

Comment: Oops, somehow that typo got missed for a decade.  Fixed now.

Answer (score 47):

$a \vee b$ and $a \wedge b$ to denote the maximum and minimum of the numbers $a$ and $b$.  (This seems to be well-known only among probabilists.)

Comment: This notation is also used in a lattice or Boolean algebra
for least-upper-bound and greatest-lower-bound, which
agrees with your meaning in a total order, such as the
reals.


Comment: Andy Browder uses this notation for real functions in the textbook I'm currently teaching from.

Comment: Sometimes I have seen $a \cup b$ and $a \cap b$ for the greatest common divisor and least common multiple of positive integers $a, b$. Much better than $(a, b)$.

Comment: AByer, it's by analogy with $\cup$ and $\cap$ that I remember that $\vee$ is maximum and $\wedge$ is minimum. (Otherwise I tend to think that since $\vee$ points down, it must be the minimum.)

Comment: Actually, I find this notation incredibly frustrating for the reason Michael mentions in his comment; $a\vee b$  is "clearly" a cartoon of a point lying below both $a$ and $b$.

Comment: $[a \vee b] = [a] \vee [b]$

Comment: @JBL: Maybe we should think temporally: lesser elements are earlier ("in the beginning there was the empty set"), and greater elements come later; then it makes sense to imagine a lattice with the least element at the beginning (top) of the page, and the greatest element at the end (bottom).

The alternative would be to decide that we have been using the wrong partial order on subsets and swap the notation for maximum and minimum (intersections increase information, unions reduce it).

Comment: ...so what is one supposed to do if one needs to say something involving AND's and OR's? I like to reserve $\wedge$ and $\vee$ for logical statements.

Comment: @Ketil Tveiten, what about `&` and `|` for logical connectives?

Comment: @JBL and  @David MJC. What does the set of all upper bounds of $\{a,b\}$ look like in a lattice? A cone with vertex pointing downwards $\vee$. The vertex is the supremum (least upper bound). What does the set of all lower bounds of $\{a,b\}$ look like in a lattice? A cone with vertex pointing upwards $\wedge$. The vertex is the infimum (greatest lower bound).

Comment: @L Spice: also $||$ could be used for "OR" in logical formulas (as in the program Mathematica, if I'm not mistaken)

Comment: @Qfwfq, that's a better idea—I hadn't considered how poor my suggestion would be at expressing disjunctions of statements involving divisions.

Comment: APL uses $A\mathbin{\lceil}B$ and $A\mathbin{\lfloor}B$ for thesse which I believe are much more intuitive.

Comment: @ArendBayer: re "much better than $(a,b)$". The notation "$(a,b)$" has a saving grace though: it is not only a notation definitionally equal to $\mathrm{gcd}(a,b)$ but it is in tune with standard commutative algebra: if we interpret $(,)$ in the usual way as "indeal generated by", then $(a,b) = (\mathrm{gcd}(a,b) ) _{\mathbb{Z}}$. For example, $(4,6) = (2) = (\mathrm{gcd}(4,6))_{\mathbb{Z}}$. Works more generally for principal ideal domains such as the Gaussian integers.

Comment: I write that $a\land b$ is read as "$a$ *and* $b$" (because a command for $\land$ is `\land` though it can be `\wedge`); and $a\lor b$ is read as "$a$ *or* $b$" (because a command for $\lor$ is `\lor` though it can be `\vee`). Then $a\barwedge b$ is read as "*greatest common divisor* of $a$ and $b$" and $a\veebar b$ is read as "*lowest common multiple* of $a$ and $b$".

Comment: For greatest common divisor and least common multiple, I use $\curlywedge$ and $\curlyvee$, respectively, and I use $\preceq$ for the divides relation usualy denoted by | because I prefer an assymetric symbol for an order relation.

Comment: @KetilTveiten You could just say "cap" and "cup", with the implied specification that you mean the "triangular cap" and "triangular cup".

Answer (score 44):

Instead of $[X]$ one often sees $\mathbf 1_{X}$ (especially in probability work?). This is neat because it literally is *1 on $X$*. Also it has the advantage over $[X]$ that you can write things like $(2+\mathbf 1_{X})^2$ for the function that is $9$ when $X$ occurs and $4$ otherwise; $(2+[X])^2$ would be less appealing here. On the other hand, if there is a lot of notation replacing "$X$" this is not so good:
$$\mathbf 1_{n_k\in \{n: n\text{ prime}\}}.$$

Comment: so how about $1[X]$?

Comment: $\mathbf{1}_X$ is conventionally used for characteristic function of a set.

Comment: The problem with 1_{X}, as you observed, is that it pushes the main stuff to the small font of the subscript. I don't understand the advantage you wrote of: what's wrong with (2+[X])²? IIRC, expressions of this sort are used without hesitation in Graham-Knuth-Patashnik (*Concrete Mathematics*).

Answer (score 43):

I once came across the notation $\underline{n}$ for the set $\lbrace 1,2,\dots,n\rbrace$.  It came in very handy to write $i \in \underline{n}$ instead of $1\leq i \leq n$ or $i \in \lbrace 1,2,\dots,n\rbrace$.

Comment: Sometimes people write ${}[n]$ for this. I agree, a shorthand of this kind is quite useful. 

Comment: I've seen this often as $[n]$.

Comment: In set theory, every ordinal number is equal to the set of
smaller ordinal numbers (a definition due to von Neumann),
and this makes for infinitely many conveniences similar to the ones you mention. Thus,
n={0,1,...,n-1} and in general $\alpha=\{\beta |
\beta\lt\alpha\}$.


Comment: In Ramsey theory, sometimes it actually matters to use $\{1,\dots,n\}$ rather than $\{0,\dots,n-1\}$, so the ${}[n]$ notation is useful (even though I would much like to just use the set theoretic $n$) but I have found ${\bf n}$ may be better sometimes. For example, one also uses interval notation, so ${}[a,b]=\{i\in{\mathbb N}\mid a\le i\le b\}$, and using both may look confusing. Plus, the beloved $[X]^k$ (the collection of $k$-sized subsets of $X$) now gets *really* confusing. I've seen Di Prisco use $X^{[k]}$, probably to avoid this issue.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments.  I guess the reason why the notation $[n]$ did not arise is that this was in the context of Lie-like algebras where the square brackets were used for the multiplication.

Comment: I like both notations (underlined $n$ and $[n]$).

Comment: Note also that the logicians would denote the set {$0, \cdots , n-1$} simply with the symbol $n$ (thought of as a finite ordinal).

Comment: In numerical linear algebra MATLAB notation is sometimes (ab)used, e.g. `1:n`.

Comment: I like $i = \overline{1, n}$

Comment: This can be confusing though, since the topologist's simplex $[n]$ is the ordered set $\{0<...<n\}$.  The rationale is that $n$ counts the number of arrows.  

Comment: Also, if I'm not mistaken, enumerative algebraic geometers use $[n]$ to denote {$1, \cdots , n$}.

Comment: @Andres Caicedo, see also Richard Stanley's answer: $\binom{X}{k}$ is a nice notation for the $k$-subsets of a set $X$, mirroring the binomial coefficient $\binom{x}{k}$.

Comment: I like too the notation/definition n:={0,1,..,n-1} but note that it becomes problematic outside the ordinal category. If e.g. $f:n\to m$ is any map between $n$ and $m$, how to distinguish the value f(k) from the image of the subset k:={0,1,..,k-1}? 

Comment: @Pietro: that's not a problem of the "ordinal" notation, it's a problem of the $f(A)$ notation for denoting images os subsets $A \subseteq X$ of the domain of an $f:X\to Y$. Logicians solve this problem using square brackets as in $f[A]\subseteq Y$. Personally, I would prefer the notation $f_*(A)$ for images of subsets and $f^{*}(B)$ for preimages.

Comment: @J.M. That "Matlab notation" actually first appeared in ALGOL and FORTRAN in the 60s.

Comment: I've often seen the notation $\mathbb{E}_n$ for this.

Comment: $\left\lbrack n\right\rbrack$ might be more appropriate, as it relates to *congruence classes* (see [here](https://math.okstate.edu/people/binegar/3613/3613-l11.pdf)). But I like $\underline n$ better because I might use $\left\lbrack n\right\rbrack$ to denote substitutions; e.g. $x+y=\left\lbrack 3\right\rbrack + \left\lbrack 5\right\rbrack = 8$. Say I had $ax+y$ and used circular brackets instead, I get $a(3)+(5)$ and now $a$ looks like a function, not a value.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins The ordinal definition is a great convenience for notation because it means you can treat $A^n$ as literally $n \rightarrow A$. For example, the application of an elementwise function $f : K \rightarrow K$ to a vector $x \in K^n$ is just $f \circ x$. These and other notational conveniences have brought me around to the belief that [natural numbers should indeed be treated as sets](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1021266519848).

Answer (score 43):

1. For rising and falling factorials: $x^{\overline{n}}$ and $x^{\underline{n}}$ *à la* Knuth. Much better than the traditional way to write the Pochhammer symbol: $(x)_n := x^{\overline{n}}$. In a book I'm writing, I use the notation $x^{\uparrow n}$ and $x^{\downarrow n}$, which I find much less clumsy (consider $(2x+1)^{\overline{6k-2}}$ vs $(2x+1)^{\uparrow6k-2}$). Anyway, the utility in either of these notations is seen in the umbral calculus; it makes the connection to "ordinary" calculus much more apparent, such as with $$\Delta x^{\uparrow n} = n x^{\uparrow n-1}\qquad\text{compared to}\qquad D x^n = nx^{n-1}.$$
2. The simple idea of omitting parentheses for function application: $f\,x$ as opposed to $f(x)$. I think this often makes some mathematics look cleaner, especially when the argument isn't especially complex. It also allows for some nice (= convenient) abuse of notation, such as in $$\left[ (-1)^{p - m - n} z \prod_{j = 1}^p \left( z D_z - a_j + 1 \right) - \prod_{j = 1}^q \left( z D_z - b_j \right) \right] G(z) = 0,$$ where $D_z:=d/dz$. Note this equation isn't a product (entirely); upon expansion, we'd have $D_z G(z)$ terms.
3. Do fractions count? Imagine having to write $$\sqrt{(x^2 + 2x + 1)\div (5x^3 - 3x^2 + 2x - 7)}$$ instead of $$\sqrt{\frac{x^2 + 2x + 1}{5x^3 - 3x^2 + 2x - 7}}.$$
4. Big-O notation. Though often abused, this is a much less clumsy way to express boundedness and asymptotics and errors and even lets you begin to do some algebra with them (provided you're careful). I don't think doing such is as obvious when you write it all out manually.
5. $\square(x)$ for the square wave, $\triangle(x)$ for the triangle wave, $Ш(x)$ for the Dirac comb (seriously, see Appel's "Mathematics for Physics and Physicists"). These are more cute than explicitly useful.
6. Notation used with musical isomorphisms as a way to do raising and lowering of indices. We have $X^\sharp$ which raises the index (in the context of Einstein summation) and $X^\flat$ which lowers the index. Here, $\flat$ and $\sharp$ are isomorphisms between tangent $TM$ and cotangent bundles $T^*M$: $\flat:TM\to T^*M$ and $\sharp:T^*M\to TM$.
7. Using $\operatorname{cis}\theta = \cos\theta + \mathrm{i}\sin\theta$ (*cosine i sine*), which is nice for obvious reasons (yes, $\omega = e^{\mathrm{i}\theta}$ is nice too) and $\operatorname{cas}\theta = \cos\theta + \sin\theta$ (*cosine and sine*), which is used in e.g., the Hartley transform.
8. Notations for hypergeometric functions $${}_pF_q \!\left( \left. \begin{matrix} a_1, \dots, a_p \\\\ b_1, \dots, b_q \end{matrix} \; \right| \, z \right) = {}_pF_q(\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b};z)$$ and Meijer-$G$ functions: $$G_{p,q}^{m,n} \!\left( \left. \begin{matrix} a_1, \dots, a_p \\\\ b_1, \dots, b_q \end{matrix} \; \right| \, z \right)=G_{p,q}^{m,n} \!\left( \left. \begin{matrix} \mathbf{a} \\\\ \mathbf{b} \end{matrix} \; \right| \, z \right)$$
9. Notation for general continued fractions: $$\underset{j=1}{\overset{\infty}{\LARGE\mathrm K}}\frac{a_j}{b_j}=\cfrac{a_1}{b_1+\cfrac{a_2}{b_2+\cfrac{a_3}{b_3+\ddots}}}.$$ The $\mathrm{K}$ comes from German's "Kettenbruch", which is "continued fraction."

I think that's good for now. There are probably lots more. :)

To end, I'll say one notation I do not like: the use of fraktur. Most of the time it just looks ugly and no one can actually write fraktur letters.

Comment: 1. I use overbars for conjugating complex numbers so I'm still discomfited by Knuth's suggestion on Pochhammer. I have to agree that there should be a better notation that calls to mind the analogy between the rising/falling factorials and ordinary powers.

Comment: 5. I think it was Bracewell who first used these.

Comment: 8. I'm starting to agree with some authorities that the $p$ and $q$ subscripts for hypergeometric functions are superfluous; just setting of the the numerator and denominator parameters in a two-row array suffices. On the other hand, if you're constrained to write on one line, then it is a great help to have those subscripts, and large enough delimiters to separate the numerator parameters, the denominator parameters, and the argument.

Comment: 9. I am a fan of this. :D

Comment: J.M., the hypergeometric functions with p,q is just tradition I guess. But also it is useful when you have arbitrary vectors as arguments. Also you can talk about different functions (e.g., 2F1, 1F2, etc.) out of context without having to describe which one you're talking about.

Comment: Well, in a sentence like "The series for the Kummer function ${}_1 F_1$ converges on the unit disc", the subscripts are certainly useful. I'm saying that if you're going to present the numerator and denominator parameters as an array then there should be no need for the subscripts.

Comment: For 9... at least in my personal notes I use a slightly different notation: $\underset{j=1}{\overset{\infty}{\LARGE\mathrm K}}\bigl(b_j \bigm\backslash a_j\bigr)$ ; I have to fight the tendency to cancel factors in the original notation, so I decided to use a special delimiter for this.

Comment: J.M. Yes, that is a useful point. I always get the temptation to do such too. Hatcher uses $\raise{5pt}{a_1}\!\!\!\nearrow\!\!\!\raise{-5pt}{b_1} + \raise{5pt}{a_2}\!\!\!\nearrow\!\!\!\raise{-5pt}{b_2} + \cdots$ for continued fractions, which I quite like. Perhaps $\underset{j=1}{\overset{\infty}{\LARGE\mathrm K}}\left(\raise{5pt}{a_j}\!\!\!\nearrow\!\!\!\raise{-5pt}{b_j}\right)$ would be a nice alternative.

Comment: Knuth's <i> x to the n falling </i> is $x^{\underline{n}}$, not $x_{\underline{n}}$.

Comment: I don't like the cis(θ) notation because it depends on the non-canonical choice of the square root of 1 (i.e., i).  The exp(iθ) notation is better because the non-canonical choice is clearly visible.

Comment: Mr Anold: Whoops, I blame it on being late. :) Fixed now.

Mr Pavlov: that is true of course. cis and cas seem to be more apparent in texts where algorithms are discussed (fast Fourier transform, fast Hartley transform, etc.). I don't think I'd use it in a pure mathematical context. :)

Comment: You're wrong that nobody can write Fraktur letters. If you put some effort into it then you absolutely can draw them. 

Comment: I like fraktur but some of the letters are difficult to recognize, especially if you never seen those before.

Comment: @KConrad: Sure you can, but you shouldn't. As with other scripts (say Latin or Cyrillic), the old script for writing German has a version for typesetting and a version for handwriting: Sütterlin (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sütterlin). If you like Fraktur, you will love it.

Comment: Re 6: as someone not familiar with coordinate notations and abstract indices, I can never remember which indices are up and which are down. Hence I think of "flat" as losing information e.g., replacing a tangent vector X by the 1-form g(X,.). To recover a tangent vector from a 1-form takes some work: you have to invert g! That's sharp.

Comment: @Bourrigan: I whole-heartedly disagree. Fraktur letters aren't that hard to write, and are easy to read. Sütterlin is illegible spaghetti, and even worse, the letters more often than not aren't what you expect them to be (the 'h' looks like an 'f', the 'e' like an 'n', etc.). It would be severely unpedagogical to use the script for anything other than to demonstrate how not to make a legible script.

Comment: According to dict.leo.org, "Bruch" is "break", "fracture", "fissure", "violation", etc., and "Ketten" is chain.  But the same source translates "Kettenbruch" as "continued fraction".  Does someone think of a continued fraction as the point at which a chain breaks?

Comment: "Bruch" is also the standard word for "fraction" in German, so the literal translation would be "chain fraction".  

Comment: 2. It's convenient but at most times clear enough to leave the parentheses when using multi-letter function names, $\sin x$ instead of $\sin(x)$. In typesetting you can distinguish such functions from ordinary multiplication by using a different font. In handwriting you can use ligatures to indicate "this is a function name as a whole".

Answer (score 43):

The notation for transversality:

$M \pitchfork N$

Comment: I like to use an analogous symbol for tangency: an intersection "cap" with a bar over it, tangential to it.

Answer (score 40):

Writing $\int_{x=0}^{2 \pi} \sin x dx$ rather than $\int_0^{2 \pi} \sin x dx$ can be very useful when there are integrals stacked several layers deep. EG

$$\int_{x=-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{y=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(x^2+y^2)/(2 \sigma)} dx dy = \int_{r=0}^{\infty} \int_{\theta=0}^{2 \pi} e^{-r^2/(2 \sigma)} r dr d\theta.$$

Comment: David, you forgot the $dydx$ on the left.  

Comment: This can also be done by writing $\int_x^{2\pi} dx\, \sin x$ etc., which is a little bit shorter. I have often seen this in physics.

Comment: Do you still need the $dx dy$ on the left if you specify the integration variable in the left part of the symbol?

Comment: @Federico: the "$dx$" is very expressive in integrals for a variety of reasons. It makes clear that what you are integrating is actually a differential form, which is useful even in one dimension: for example $\int f(u)du=\int f(u(t))u'(t)dt$, and $\int_{t=a}^b udv=uv|_a^b-\int_{t=a}^b vdu$. Also, in Physics it makes physical quantities add up correctly ($\int F\cdot ds$ for the work done by a force makes it clear that work is measured in units of force *times* units of length).

Comment: It's also useful when there's variable changes flying around in the background.  I teach my calculus students this notation at the same time we go over $u$-substitution in an attempt to cut down on the number of students plugging in their $x$-boundaries for $u$.

Comment: This also makes integrals better parallel their sigma cousins $\sum_{n = 0}^\infty$.  (Although I've always somewhat guiltily objected to $\sum_{n = -\infty}^\infty$ for the pedantic reason that we never actually have $n = -\infty$ ….)

Answer (score 32):

> The [abstract index notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_index_notation).

The original problem with the indices was that they were used to label coordinates, so mathematicians preferred more and more coordinate independent operators, while physicists continued to use indices. Then, Penrose realized that it has to be something beyond the indices that makes them useful - mainly the Einstein summation convention - and proposed the *abstract index notation*. This notation is almost identical in form with that of coordinate indices, but it is invariant, like the notation used by mathematicians, and maintains the simplifications due to the use of indices. The indices are not interpreted as labeling coordinates, but as representing the type of vectors and tensors and how they act on each other.

I think that there are advantages and disadvantages in both notations. Though, many tensor operations, especially contraction and type change, are easier to define and perform by using indices.

The following fields can benefit of this notation: Linear Algebra, Representation Theory, Group Theory, Differential Geometry.

This notation can naturally be related to [Penrose's diagrammatic notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_graphical_notation).

Comment: I agree that abstract index notation was a brilliant observation. However, the problem with tensor calculus in general and (abstract) indices in particular, is that it does not conceptualize the calculations being performed. This can be very pragmatic, as a tensor expression admits multiple interpretations, but it can also be confusing. For instance a contraction could be indicating composition, an inner product, or a trace, while skew symmetrization could be indicating a wedge product or a Lie bracket.

Comment: @David MJC: That's one reason because I like it. Some operations like those you mentioned are, from a viewpoint, indeed "equivalent". We can see this notation like a forgetful functor, or as a polymorphism in object oriented programming. It introduces a higher layer of abstraction, which allows us to see relations between apparently unrelated things. You are right that it hides some concepts, but it reveals others. At a much smaller scale it is like Category Theory, exposing hidden connection and general patterns.
But I do not prefer it over using operators, I view them somehow complementary.

Answer (score 31):

I like to interpret $f(x)$ as meaning $f\circ x$, otherwise known as the pullback $x^*f$. For instance $x$ could be the standard real valued coordinate on a line. This makes rigorous sense of the concept of a "variable" and hence also dependent and independent variables ($y=f(x)$). In the example of functions on a line, $f'=dy/dx$ is simply a ratio of 1-forms.

Such an interpretation also answers the common complaint that $f=f(x)$ confuses a function with its values. Instead it represents the very common shorthand of omitting pullbacks!

Comment: Did you invent it your-self? If not did you see this notation in some books?

Comment: Any book which describes a function f as a relation y=f(x) between dependent and independent variables is using this notation, so in that sense I didn't invent it. Also for mathematicians such as E.Cartan, points were always variable, i.e., functions on some unspecified parameter space: $x\in X$ means "x is a function on an unspecified domain with values in X", which is Grothendieck's "functor of points".

However, I don't have a reference for my interpretation, and it does generate a laugh (e.g. in a colloquium) to say that confusing a function and its values amounts to omitting pullbacks.

Comment: This one is nice both because: a) it makes sense of the reverse-Polish notation for functions, $f(x) = xf$, and b) it makes sense of the term "random variable" in probability, which it took me a long time to understand the meaning of.

Comment: This point of view is espoused in Munroe's 1958 AMM article "Bringing calculus up to date" (http://www.jstor.org/stable/2308879).  He gives a very little bit of history, mostly without references.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin have you never seen people talk about "the function f(x)" ?

Answer (score 30):

The notation $\perp$ to denote either orthogonality, or to indicate independent random variables, or perhaps even to indicate relatively prime numbers.

Comment: Wait, if $n \perp m$ means that n and m are relatively prime, then does $(n,m)$ represent their inner product?  Far out...

Comment: ;-) --- anyhow, it seems that Knuth advocates the $\perp$ notation for relative primeness on p.126 of Concrete Mathematics, a book wherein several other pieces of great notation are described by him.

Comment: With Knuth's proposal to write $k \perp n$ for `k relatively prime to n' we can write by the Moebius inversion formula $\sum_{1 \le k \le n} \left[ k \perp n \right] = \sum_{1 \le k \le n} \left[ k \mid n \right] \mu\left(\frac{n}{k}\right).$ Note that by the conventions of the Iverson bracket when the Iverson-bracketed statement is false, it `annihilates anything it is multiplied by - even if that other factor is undefined'.


Comment: Ryan, how about <log n, log m> = log (n,m) ?

Comment: @David: I think it's appropriate for the "inner product" to be a (bi-)multiplicative function rather than an additive one, since "orthogonality" is a multiplicative concept.  Note: "far out" was a term of appreciation!

Comment: Thanks for answering! I agree with you that forcing the concept to be additive rather than multiplicative is artificial, but I hope it was at least a little bit humorous. :)

Comment: I don't like $\perp$ for stochastic independence, since Hilbert space orthogonality of random variables is correlation=0, not independence. So for independe we should use $\Perp$!

Comment: There is also a nice use of $\bot$ in logic to mean absurdity, i.e. the negation of $\top$.  

Comment: The mobius formula suggestion of Bruce’s comment. I needed to see it: $\sum_{1 \le k \le n} \left[ k \perp n \right] = \sum_{1 \le k \le n} \left[ k \mid n \right] \mu\left(\frac{n}{k}\right).$

Comment: $\mu\perp \nu$ is also used for mutually singular measures, i.e., each is supported in a null set of the other

Answer (score 29):

A good notation and a bad notation (in my opinion).

Good: $p' = (1 - \frac1p)^{-1}$. It is commonly enough used in analysis (Holder inequality) that it is good to have a shorthand, and it makes clear that the conjugate exponents are dual pairs: $(p')' = p$.

Bad: $p^* = \frac{np}{n-p}$ the Sobolev conjugate in Sobolev inequalities. It hides the dependence on the spatial dimension $n$, and overloads the $ * $ for something that does not have a duality: $(p^* )^* = \frac{(2p)^*}{2} \neq p$.

Comment: Having shorthand for the dual to a norm is indeed convenient $\left|\mathbf{A}\right|_{p^{\prime}}$. :D But maybe there is a better superscript than the already heavily used prime?

Comment: @J.M.: both of these are historical (so don't blame me for them); also, when else do you see a prime applied to a number? 

Comment: @Willie, it is a convenient way to denote zero!

Comment: I'm definitely not blaming you (and it's also what I see in the literature); just that the prime looks to be an overloaded symbol that maybe there should be something different we can use.

Comment: Ah, so we could write Euler's formula as $\sum_{n \geq 0} n^{-s} = \prod_p (p')^s$! 

Comment: I like Todd's pun very much, although it should be $\sum_{n\geq 0} n^{-s} = \prod_p (p^s)'$, shouldn't it? Anyway "Zeta(s) is the product over p prime of p to the power s prime" reads nicely!

Comment: If one followed the convention mentioned [elsewhere](https://mathoverflow.net/a/291557) in this question of indicating a sum (or product) indexed by primes by appending a prime, then one could even write $\sum_{n \ge 0} n^{-s} = \prod^\prime_p (p^s)'$.

Answer (score 26):

I really like the arrow notation for limits: $$\frac{\sin(x)}{x} \xrightarrow{x\rightarrow 0} 1.$$ I've seen people use this on the blackboard, but I don't think I've seen it in print. The right-hand side of an arrow expression can be decorated with a "+" or "-": $$\frac{\sin(x)}{x} \xrightarrow{x\rightarrow 0^+} 1^-.$$ Arrow expressions can be treated as propositions (e. g., $x\rightarrow 0$ implies $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\rightarrow 1$), but this is usually less succinct than the stacked arrows. However, it's easier to chain limits this way:

> If $f$ and $g$ are continuous [in the sense of elementary calculus], then so is $f\circ g$: if $a$ is fixed and $x\rightarrow a$, then $g(x)\rightarrow g(a)$ (since $g$ is continuous), so $f(g(x)) \rightarrow f(g(a))$ (since $f$ is continuous), QED.

This can be made rigorous, say, with nonstandard analysis, although there are probably more elementary ways.

Sometimes, we need to use a limit as a subexpression in a formula, rather than just stating that the limit equals something. For this, I like the notation $f(x)|_{x\rightarrow a}$ in favor of $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)$. To me, it's an obvious and intuitive extension of the notation $A(x)|_{x=a}$, which is commonly used to denote the expression that results when $x$ is replaced by $a$ in the expression $A(x)$ (in which $x$ occurs free).

Comment: Interesting... could you tell where you saw this first?

Comment: @J. M. - actually, I can't recall. :-( It's possible that I use it more than others, but I'm certainly not the inventor. I probably haven't seen "x -> a" treated as a proposition exactly as I did above, but it's basically equivalent to "x~a" (in nonstandard analysis, to mean that the difference between x and a is smaller than all standard positive reals). 

Comment: As an undergraduate in Cape Town I saw and used "$\frac{\sin x}{x} \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow 0$" almost as often as the $\lim$ notation.

Comment: This notation was always present in my education (in Bremen) and is especially popular in functional analysis where there is $\to$ for strong convergence and $\rightharpoonup$ for weak convergence.

Comment: @Max, I hope your post-undergraduate education has taught you a different value for that limit!

Answer (score 25):

I found the notation $K_\bullet$ for a complex (in with objects an abelian category or as an objects of the derived category) is very helpful. Otherwise people have to write something like $\cdots \to K_{n}\to \cdots \to K_{2}\rightarrow K_{1} \to K_{0}$ which just contains exactly the same amount of information.

Answer (score 24):

As a freshman, I "invented" the notation

$H \lhd ! \; G$

to say that $H$ is a *characteristic* subgroup of $G$, i.e. a subgroup invariant under any automorphism of $G$ (whereas a *normal* subgroup $N\lhd G$ is only invariant under the inner automorphisms).

Comment: I love this! :)

Answer (score 24):

Since the standard notation for open interval $(a,b)$ can be confused with the coordinates, gcd, and other stuffs (open brackets have been used A LOT!), I've seem notations like

$]a,b[$

occurred in the book "Elementary Classical Analysis" by Marsden,
and we can denote half-open half-closed interval like this:

$]a,b]$ or $[a,b[$.

Comment: For a similar reason, Munkres uses $a\times b$ instead of $(a,b)$ for an element of $A\times B$.

Comment: I have to -1 this one. Nothing annoys me more than seeing $[x,y[ \cup ]a,b[$ and such. 

Comment: Bourbaki does this, and I'm a fan.

Comment: I was a fan of this notation until I read Quadrescence's comment.

Comment: The point is that $]a,b[$ is the French way to write the open interval (this explains Harry's comment). It is still taught in high school, and students never learn about $(a,b)$, even at university. Only researchers adapt to this notation once they write in English. I agree that $]a,b[$ is clearer.

Comment: The notation $]a, b[$ is ok, except that it makes some text editors (while doing paren-matching) balk.

Comment: It seems that we need a new notation which is better than both $(a,b)$ and $]a,b[$... any idea?

Comment: This won't render, I bet, but how about `\ullcorner` and `\ulrcorner` from MnSymbol?  Or `\lwavy`/`\rwavy` from the same package (see symbols-a4.pdf, page 55).  They both have a suitable "open" feel, and I especially like the first since they are, literally, brackets which are open.

Comment: @Ryan Reich: Quadrescence's example is only annoying when improperly typeset. Look at the difference in LaTeX between $[x,y[\cup]a,b[$ `[x,y[\cup]a,b[` versus $\left[x,y\right[\cup\left]a,b\right[$ `\left[x,y\right[\cup\left]a,b\right[`.

Comment: \ullcorner and \ulrcorner are nice, I've thought about it!

Comment: It was used also in the former Soviet block.

Comment: I prefer Knuth's notation, which uses $ (a.\,.b) $ for the open interval and $ [a.\,.b] $ for the closed one.


Comment: I could be wrong, but I was kind of under the impression that this notation ]a,b[ is more common than (a,b) in France.

Comment: I also learned it like $]a,b[$ in school (Germany) but since I am reading research articles I got used to $(a,b)$.

Comment: I've always used semicolon for intervals:

$$(a;b)\qquad [a;b)\qquad (a;b]\qquad [a;b]$$

Also, for composition of functions, to avoid a confusion with multiplication, I use $\bigcirc^n f$ for powers, and in particular $\bigcirc^{-1}f$ for the inverse.

Comment: Actually the power notation can be used for any 2-argument operation. For instance:

$$n\cdot a\ \ :=\ \ \sum^n a$$

and

$$a^n\ \ :=\ \ \prod^n a$$

Etc.

Comment: @Wlodzimierz: isn't it better to use the less bombastic $f^{\circ n}$ for composition powers? (and $f^{\circ (-1)}$ for the composition inverse, to nitpick)

Comment: @Qfwfq: perhaps this could be an option, perhaps a tricky option when things get complicated. My notation above is a part of my system.

Comment: @RossChurchley, another nice advantage of that notation is how easily it generalises:  $x \ltimes y$ lives in a semi-direct product, $x \otimes y$ lives in a tensor product, $x \wedge y$ lives in a wedge product, ….

Comment: @WillieWong The easiest fix is `${[x,y[}\cup{]a,b[}$` — note how the curly braces separate the intervals. To compare, the original is $[x,y[\cup]a,b[$, the braced-version is ${[x,y[}\cup{]a,b[}$.

Comment: Of course the best notation for intervals is `\open a b` and `\closed a b`, or whatever name makes sense to you, and then you can `\newcommand\open[2]{(#1, #2)}` or whatever you please and leave the journal to change it if they insist.  (If you like the French style, then `\newcommand\open[2]{\mathopen]#1, #2\mathclose[}` will space properly, like $\mathopen]x, y\mathclose[ \cup \mathopen]a, b\mathclose[$, and you can forget about `\mathopen` and `\mathclose` having once made the definition.)

Comment: *)Ouch.(* - [Graham, Knuth and Patashnik](https://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~knuth/gkp.html), p 63. In fact it's a joke about the failed attempt to use $]x[$ to mean $\lceil x \rceil$.

Answer (score 22):

To denote an action $\alpha: G\times X \rightarrow X$ of a group $G$ on a space $X$, there is the nice piece of notation:

$\alpha: G \curvearrowright X$

or simply

$G \curvearrowright X$  (the latter when the action is understood from the context).

E.g. you can say something like: $\rm{GL}(V) \curvearrowright V$ linearly. Or, to say that $W$ is an invariant subspace for $G \curvearrowright V$, you just write: $G \curvearrowright W$.

Another example: $\rm{Ad}:G \curvearrowright \mathfrak{g}$, and so on.

Comment: I prefer for the arrow to be a nearly-full circle, coming from X back to X. Warning: if you put the arrow on the lower part instead of upper, it looks like you've written G twice but in two different fonts.

Answer (score 22):

One can decorate a subscript or superscript by additional symbols to indicate what the subscript or superscript is doing.  For instance, consider a truncation $f 1_{|f| \leq N}$ of a function to its values whose magnitude is at most $N$.  One could of course call such a function something like $f_N$, but why not call it $f_{\leq N}$ instead?  Then one can do things like "Decompose $f = f_{\leq N} + f_{>N}$, where $f_{\leq N} := f 1_{|f| \leq N}$ and $f_{>N} := f 1_{|f| > N}$."  Notation of this type is sometimes used in PDE, particularly with regard to Littlewood-Paley frequency projections.

Similarly, one could imagine the operation of shifting $f$ by $N$ to be denoted something like $f_{+N}$ rather than $f_N$, etc..

Comment: Hum, I would prefer if $f 1_{|f| \leq N}$ be written as $f|_{\leq N}$ to make clear that it is a spatial cutoff. $f_{\leq N}$ suggest so me a vertical cut-off: $=f$ if $|f| \leq N$ and $=N$ otherwise. This could be a nice notation when doing Calderon-Zygmund...

Comment: I'm just making this up, but it seems you could be more consistent with the projection $[x^n]$ as in $[x^n]f(x)$ by doing something like $[\le N]f$: "Decompose $f=[\le N]f + [>N]f$", or if you're daring, "decompose $f=([\le N] + [>N])f$." 

Answer (score 22):

$$a^{\cdot \, n} = a\cdot a\cdots a$$
$$a^{\wedge \, n} = a\wedge a\wedge\dots\wedge a$$
$$a^{\,, \, n} = a,a,\dots,a$$
For example one could write
$$\langle(x+10y-z)^{\,, \, 2}\rangle= \langle(x+10y-z),(x+10y-z)\rangle.$$
or 
$$\sin^{\circ(-1)}x=\arcsin x$$
or
$$\sin^{\cdot(-1)}x=\frac1{\sin x}$$

Comment: In contrast, the insistence of Calculus textbooks to use $sin^{-1}$ for inverse or arc sine has baffled me. It throws even my best students off as being some kind of reciprocal, especially since we are already stuck with the idiosyncratic notation for powers like $sin^2(x)$

Comment: Sorry, should have read on and posted this under Blake's answer below.

Comment: That's why you shouldn't write $\sin^2(x)$, but $\sin(x)^2$. Also, one can mix up $\sin^2(x)$ with $\sin\sin(x)$.

Comment: The notion $f^{\circ 2}(x)$ for $f(f(x))$ is, while not common, pretty well-established in a number of references where there might be confusion with other uses.

Comment: @Turion, I have always used $\sin(x)^2$ for the reason you say, but then a possible confusion was pointed out to me:  what does $\sin(x + 1)^2$ mean?  Having to write $\bigl(\sin(x + 1)\bigr)^2$ is pretty awful.  (To be fair, the complainer's solution of using $(\sin x)^2$ doesn't address the ambiguity either.)

Answer (score 21):

I know some people absolutely DESPISE using coordinates and components to do "tensor analysis", but sometimes there is no recourse, and then Einstein's summation convention is a big help.

Comment: Have you ever seen Penrose's notation? It seems crazy at first, and I've never used it but it actually seems like a pretty good compromise between "abstract" notation and co-ordinates.

Comment: I love both Penrose's notation (which is to a first approximation the same as the string diagrams mentioned in another answer) and the Einstein summation convention.  Neither of them solves all problems; each is sometimes more efficient than the other.  (In particular, I find sums of several terms get ugly quickly in string diagrams.  So for proving an associativity, I'll typically try string diagrams first, but for proving a Jacobi identity, I'll go for Einstein summation.)

Answer (score 20):

$G \circlearrowleft X$ (or $G \circlearrowright X$) to denote that $G$ acts on $X$.

---

*Edit by A.H. :*
Here are some latex definitions that produce the symbol that David Speyer describes in his comment:

```
\def\acts{
\hspace{.1cm}
{
\setlength{\unitlength}{.30mm}
\linethickness{.09mm}
\begin{picture}(8,8)(0,0)
    \qbezier(7,6)(4.5,8.3)(2,7)
    \qbezier(2,7)(-1.5,4)(2,1)
    \qbezier(2,1)(4.5,-.3)(7,2)
    \qbezier(7,6)(6.1,7.5)(6.8,9)
    \qbezier(7,6)(5,6.1)(4.2,4.4)
    \end{picture}
\hspace{.1cm}
}}
```

and

```
\def\acted{
\hspace{.1cm}
{
\setlength{\unitlength}{.30mm}
\linethickness{.09mm}
\begin{picture}(8,8)(0,0)
    \qbezier(1,6)(3.5,8.3)(6,7)
    \qbezier(6,7)(9.5,4)(6,1)
    \qbezier(6,1)(3.5,-.3)(1,2)
    \qbezier(1,6)(1.9,7.5)(1.2,9)
    \qbezier(1,6)(3,6.1)(3.8,4.4)
    \end{picture}
\hspace{.1cm}
}}
```

Comment: I prefer $G \curvearrowright X$.

Comment: I use a notation like that, but I have not found it in latex: the closest I can find is $G\subset X$ but with the $\subset$ turned into an arrow (so that $G$ appears as the label on the arrow, you could say) I distinctly dislike using \circlearrowleft for this! :)

Comment: I actually don't use a full circle either; \circlearrowleft is the closest approximation to what I use, at least according to http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html.

Comment: @Mariano: Right click on Mark's formula and select Show source to see what he typed. AMSfonts required. See also table 105 in the comprehensive LaTeX symbol list, accessible with texlive using the command “texdoc symbols”.

Comment: In hand writing, I prefer a roughly 3/4 circle which starts at about 4 oclock and ends at about 2 oclock. That way the arrow starts at X and returns there. Important note: if draw the arrow going the other way, people may mistake it for a capital G.

Comment: When I posted my answer I didn't see this had already been addressed. I also prefer $\alpha: G \curvearrowright X$ for actions.

Comment: I agree with David Speyer. You want the arrow to begin and end at $X$ and go by way of $G$. (Not that this answers the original question, which was to come up with notation that substantially improves understanding...)

Comment: \lcirclearrowright in MnSymbol looks ok.

Comment: related question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/64544/what-is-the-standard-notation-for-group-action

Answer (score 20):

As mentioned in a comment, $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is much better notation than $[x]$ for denoting the greatest-integer function. Most especially since it doesn't collide with the $10^6$ other things that $[]$ is used for, e.g. the $0,1$ function Richard Borcherds mentioned.

I very much like, though haven't had much use for, the notation $n{q\atop \cdot}$ for $|GL_n(q)/B|$, pronounced "$n$ $q$-torial". Famously, it extends to a polynomial function of $q$, and when $q=1$ we have $n{1\atop \cdot} = n!$

(Oops: I left out the $/B$ the first time, thanks Jim and David.)

Comment: Allen, that's not quite right about the cardinality of $\mathrm{GL}_n(q)$. For instance, when $q=1$ you get $0$. (Maybe you want the number of points on $G/T$?)

Comment: I'm pretty sure G/B is what Allen wants.

Answer (score 19):

$f_*$ and $f^*$ for direct and inverse image. We really should use this right from the beginning, for functions $f\colon X\to Y$, where $f_*\colon P(X)\to P(Y)$ ($P(X)$ being the power set) and $f^*\colon P(Y) \to P(X)$ instead of the awful notations $f(A)$ and $f^{-1}(B)$ for subsets $A$ of $X$ and $B$ of $Y$.

Comment: Why do you think $f(A)$ and $f^{-1}(B)$ are awful?

Comment: I would say they are extremely confusing for beginners. Sometimes they think there is an inverse map $f^{-1}$.

Comment: Per Leo, it is indeed confusing for beginners, and not surprisingly so: f is being used both for a function from X to Y and for a function from P(X) to P(Y). This can even be ambiguous as well as confusing e.g., when the domain is a set such as {0,{0}}. And I further agree that the notation $f^{-1}$ for inverse image is likely to suggest there is an inverse function. It is but a small consolation that when there is an inverse function, the notations are self-consistent (because `$f^*=(f^{-1})_*$` in that case).

Comment: I have also seen $f^{\rightarrow}$ and $f^{\leftarrow}$.

Comment: I like $f^\rightarrow$ and $f^\leftarrow$ better, since when applying the inverse, it looks like: $(f^{-1})^\rightarrow = f^\leftarrow$.

Comment: I've also seen an instance in which the "$-1$" in $f^{-1}$ is written just on top of the $f$ instead of at the top right part. I think it originated from Bourbaki...

Answer (score 16):

> [Dirac's bra-ket notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_notation)

This notation is very useful when applying the Hilbert spaces in Quantum Theory. It exploits some properties of duality, eigenvalues/eigenvectors, projectors and self-adjoint operators. In mathematics, perhaps it is difficult to adopt, because mathematicians are using notations that are more general, and cannot exploit these particularities. But if you know Hilbert spaces you can learn this notation in one minute, and then it makes visible many of these nice properties.

Comment: I have to strongly disagree with the use many physicists do of the Dirac bra-ket notation, as I'm going to explain: mathematicians would use the $\langle\, |\, \rangle$ as a *function* with the "blank places" to be saturated by its 2 argument (or even $\langle\, | \, | \, \rangle$ as a function to be saturated by 3 arguments, the one in the middle being an operator as in $\langle \xi | \, A | \,\eta \rangle$) [continued]

Comment: [continued]  On the contrary, I have seen many physicists use the highly "dis-functional" notation $| \, \lambda \rangle$ to denote an eigenvector with $\lambda$ as eigenvalue, and so write things like: $A | \lambda \rangle=\lambda\cdot | \lambda \rangle$

Comment: There are other examples of notations which don't represent the missing arguments by blanks. One is the (abstract) index notation. An index which appears repeated in covariant and contravariant positions means contraction, and if it is not repeated, it represents a free slot that can be filled by contracting with another free slot of another tensor. The blank to be filled by an argument is not visible, but we know that a free index can do this. Another example is the Polish notation, where again we don't see the missing arguments as blanks.

Comment: I guess that one of the points of the Dirac notation is exactly this. A bra vector $\langle\psi|$ or a ket $|\varphi\rangle$ look "unsaturated" as and suggest that they may act on something. They are like two pieces of a puzzle. An operator $O$ and a projector $|\psi\rangle\langle \psi|$ are twice unsaturated. When saturated, $O$ has two angles $\langle\psi|O|\eta\rangle$ and it is a scalar.


Comment: @unknown (google). On the other hand, I like $|\lambda\rangle$ as eigenvector only if it is stated that $\lambda$ has multiplicity 1, otherwise is confusing. When multiplicity is 1, the confusion is avoided because in fact $|\lambda\rangle$ is a ray in the complex projective space.

Comment: There was a long, long discussion at the n-Category Cafe one time, started by how offensive "bra" was to someone (speaking as a woman). 


Comment: I was curious about the discussion @ToddTrimble [references](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/282599).  I think it is [a comment thread in "Mathematical Emotion"](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2009/11/mathematical_emotion.html#c029689).

Comment: @LSpice The link you gave contains a half-serious complaint about why it's "bra" and "ket", when "bracket" also contains a "c".
My answer is that between bra and ket there is a label, which is often a c-number, the eigenvalue. For example the position.

Answer (score 15):

The ever-controversial reverse Polish notation for functions: $f(x) = xf$.  Thus in composition, the order makes sense: $(g \circ f)(x) = x f g$ (this point is moot for the fortunate Hebrew- and Arabic-speaking mathematicians).  I hate this notation in practice but I can't deny that it is objectively right and "just makes sense" in more or less the same way that the original post discusses writing $B^A = A \to B$.  Please no one vote this up.

Comment: One partial compromise is to subscript a function $f: X \to Y$ as $f_{Y \leftarrow X}$.  For instance, the composition of two inclusion maps $\iota_{Z \leftarrow Y} \circ \iota_{Y \leftarrow X}$ becomes $\iota_{Z \leftarrow X}$.

Comment: Hehe, `objectively right'.

Comment: @Terry Tao: I've seen that one from time to time, and it is pretty nice when you are dealing with different spaces (especially when you have a category of them and, as you write, a functorial assignment of maps).  For self-maps of X, it leaves...something to be desired.

Comment: Abstractly an arrow from $X$ to $Y$ has and an orientation but no direction. It could be drawn either up/down/right/left/slant 30°/slant-45°/... . But we are heavy victims of the typographical habits, and this in spite of modern computer possibilities (not means :Tex being a terrible tool!). The best thing to do is to think of an arrow as slanted +200°or in three dimensions, then the typographical induction tends to disappear completely (at least for me and I guess for Hebrew/Arabic writers too). 
So the motto (not necessarily a categorist's one) is "let's do multidimensional algebra!".   

Comment: Haskell uses `&` for reverse application and `>>>` for reverse composition. I've [also seen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition#Alternative_notations) `;` used for reverse composition.

Comment: As a computer scientist, function application/composition leaves me desperate with an unresolved conflict. **For one,** I strongly support left-to-right notations, so that it plays well with arrows and diagrams and you get a sense of “segment addition”: $A, A \to B, B \to C$ [versus: $B \to C, A \to B, A$] telescopes into $C$. It is naturally read as “start from the *antecedent*, apply a transformation, then another”. **But** I’m also a fan of currying, which is not nice in left-to-right style: $y\,(x\,f)$ is the curried form of $(x,y)f$ [versus: $f\,x\,y$ being the curried form of $f(x,y)$].

Answer (score 15):

Here is a notation in algebraic geometry that in my opinion is very useful and self-explanatory but not used widely.

For a birational morphism $f:X\to Y$ there exists an open dense set $U\subseteq Y$ for which $f$ induces an isomorphism $f^{-1}U\to U$. For a closed subset $Z\subseteq Y$ such  that $Z\cap U\neq\emptyset$ the *strict transform* is defined as $$\overline{f^{-1}(Z\cap U)}\subseteq X,$$ i.e., the closure of the preimage of the part of $Z$ that lies on the part where the morphism is an isomorphism. This is a very important construction and there isn't a universally accepted notation for it.

János Kollár invented the following notation for this: $$f^{-1}_*Z:= \overline{f^{-1}(Z\cap U)}\subseteq X$$ The genius of the notation is that anyone familiar with basic notation in algebraic geometry should understand what it is:

1) As $f$ is birational, $f^{-1}: Y\dashrightarrow X$ exists as a rational map.

2) For any map $g$, it is common to use $g_*$ to denote push-forward of cycles.

The strict transform is really just the push-forward of cycles via the rational map $f^{-1}$.

Answer (score 14):

Diagrammatic notation for tensors (Penrose diagrams, birdtracks, etc.).  It makes many things like the invariance of tr(A B C) under cyclic permutation into empty statements.

Comment: One problem with notation that makes certain statements empty is that it obscures the fact that they're *not* empty—it is a fact, not a convention, that the trace is invariant under cyclic permutation, and a notation that doesn't allow one even meaningfully to state it runs the risk of obscuring understanding for novices.

Answer (score 14):

I like $ A^{\text{H}} $ for the conjugate transpose of the matrix $ A $, ananlogously to how $ A^{\text{T}} $ and $ A^{\text{C}} $ means the transpose and the conjugate.  You call it the *Hermitian* of the matrix for short.  I learnt this notation from Rózsa Pál, but I can't tell who invented it.

Comment: I use simply $A^\ast$ for this but I also saw $A^\dagger$ for both transpose and conjugate.

Comment: I also like $A^{-H}$ for $(A^H)^{-1}=(A^{-1})^H$. Often handy, but I suggest you not to try $A^{2H}$ or $A^{\frac12 H}$ (exercise: why is the latter ill-defined?)

Comment: @MarcelBischoff OP means $A^*$ is also used as conjugate, thus ambiguous. I came to a fan of $A^H$ and $A^C$.

Answer (score 14):

For quite some time, Giovanni Sambin has been advocating the notation $A\between B$ for "overlapping" sets, that is, for inhabited intersections, where $\exists_{x} \ x \in A \cap B$. He makes his case in a constructivist frame, but I think that a lot of ink, chalk---and keyboard pushing...---would be spared if one wrote $A\between B$ instead of $A\cap B \neq \emptyset$, even in non-constructive mathematics.

Comment: Doesn't extend nicely to $A\cap B\cap C\ne\varnothing$.

Comment: Well, one can just overload the overlapping symbol, $\between (A, B, C)$; it would again be more economical than the traditional exploitation of the associativity of $\cap$.

Comment: So we could write $\between (A, B) := (A\cap B = \varnothing)$ as well?

Comment: One must be careful with this type of notation, because one can be confused as to whether $A\between B$ denotes a set, or a statement about $A$ and $B$. A fix is to say: "we write $A\between B=C$ when we have $A \cap B=C$ and $A\cap B\neq \varnothing$", and to refrain from writing things like "now consider the set $A \between B$".

Comment: Nice. I'd use it _not_ for referring to a set (consider the set $A \between B$) but a _statement_ (consider $A$ and $B$ such that $A \between B$.

Answer (score 13):

The universal property of the univariate polynomial ring: For any commutative ring $A$, any commutative $A$-algebra $B$ and any $x\in B$, there exists one and only one $A$-algebra homomorphism from the polynomial ring $A\left[X\right]$ to $B$ which maps $X$ to $x$.

This is the so-called *evaluation homomorphism at $x$*. I denote this homomorphism by $\lim\limits_{X\to x}$. This has the advantage that we have $\lim\limits_{X\to 0}\dfrac{\left(X+1\right)^n-1}{X}=n$ and similar properties hold just as in classical analysis. The polynomial $\dfrac{\left(X+1\right)^n-1}{X}$ is well-defined (since $X$ is not a zero divisor in $A\left[X\right]$ and divides $\left(X+1\right)^n-1$), but if we would blindly replace $X$ by $0$ we would obtain a $\dfrac{0}{0}$ error.

Comment: Ah, I really like calculus-inspired notation for algebraic stuff, just like the integral for ends. Looking forward to see more in this spirit!

Comment: This looks beautifully created :) very neat

Answer (score 11):

**A)** Two notations I love are the rising factorial $x^\overline n$ and its falling factorial twin $x^\underline n$. They are used and advocated in the great book see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_Mathematics . In passing this book uses great notations.

**B)** A general trick with binomials to reuse them with sets instead of numbers, here are some typical examples.

1) $\binom S k $ to denote the set of all $k$-sets of the base set $S$ .

2) $S^\underline 2$ to denote the pairs $(x,y)$ of $S$ where $x$ and $y$ are different.

3) $S^\underline k $ to denote  the $k$- uplets of $S$ (each uplet has $k$ different elements).

**C)** Another notation I find useful when listing some (big) families of examples in a combinatorial setting. Use as variables the very numerals $1$ $2$ .. themselves instead of $x_1$ , $x_2$ ... . For example ( very untelling because too small an example) : the intersection of $123$ and $34$ is $3$.

**D)** I also often use {{ a,a,b,c}} for multiset. Any other standard or suggestion (or a way to avoid speaking about multiset) is welcome.

Comment: D)  Perhaps {$(a)^2, b, c$} for your multiset {{a,a,b,c}}

Comment: for unknowngoogle : this is even better without the parenthesis around a , yet it does not work with variables ${{a1, a2}}$ where you don't know if $a1$ equals $a2$. 

Comment: Perhaps $2a+b+c$ for your multiset: a 0-cycle.

Comment: @BenMcKay, I agree, since a (finitary) multiset on the symbols $X$ is just an element of the free Abelian monoid generated by $X$, which thereby becomes a "module over the semiring $\mathbb{N}$" in a canonical way.

Comment: (C) reminds me of a pet peeve of mine, which is unnecessarily indexed sets.  I frequently see something like "$\prod\limits_{i \in I} x_i$, where $\{x_i : i \in I\}$ is the set of primes not exceeding 200" rather than "$\prod\limits_{\substack{\text{$x$ prime} \\ x \le 200}} x$" (and other less transparently silly examples).

Answer (score 10):

In commutative algebra with many variables, repeating lists of variables in polynomial arguments and various rings gets very tedious. I suggest using $X_{1..n}$ instead of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$.

Here's an excerpt from Bourbaki's *Commutative Algebra*, page 222:

---

For every formal power series $f\in A[[X_1,\ldots,X_n]]$,
$$f(X_1,\ldots,X_n)-f(Y_1,\ldots,Y_n)=\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-Y_i)h_i(X_1,\ldots,X_n,Y_1,\ldots,Y_n)$$
where the $h_i$ belong to $A[[X_1,\ldots,X_n,Y_1,\ldots,Y_n]]$.

---

And here's how it looks with my suggested notation:

---

For every formal power series $f \in A[[X_{1..n}]]$,
$$ f(X_{1..n})-f(Y_{1..n})=\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-Y_i)h_i(X_{1..n},Y_{1..n})$$
where the $h_i$ belong to $A[[X_{1..n},Y_{1..n}]]$.

---

I think this notation is maximally succinct, and helps a reader from getting lost in long lists of variables.

Comment: I can see that being handy when one needs to call out some of the indices.  For your example from Bourbaki, I would sooner use X decorated with a hat or overbar to indicate a tuple.  Gerhard "That May Just Be Me" Paseman, 2013.02.03

Comment: You could combine with https://mathoverflow.net/a/42941 to get the still more succinct $X_{\underline n}$.

Answer (score 10):

I would love for topologists to start differentiating between properties that hold “locally” and properties that hold “regionally”, that is: A local property holds on *some neighbourhood basis* of every point, a regional property holds on *some neighbourhood* of every point. For any space, having a property locally implies having it regionally.

This would resolve the permanent confusion of “which sort of local” is meant in a given context.

Comment: There's something mathematically funny about a comment that begins "I would love for topologists to start differentiating".  

Answer (score 9):

This is probably the exact opposite of what the thread starter intended, but here's an instance where it might have been useful to have overloaded notation! I recently found that in propositional logic, $p \to q$ obeys much the same rules as exponentiation $q^p$: for instance, we have $(r^q)^p = r^{q \times p}$, and similarly, $p \to (q \to r)$ iff $p \land q \to r$. This is apparently due to the universal property for exponential objects, as applied to a Boolean algebra viewed as a poset category. I suppose it's also an instance of the Curry—Howard correspondence.

More generally, it seems like it isn't such a bad idea to conflate exponentiation and arrows - it looks nicer, to me at least, to write that a function of the type $A \to (B \to C)$ is naturally isomorphic to a function of the type $A \times B \to C$, than to write about $A \to C^B$. Even, as some have suggested, $A \to {}^B C$ or $C^B \leftarrow A$ would look nicer. On the other hand we'd lose the association with cardinal arithmetic if we do this...

Answer (score 9):

If $\mathcal{C}$ is a category and $X,Y\in\mathrm{obj}(\mathcal{C})$, I like the notation $\mathcal{C}(X,Y)$ to denote $\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{C}}(X,Y)$.

So, $\mathcal{C}(X,X)=\mathrm{End}_{\mathcal{C}}(X)$.

What do you think of the notation $\mathcal{C}(X):=\mathrm{Aut}_{\mathcal{C}}(X)$ ?

This would be consistent with the notation (or similar notations) $\mathsf{DIFF}(S^1)$ (resp. $\mathsf{TOP}(S^1)$ ) for diffeomorphisms (resp. homeomorphisms) of the circle, i.e. the $\mathrm{Aut}$ in the category $\mathsf{DIFF}$ of smooth manifolds (resp. $\mathsf{TOP}$ of topological manifolds), sometimes used in topology (see e.g. [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/87681/references-for-the-categories-diff-pl-lip-top) and [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/61601/central-extensions-of-diffs1-and-of-the-semigroup-of-annuli). And (see e.g. [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/106971/homotopy-type-of-top4-pl4)) $\mathsf{TOP}(n)=\mathrm{Aut}_{\mathsf{TOP}}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you've chosen to make your links single letters, instead of pointing them out more explicitly?

Comment: @S. Carnahan: not really... I just wanted the links to be kind of parenthetic references, because those MO pages weren't "standard" definitory places for the notations. If it's considered weird of annoying according to MO netiquette, I'll just edit :)  

Comment: I'm using these notations privately already, especially the $\mathcal{C}(X)$ one and I didn't know there was anyone else doing it! I'd upvote twice if I could!

Comment: I have been using some similar notation for a while too! Just like you do, I wright $\mathcal{C}(X,Y)$ for morphisms, but for monomorphisms I write a "monomorphism arrow" over $\mathcal{C}$, and similarmly for epimorphisms and isomorphisms. For endomorphisms I abbreviate $\mathcal{C}(X)$, and for automorphisms I write $\mathcal{C}(X)$ with a double-sided arrow above the C.

Answer (score 9):

I find 
$$\lim_{x\nearrow0} f(x)$$
$$\lim_{x\searrow0}  f(x)$$
for the limit from below and from above much more intuitive that all other notation I've seen, including $\lim_{x\to 0^-}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)$.

Comment: For $\lim_{x\to0^+}$ or $\lim_{x\searrow0}$ one could almost imagine $\lim_{0\leftarrow x}$... but then $\lim_{x \to0}$ would become ambiguous.

Comment: I have seen $\lim\limits_{x\downarrow 0}$ and $\lim\limits_{x\uparrow 0}$

Comment: @ZachTeitler, obviously the solution is to write $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0 \leftarrow x}$ for the two-sided limit.  :-)

Comment: Obviously, not $\lim_{0 \leftarrow x \rightarrow 0}$, that would be ridiculous... :-)

Comment: I can never get accustomed to these ``\se`` and ``\ne`` arrows for lim. $\uparrow$ and $\downarrow$ are ok. I don't think I have dyslexia, but this example  always makes me unsure.

Answer (score 9):

Forgive me for bumping such an old big-list question, but I can't resist. In linear algebra texts you will sometimes find the notation $[v]_B$ for the vector of coordinates of a vector $v \in V$ with respect to a basis $B$ of $V$, but you will not (to my knowledge) find corresponding notation for the matrix of a linear transformation $T : V \to W$ with respect to two bases $B, C$ of $V$ and $W$, except perhaps in the special case $V = W, B = C$, where I have seen $[T]_B$. The notation I use and advocate for this matrix is

$$_C[T]_B$$

and I taught this in a few [linear algebra classes at UC Berkeley](https://math.berkeley.edu/~qchu/54/Matrices.pdf) as a TA although I don't think it caught on. It has the pleasant property that its definition can be written

$$_C [T]_B [v]_B = [T(v)]_C.$$

This lets us give a transparent proof of the equally pleasant "functoriality" property that if $S : U \to V$ is another linear transformation and $A$ is a basis of $U$ then

$$_C[TS]_A = (_C[T]_B)(_B[S]_A)$$

("the $B$s just cancel"). Try even stating this result without notation for it! The notation makes it hard to misstate the basic facts about how such matrices change upon change of basis etc., because the correct statements "typecheck" properly and you won't be tempted to multiply matrices that haven't been expressed in compatible bases. Although things would be slightly better if either 1) the vector notation were written with the basis on the left or 2) matrices acted on the right and we switched the order of the two bases.

Importantly, the change-of-basis matrix between two bases $B, B'$ can just be written $_B[I]_{B'}$ and all of its properties become obvious (everything follows from "canceling" bases) and easy to remember, including e.g. that $_{B'}[I]_B$ is the inverse matrix and that if $T : V \to V$ is an endomorphism then

$$_{B'}[T]_{B'} = (_{B'} I_B) (_B[T]_B)(_B I_{B'}).$$

$\LaTeX$ balks a bit at the repeated subscripts, though.

(Incidentally, it's annoying that we use "vector" to denote both an "abstract vector" and a "concrete vector" while we have different terms for "linear transformation" and "matrix." Perhaps we should start using something like "array" or "list" or "tuple" to mean a concrete vector.)

Comment: Related: [Notation for change of basis matrix](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/15371/590), where I suggested we adopt the partial derivatives notation for this.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to write $_{C^{-1}}[T]_B$ so that $_B$ and $_C$ could be interpreted as isomorphisms between $V$ and $W$ and $\mathbb R^n$ and $\mathbb R^m$?

Comment: Row vectors should be $[v]_B$, column vectors should be ${}_B[v]$ (or $_{B^{-1}}[v]$ perhaps).

Comment: I wrote $[T]_{C,B}$ in lectures I gave in 2016, and I don't think I invented that notation. It might be in Anton & Rorres, the text I was using at the time.

Comment: Look the notation that is in the following question. I like it very much! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3350974/useful-mathematical-notation

Comment: At the Charles university in Prague a lot of people teach with similar notation. Except they take it one notch further and write it as $[T]^C_B.$  This has the added advantage of exposing students to kind of "Einstein summation notation" common in physics and differential geometry.

Comment: Another advantage is that it allows you to make a clear distinction between vectors $[v]^B$ and forms $[\alpha]_C$ and between linear mappings $[T]^C_B$ and bilinear forms $[T]_{C,B}.$

Comment: @Vit: ah, I might like that even better, thanks! It is actually quite close to Einstein notation.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan You are welcome! (I just noticed another advantage: it's easier to TeX it.)

Comment: The book of Lay, Lay, and McDonald uses the initially awkward notation $[T]_{\mathcal C \leftarrow \mathcal B}$, which is a bit odd at first but works well:  $[T(x)]_{\mathcal C} = [T]_{\mathcal C \leftarrow \mathcal B}[x]_{\mathcal B}$.

Answer (score 8):

If one needs to denote the *fiber* (not the *stalk* which is standardly denoted $\mathcal{F}_{x}$) of a sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ at the closed point $x$ of the $\Bbbk$-scheme $X$, one can write

$\mathcal{F}\mid_{x}$

After all, the fiber $\mathcal{F}\otimes_{\Bbbk}\;\kappa (x)$ *is* the restriction (pullback) of $\mathcal{F}$ to the point $x:\rm{Spec}\;\Bbbk\rightarrow X$.

The problem is that, when you identify vector bundles with locally free sheaves, the above notation clatches with the usual notation $E_x$ for the *fiber* of vector bundles. 
On the other hand almost always the context would be sufficient to clarify which of the two notations is being used.

Comment: In Ravi Vakil's thread on teaching schemes, there was some discussion of using the notation $\mathcal{F}(x)$, since given a section $f$ of the sheaf, its values as a function on $X$ are written $f(x)$ and lie in the fibers.

Comment: It's this answer, and the many, many comments below it: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/28496/what-should-be-learned-in-a-first-serious-schemes-course/28572#28572.  Note that what I wrote is given by BCnrd about halfway down.


Comment: @Ryan: I appreciate the $\mathcal{F}(x)$ notation, but there's a (minor?) clutching with the widely used notation $\mathcal{O}_{X}(x)$ to denote the line bundle on the algebraic curve $X$ twisted by the divisor given by the point $x\in X$. 

Comment: It's true, this notation would lead to the unfortunate equality $\mathcal{O}_X(x) = \mathcal{O}_X/\mathcal{O}_X(-x)$.

Answer (score 8):

- I also like the notation $x \prec y$ to denote [*majorization*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majorization) of a vector $x$ by a vector $y$; once defined, this notation relieves quite lot of burden.
- On a related note, I also prefer the notation $A \succeq 0$ to signify that $A$ is a positive semidefinite matrix (some prefer to use the perhaps "more natural" $A \ge 0$, but since I frequently deal with nonnegative matrices, the $\ge$ is out)

Comment: Unfortunately, "majorization" has at least two different meanings...

Comment: Majorization theory involves also the useful notation $x_\uparrow$ and $x_\downarrow$ for vectors with real entries.

Answer (score 8):

All of the notations created to simplify writing category theory. For instance, the idea of drawing a circular arrow inside of a diagram to indicate that that diagram is commutative.  As well as the idea of putting an angle in the top left or bottom right of a square diagram to indicate that it is a pushout or pullback.  And finally, the notation of augmenting any of these notations with $\simeq$ to indicate that the diagram is only "up to homotopy".

Answer (score 7):

The three-dot notation $f\mathrel{\scriptsize\vdots}A\to B$ to indicate that $f$ is a partial function from $A$ to $B$, meaning that $\text{dom}(f)\subseteq A$ rather than $\text{dom}(f)=A$. Partial functions are pervasive in logic, especially computability theory and set theory, and this notation is both compact and suggestive.

Comment: Joel, do you know who introduced it? I've heard the rumor it was Mathias, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I personally learned it from Mathias, but in another MO
question, I recall that we traced it down to someone else,
but I forgot who...


Comment: How are the three dots to be placed? Like in $\vdots$?

Comment: I use $\rightharpoonup$ for partial functions.

Comment: I once saw a notation for partial functions that I found quite nice: it's an arrow of which the first part looks like a cup (like in the "cup product") and the remaining trait is straight. 

Comment: Thanks, Harald, I used your \vdots idea, reduced in size by \scriptsize and with \mathrel, which looks basically fine.

Comment: Use a broken arrow instead:  f : A - - - > B. I have no idea how three dots is suggestive of the domain being something smaller than A.

Comment: I just meant that it suggests that $f$ is something like a function from A to B, without being intrusive. This notation is really useful in situations where you have numerous partial functions of different arities running around. 

Comment: Are there some books where these notations is used?

Comment: Never saw the three-dot notation. It looks like a smudge or tiny dead gnat to me. I use the notation mentioned by Andreas. 

Comment: I prefer Andreas's notation but have also seen $f :\subseteq A \rightarrow B$ which can be read mnemonically as "f is a function from  a subset of A to B" or "f is a subset of a function from A to B" (this not being strictly true, unless we identify a function with its graph).

Comment: @Max According to set theory, a function *is* its graph.

Comment: @user76284: functions with the same graph but different codomains are usually not identified (otherwise it makes no sense to talk about functions being onto or bijective). Unfortunately introductions to set theory usually *don't* say this leading to confusion later on.

Comment: @Max You say "usually not identified", but this is a practice that varies considerably with subject area. For example, in essentially all of logic, including set theory, computability theory, complexity theory and theoretical computer science, as well as in huge parts of real analysis and essentially all of applied mathematics, your practice is not observed. And despite your remark, I also think there is essentially no confusion, and certainly there is no problem in expressing that a function $f$ is onto a set $B$ or bijective between one set $A$ and another set $B$.

Answer (score 7):

I really like $(-)^n$ instead of $(-1)^n$ for alternating signs in series etc. Its more aesthetic and slightly easier to write. I found it in a 1976 paper about multipolar expansions.

Comment: I have used this in my own personal notes. I've deliberately avoided showing it to many of my pre-calc or calculus students though. They have enough issues with notation as is.

Answer (score 6):

To say that $u$ and $v$ are orthogonal you can spell out "The scalar product of $u$ and $v$ is equal to zero", i.e.:

$\langle u,v \rangle=0$

but you can also use the binary symbol $\perp$ to write the sentence "$u$ orthogonal to $v$" more directly, i.e. $u\perp v$.

Analogously, to say that sets $A$ and $B$ have empty intersection, of course you can spell out "$A$ intersection $B$ equals the empty set", i.e.:

$A \cap B = \emptyset$

> But it would be nice if there was a binary symbol (like a **barred $\cap$ symbol**, not to be confused with the $\pitchfork$ symbol for transversality) to say directly "$A$ does not intersect $B$ (nontrivially)".

I don't think this symbol already exists in LaTeX.

Comment: You could use $\perp$ for that as well...

Comment: I write $A\thinspace )\thinspace(\thinspace B$  for $A\cap B=\emptyset$ and similarly $A\supset\hskip-5pt\subset B$ for $A\cap B\ne\emptyset$.

Comment: Surely you should write $A \supset \subset B$ and not $A)(B$.

Comment: You can use $A \parallel B$ for $A\cap B=\varnothing$, since parallel lines don't meet, and so do disjoint sets.

Comment: @Asaf that metaphor for || doesn't work if A and B are subsets of projective space... SCNR.

Answer (score 6):

Whenever $X$ is a singleton set, denote by $!X$ the unique element in $X$, or put else (assuming some standard material set theory),
$$! \colon \mathrm{Singletons} → \mathrm{Set}$$
is the unique inverse for $\{\,\} \colon \mathrm{Set} → \mathrm{Singletons},~x ↦ \{x\}$. So $!\{x\} = x$ for all things $x$ and $X = \{!X\}$ for all singletons $X$.

This makes it possible to formulaically talk about “*the unique element $x$ such that …*” (which happens a lot) and it fits well with the notation “$∃!$” for saying “*there exists some unique …*”.

For example, one may define the minimal polynomial of an element $α$ in an algebraic field extension $E / F$ as
$$\operatorname{minpol}_F α = ~!\{f ∈ F[X];~\text{$f$ monic, irreducible with $f(α) = 0$}\}.$$

Comment: By the way, I use angle brackets $⟨~⟩$ whenever the curly braces of sets feel awkward, e.g. in the context of defining maps, I’d rather write $$\mathrm{minpol}_F \colon E → F[X],~α ↦ ~!⟨f;~\text{$f$ monic, irreducible with $f(α) = 0$}⟩.$$

Answer (score 5):

For a Lie group $G$ with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, and element $A\in\mathfrak{g}$, denote the left invariant vector field $\overrightarrow{A}(g)=L_{g*} A$, and the right invariant vector field $\overleftarrow{A}(g)=R_{g*}A$. On any matrix group, $\overrightarrow{A}(g)=gA$ and $\overleftarrow{A}(g)=Ag$, easy to remember. The notation uses fewer subscripts than the more common notation $X_A$, which is also not easy to adapt to right versus left invariant vector fields. When discussing group actions, we usually use left actions. The left action of the group on itself is generated by the right invariant vector fields. Some authors use $X_A$ for left invariant vector fields, but also for the generators of any action of the group, which can lead to sign mistakes when discussing the left action of the group on itself.

Comment: The visual asymmetry between the lengths and heights of the arrows $\overleftarrow A$ and $\overrightarrow A$ is a bit unfortunate ….

Answer (score 4):

(This would be a comment on notation for partial functions, but I don't have the reputation points, as I just joined MO.)  Though this is by no means standard, for personal use I've adopted the following system of arrow decorations that captures many standard types of binary relations.  For a relation f from A to B, use $\rightharpoonup$ to indicate $\forall x\in A ~\exists y \in B~~xfy$, $\rightharpoondown$ to indicate $\forall x\in A~\exists^{\leq 1} y\in B~~xfy$, $\leftharpoondown$ to indicate $\forall y\in B~\exists x\in A~~xfy$, and $\leftharpoonup$ to indicate $\forall y\in B~\exists^{\leq 1}x\in A~~xfy$.  So, $\rightarrow$ is for functions, $\leftrightarrow$ is for bijections, $\leftharpoonup\hspace{-1em}\to$ is for injections, $\leftharpoondown\hspace{-1em}\to$ is for surjections, $\rightharpoondown$ is for partial functions, $\rightharpoonup$ is for serial relations, and so on.

Comment: I was sold when I saw the notation for injections, but I'm not so happy with the notation for surjections, as compared to the usual symbol $\twoheadrightarrow$.  There is nothing in that arrow to suggest "surjection" to me.

Comment: Incidentally, this answer also indirectly introduces the notation $\exists^{\le1}$, which has the marvellous virtue that its meaning is so obvious no-one wondered about, or even visibly noticed, it.

Answer (score 4):

Has this already been mentioned?  If a group $G$ acts on a commutative group $A$ by homomorphisms, $G \to Aut(A)$, then use $a^g$ to denote the action. Especially if the group multiplication on $A$ is written multiplicatively, where we can say things like $(ab)^g = a^g b^g$. This can come up especially in Galois theory; I remember Lang using this notation in his Algebra to prove Hilbert's Theorem 90, and I thought it was very neat, and enhanced the readability of notation as well.

Comment: I like this notation for actions in general, but for the particular case of actions on groups written in multiplicative notation, this is quite confusing, as superscripts already denote too many other things in this context. You ruled out conjugation by making the group commutative, but it’s still ambiguous which superscripts in a thing like $(a^kb)^g$ denote action by $G$, and which denote powers with integer exponents.

Comment: @ToddTrimble, I agree with Serre (*Cohomologie Galoisienne*, p. 42):  "Si $s \in G$ et $x \in E$, le transformé $s(x)$ de $x$ par $s$ sera souvent noté ${}^sx$ [mais jamais $x^s$, pour éviter l'horrible formule $x^{(st)} = (x^t)^s$]."  (Nonetheless, Harish Chandra does use your suggestion for the conjugation of a group on itself or its Lie algebra.)

Comment: I use a similar notation for any group action on any set (or structured set); By putting the exponent on the left, one can also distinguish between left- and right-actions. For example the two possibilities for conjugation would be ${^g x} = gxg^{-1}$ and $x^g = g^{-1}xg$. I learned this notation from Burkhard Külshammer.

Answer (score 4):

Round brackets as Cartesian coordinates and square brackets as homogenous coordinates.

I picked this up idea from Needham's *Visual Complex Analysis*, and I'm not sure how commonly it's used elsewhere. In the book, the convention was to use round-bracketed matrices
$$
    \begin{pmatrix}
        a & b \\
        c & d \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
for representing linear transformations, and square-bracketed matrices
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
        a & b \\
        c & d \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
for representing Möbius transformations. More generally, we can let round brackets be for all "ordinary", "Cartesian", "vector"-ish things, and square brackets be for all "projective" or "homogeneous" things. It's useful to be able to tell them apart quickly, as the algebra looks the same but the meaning is very different.

Outside of complex analysis, there's an even plainer context where this convention would help:  computer graphics (a.k.a. the actual "real-life" application of projective geometry). In computer graphics, there are two common ways to think of a point, say, in 2-dimensional space. One way is a pair $(x,y)$, the way people normally think of coordinates. The other way is to add an extra coordinate: $x$ and $y$ along with an extra $1$. This is a practical representation, since it works naturally with affine and projective transformations, which we represent in homogeneous coordinates too. The use of both systems leads to a problem. Without any notational convention, is $(3,-4,1)$  supposed to mean a 2D point or a 3D point? Is
$$
    \begin{bmatrix}
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
    \begin{bmatrix}
        -2 \\
        3 \\
        1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
supposed to be a translation applied to a 2D point, or a shear mapping applied to a 3D point? You need context and you can't tell at a glance. If we used round/square brackets with our designated interpretations, though, we'd know right away that $(3,-4,1)$ means a 3D point and the square-bracketed matrix above means a 2D translation.

Unfortunately, they don't actually make any notational distinction at all in computer graphics. They're just going to stay confused ;) - but you don't have to. You can use the round and square to distinguish ordinary and projective coordinates. It deserves to be more standard.

(There's another convention out there to make the distinction with commas and colons, i.e. $(a,b,c)$ is Cartesian and $(a \mathbin{:} b \mathbin{:} c)$ is homogeneous. It works well for some purposes, but not if you need the notation to generalize to matrices.)

Answer (score 4):

For the value at $x$ of the conditional probability density function of a random variable (capital) $X,$ given the event that the value of a random variable (capital) $Y$ is $y,$ I prefer $f_{X\,\mid\,Y\,=\,y}(x)$ to the more frequently seen $f_{X\,\mid\,Y}(x\mid y).$ It emphasizes that we are concerned with a function of $x.$

Answer (score 3):

The lack of a nice obviously symmetric notation for $\binom{a+b}{b}$ has bothered me; Dijkstra suggested in [EWD 782](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/index07xx.html) the notation $P(a,b)$, generalizing it also to $P(a_1,\ldots,a_k)$ for $\binom{a_1+\ldots+a_k}{a_1,\ldots,a_k}$.  (Though I certainly disagree with him about $\binom{n}{k}$ being useless - you certainly do want to think about it that way a lot of the time.)  I haven't actually had any reason to use this since I saw it but I can certainly think of times I would have.

Also the double-parentheses multichoose notation $\left(\!\binom{n}{k}\!\right)$ is nice because it lets you say "...and this is n multichoose k (which is equal to this binomial coefficient)" instead of just jumping directly to a binomial coefficient whose relevance may not be immediately obvious.  But I suppose that's not really on the level of giving you a better way to look at things.

Comment: Isn't there a nice obviously symmetric notation for ${a+b} \choose b$, namely ${a+b} \choose {a,b}$?

Comment: Oh, true.  That is a good point.  It looks a bit clunky but it works.

Comment: $\left(\!\binom{n}{k}\!\right)$

Comment: is given by \left(\!\binom{n}{k}\!\right)

Comment: $\binom{a+b}{a,b}$ often means something else when $a=b$, namely the number of ways of partitioning $2a$ into two groups of size $a$. Thus $\binom{4}{2,2}$ is $3$ not $6$.

Comment: @Rasmus: Your notation will become a bit less useful once $a$ and $b$ are replaced by more complex terms. In that case Dijkstra's notation is better.

Answer (score 3):

Using $(a, b, ... )$ is handy to denote a *column* vector, which is the transpose of the row vector $[a, b, ... ]$, especially in linear text. Correspondingly, all displayed matrices should be written with brackets, not parentheses. This notation agrees with the usual identification of coordinates with column vectors.

Comment: I take it you also hate having to write the transpose when you're constrained to writing on one line? :)

Comment: Yes, particularly when stacking vectors $a, b, ... $, in which case you have to write the artificial $[a^T, b^T, ... ]^T$ without this convention.

Comment: It is, of course, not $[a, b, \dots]^T$ but $[a\;b\;\dots]^T$.  This is an awful convention because even once you remind yourself why the $T$ is there you (or I at least) am not convinced that it has any meaning other than to satisfy a badly chosen precedent.  I don't know why anyone would vote this down.

Comment: Don't forget the invariant literature which uses $\left[v_1,...,v_n\right]$ not for the matrix formed by the columns $v_1$, ..., $v_n$, but for its determiannt...

Comment: I personally prefer the notation $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$, with commas, or equivalently $(a_1\;a_2\;\ldots\;a_n)^{\mathrm{T}}$ or $[a_1\;a_2\;\ldots\;a_n]^{\mathrm{T}}$ for *column* vectors. And  $(a_1\;a_2\;\ldots\;a_n)$ or $[a_1\;a_2\;\ldots\;a_n]$ for row vectors.

Answer (score 3):

In the notation of [Time scale calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_scale_calculus), the ordinary calculus derivative df/dt and the forward difference operator $\Delta f $ are both written as $f^\Delta$. Indefinite sums and indefinite integrals are both written as $\int{f(t)\Delta t}$ and called indefinite integrals. The context would say $\mathbb{T}=\mathbb{Z}, \mathbb{T}=\mathbb{R}$ or other $\mathbb{T}\subset\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: What do you mean by "indefinite integral"? I used to hear this term referred to the "family of primitives" of a given function, like in: $\int f(x) dx=F(x)+C$

Comment: (btw, it wasn't me to downvote)

Comment: Yes, when the time-scale is the real numbers, the indefinite integral $\int f(t)\Delta t=\int{f(x)dx}=F(x)+C$ and when time=integers, $\int f(t)\Delta t=\Delta^{-1}f(x)=F(x)+C$ (not the same F in each case though of course).

Answer (score 3):

Multi-factorials are handy.  Sometimes results can be expressed compactly by introducing a double factorial or possibly higher factorial. For example

$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^{2n+1} \theta \:\: d\theta = \frac{(2n)!! }{ (2n+1)!!}$$

Comment: I wish there were a notation that didn't scream "iterated factorial", though (not that one sees this very much).  I forget: does $n?$ mean anything?  The question mark is handy because it suggests having to make a choice, as in "even or odd?"

Comment: The question mark has a meaning in C and programming languages derived from C. The notation a ? b : c; means to do b if a is true, otherwise do c.

The question mark also means "optional" in regular expressions. For example, the regular expression ab?c matches abc or ac. 

I don't know whether either of these notations would make sense imported into math.  On a related note, sometimes I would like to import C's % operator into math notation.

Comment: True, but C also doesn't have a factorial operator, and ! means something entirely different again.  There's not much reason to make mathematical notation agree with programming design choices.  As for %, we always have "mod".

Comment: The problem with "mod" is that it is usually an equivalence relation and not a function.  That is, you see "a equiv b mod m" more than "a mod m".  I'm not sure the latter is common notation or that people agree in detail what it means.

Answer (score 3):

I think that Inuit numerals are cool. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inuit_numerals) They are useful for vigesimal type things.

Comment: Now I wonder where in mathematics you would like to do actual vigesimal calculations?

Answer (score 3):

In type theory, the notation $(x : A) \to B (x)$ instead of $\Pi_{x : A} B (x)$ for the dependent product and $(x : A) \times B (x)$ instead of $\Sigma _{x : A} B (x)$ for the dependent sum. For non-type-theorists, a dependent product is a set-indexed product of a collection of sets, and a dependent sum is a set-indexed disjoint union of a collection of sets[1]. The former notation is used in the [Agda](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php), the latter is less widely spread but both are used for example in [cubicaltt](https://github.com/mortberg/cubicaltt). Some advantages of this notation are:

- It is consistent with notation for non-dependent sums and products $A \times B$ and $A \to B$ (the latter is in fact an instance of the third example of good notation given in the original question, and is already widespread among type-theorists as a notation for the set of functions from $A$ to $B$)
- The fact that $A$ does not appear as a subscript certain complex types easier to follow, as in the equation

$$ (x : A) \times ((y : B (x)) \times C (x, y)) \cong (u : (x : A) \times B (x)) \times C (\pi_1 u, \pi_2 u) $$

- The fact that $A$ does not appear as a subscript makes it easier to represent this notation in plaintext, as is frequently done when programming with dependent types.

[1] Here and in the rest of my answer, I am ignoring the distinction between a set and a type.

Answer (score 2):

I use the notation

$V \oplus^{\perp}W$

to denote orthogonal direct sum [Edit: direct sum of, say, subspaces of a given inner-product space].

Or

$(M,g) \times^{\perp} (N,g')$, or simply $M \times^{\perp} N$, to denote (orthogonal) cartesian product of Riemannian manifolds.

Comment: I'd like to know why this was downvoted: you simply don't like the symbol, or there's some deeper reason?

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but I don't like the notation because it is redundant and emphasizes the wrong thing.  For vector spaces, there is no intrinsic inner product with respect to which a direct sum can be either orthogonal or not.  If you have two inner product spaces, then the direct sum is always orthogonal unless specified otherwise, because there is no one way to do it otherwise.  Likewise for the direct product of two manifolds with a Riemannian metric.  It is better to have a notation for when the sum or product is *not* orthogonal, and to specify how.

Comment: I have seen that some authors use the notation  $V\obot W$ for this purpose (provided by mathabx package in latex), see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61882/39306.

Answer (score 2):

Cauchy-Binet as a generalized Pythagoras theorem.

Let $X$ be an $ n \times k$ matrix with $n \ge k$. For any $k$-index
$I=i_1...i_k, \; 1 \le i_1 < ... < i_k \le n$, there is some advantage
to denote by $X_I$, the determinant of the $k \times k$ submatrix of
$X$ with rows indexed by $I$. For any two such $X,Y$, we can state
the Cauchy-Binet formula as a pairing
$$ \det (X^TY)= \sum_{I} X_I Y_I $$ where the sum is over all $n
\choose k$ $k$-indices. This is a Pythagoras theorem for $X=Y$ since
it says that the the volume-squared of the parallelepiped spanned by
the $k$ columns of $X$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is the sum of squares of
the volume of the projections on the $n \choose k$ $k$-dimensional
coordinates.

For any $n \times m$ matrix $A$ with $m,n \ge k$ and $k$ indices
$I,J$, we also denote by $A_{IJ}$ the determinant of the $k \times
k$ submatrix of $A$ with rows indexed by $I$ and column indexed by
$J$. Then for $X(m \times k)$ and $Y(n \times k)$, we have by
Cauchy-Binet twice,
$$ \det(X^TAY)=\det(X^T(AY))=\sum_{I}X_I(AY)_I =\sum_I X_I \det(A^IY)=\sum_I X_I \sum_J A_{IJ} Y_J,$$
where $A^I$ is the $k \times n$ matrix given by the rows of $A$
indexed by $I$ and we note that $(AY)_I= \det(A^IY)$ and
$(A^I)^T_J=A_{IJ}$. This notation thus allows us to view
Cauchy-Binet (usually stated with $m=n,A=I$) as an extension of the
usual $x^TAy=\sum_{ij}A_{ij}x_iy_j$ for $k=1$.

Comment: This is not really about notation, but it's a very good point.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of writing 
$$|x-y|\le \varepsilon,$$
I used to write 
$$x\lessgtr y\pm \varepsilon.$$
You may read it as $x$ is more-or-less $y$ plus-minus $\varepsilon$.

One may also write something like 
$$x\lessgtr e^{\pm\varepsilon}\cdot y$$
which is much better than
$$|\ln(y/x)|\le\varepsilon$$

It is easier to read, 
especially if instead of $x$ and $y$  you have long expressions.

Comment: What would you write for $|x-y|\geq \epsilon$?

Comment: You often need to say that two values are close. I do not see a place where you need values which are far, but in principle you could write 
$x\lessgtr y\mp \varepsilon$

Comment: I'm not happy about the "principle" in Anton's reply to Nate's comment.  In the body of the question, the upper inequality (with $<$ and $+\varepsilon$) and the lower inequality (with $>$ and $-\varepsilon$) are to be understood as combined by "and", whereas in the comment, the upper and lower inequalities are intended to be combined by "or".  Allowing both uses of the notation seems to be inviting confusion.

Comment: Andreas, you are right, I made this reply without much thinking :)

Comment: Actually, I like $x =^\epsilon y$ for this concept.

Comment: With a better TeX intepreter, I would actually stack the $\epsilon$ right on top of the $=$.

Comment: @Lee, imagine that it is not $\varepsilon$, but 
$$10\cdot\varepsilon\cdot\delta^{1/10}.$$
You do not want to put it over or under!!!

Comment: @AntonPetrunin, this does not seem so good if $x$ and $y$ are complex.

Comment: @LeeMosher, as a $p$-adic analyst I like this, but surely those poor folks for whom $=^\epsilon$ is not transitive will not be so happy.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

I find the standard notation $X \times_G Y := \frac{X \times Y}{G}$ for balanced products of $G$-spaces annoying, because it conflicts with the well-established notation for fibre products. But on the other hand writing out the full quotient $(X \times Y)/G$ is cumbersome, especially if you're dealing with associated bundles to principal bundles, or if you have spaces with compatible left and right actions of different groups, and you need to write something like $X \times_G Y \times_H Z$.

So I came up with that following notation which combines the product symbol "$\times$" and the quotient symbol "$\_$" into a single binary symbol:
[image]

The last one, without the group decorating it, is used in the same way as tensor products $\otimes$ when the ring involved is obvious (e.g. if you're working with associated bundles to a $G$-principal bundle $P$, and you're not planning on taking any reductions of the structure group).

It's just a rotated semidirect product, so it's easy to implement in LaTeX, and looks similar enough to the usual notation that it's easy to introduce in a talk. Here's my LaTeX code:

[image]

Comment: I learned from Indranil Biswas to use $X \times^G Y$ for $(X \times Y)/G$. I think this notation is becoming standard.

Comment: I also think the notation $X\times^G Y$ is the standard one.

Comment: Unfortunately not standard in differential geometry yet---everywhere I look people are still using the ambiguous fibre-product notation.

Answer (score 2):

In computations in differential geometry, when we need to omit one entry of a list, I like to write $x^{\hat\imath}$ instead of $(x_1,\dots,\hat{x}_i,\dots,x_n)$, and similarly write $x_{\hat\imath}$ instead of $(x^1,\dots,\hat{x}^i,\dots,x^n)$. This makes the Einstein convention work, and simplifies the computations of relations between exterior and Lie derivatives of differential forms, for example. Similarly, $x^{\widehat{\imath\jmath}}$ to omit two entries. Careful that $x^{\hat\imath\hat\jmath}\ne x^{\widehat{\imath\jmath}}$

Comment: Is $x^{\hat\imath\hat\jmath} \ne x^{\widehat{\imath\jmath}}$ because of the index shift, e.g., starting with $x = (x_1, x_2, x_3)$, we get $x^{\hat1\hat2} = (x_2)$ but $x^{\widehat{12}} = (x_3)$?  Could this be remedied simply by not shifting the indexing, so that, e.g., we still call $x_2$ the $2$nd (not the $1$st) entry of $x^{\hat1} = (x_2, x_3)$, or does that come with separate disadvantages?

Comment: @LSpice: exactly the problem; I am not sure what would be the best approach, thinking of sign problems that arise when we work with permutations of vectors entering differential forms.

Comment: I don't know how it'll work for you, but I've often found it helpful explicitly to "reify" the indexing.  That is, an element $x \in \mathbb R^n$ isn't just an $n$-tuple, but a function $\{1, \dotsc, n\} \to \mathbb R$; so, for $x \in \mathbb R^3$, we have that $x^{\hat2}$, though a $2$-tuple, is not a function $\{1, 2\} \to \mathbb R$ but a function $\{1, 3\} \to \mathbb R$.  (This convention works best if, for natural $n$, you let $n$ stand for $\{0, \dotsc, n - 1\}$, so that $\mathbb R^n$ becomes literally a function space … but $0$-based indexing confuses many!)

Answer (score 2):

***UMBRAL NOTATION*** (courtesy of Blissard)

$$(q.)^n = q_n$$

Concise, elegant, and suggestive, it often allows for both brevity and comprehensibility of presentation and short derivations of operational results.

***Examples of umbral variables***:

$q.^n = q_n = d$, a constant quantity, maybe a single variable or polynomial,

$q.^n = q_n = d^n $, a constant quantity raised to powers,

$q.^n = q_n = x^n$, a variable raised to a power,

$q.^n = b.^n = b_n$; an element of a sequence of numbers, such as the Bernoulli,

$q.^n = B.(x)^n = B_n(x)$, an element of a sequence of polynomials, .e.g., Bernoulli,

$q.^n = (.)!^n = (n)!$, an expression containing an integer parameter,

$q.^n = \binom{x}{.}^n = \binom{x}{n} $, ditto,

$q.^n = M.^n = M_n$, a sequence of matrices, differential ops, ... whatever.

***The umbral maneuver in more complex expressions***:

1. reduce an expression that contains the umbral entity to an analytic series in monomial powers of $q.$ when possible
2. then lower the positive integer exponent to a subscript
3. when in doubt apply

$$e^{q.xD_y} \; f(y) \; |_{y=0} = f(q.x +y) \;|_{y=0} = f(q.x) \;$$

4. sensible results can often be obtained for functions not analytic at the origin from

$$f(q.x) := e^{-(1-q.)x D_y} \; f(y) \; |_{y=x} = f(x-(1-q.)x) = f((1-(1-q.))x) $$

(See below on Newton interpolation. E.g., with $f(x)=x^s$, then $f(q.x) = (q.x)^s = q_s\; x^s \; := (1-(1-q.))^sx^s \; $ when convergent.)

***Basic umbral operations***:

1. binomial convolution for commuting quantities:

$$c_n = c.^n = (a. + b.)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \; a.^k \; b.^{n-k} = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \; a_k\; b_{n-k},$$

2. formation of e.g.f.s and o.g.f.s:

$$E(t) = e^{q.t} = \sum_{n \geq 0} \; q.^n \; \frac{t^n}{n!} = \sum_{n \geq 0} \; q_n \; \frac{t^n}{n!}$$

and, with $q_0 =1$,

$$O(t) = \frac{1}{1-q.t} = \sum_{n \geq 0} (q.t)^n = \sum_{n \geq 0} q_n \; t^n = e^{\bar{q}.t}= \bar{O}(t)$$

with $\bar{q}_n = n! \; q_n$.

Then multiplication of formal series is

$$EA(t) \; EB(t) = e^{a.t} \; e^{b.t} =  e^{(a.+b.)t} = e^{c.t} = EC(t) \; .$$

We can even disregard convergence of both series if we are interested only in formal compositional or multiplicative inverses or the formal Laplace transform of an e.g.f. to an o.g.f. since the production of the $n$-th coefficient of the target series depends only on the coefficients of order $n$ or less of the source series for these transformations.

***Brevity and intelligibility in umbral versus conventional presentations***:

The Euler transformation for e.g.f.s in umbral notation

1. $$ e^{a.x} =   e^x \; e^{-(1-a. )x}$$

versus conventional notation

2. $$ \sum_{n \geq 0} a_n \; \frac{x^n}{n!} = e^x \; \sum_{n \geq 0} (-1)^n \; [\;  \sum_{k=0}^n \; (-1)^k \; \binom{n}{k} \; a_k \; ] \; \frac{x^n}{n!} \; ,$$

and derivation of the conventional formula via the umbral,

3. $$ e^{a.x} = e^x \; e^{-x} e^{a.x} =  e^x \; e^{-(1-a. )x}$$

$$ = e^x \; \sum_{n \geq 0} (-1)^n \; (1-a.)^n \; \frac{x^n}{n!} = e^x \; \sum_{n \geq 0} \; (-1)^n \; [\;  \sum_{k=0}^n \; (-1)^k \; \binom{n}{k} a_k \; ] \; \frac{x^n}{n!} \;.$$

(23 keys tapped for eqn. 1 versus 102 keys for 2, not counting the appreciable difference in taps for blank spacing and latex spacing for readability. I could have saved a good fraction of a lifetime of math work by being able to use umbral notation in symbolic apps, study, and publications rather than sigma gymnastics.)

***Natural generalizations via umbralization--monic to partition polynomials:***

Stirling polynomials of the first kind, related to cyclic permutations, have the e.g.f.

$$e^{St1.(x)t}  = e^{x \ln(1+t)} = (1+t)^x\; ,$$

and Stirling polynomials of the second kind, related to partitions of sets,

$$e^{St2.(x)t}  = e^{x (e^t-1)} \, .$$

Flexibility and precision is afforded if some notation is used to indicate at what level the umbral exponent lowering is to occur. For example, with $\langle \cdots \rangle$ denoting evaluation of the expression between the angular brackets after reduction to a series in the umbral quantity and with $q_0=1$,

$$\langle \; e^{-\ln(1-q.t)} \;\rangle = \langle \frac{1}{1-q.t}\rangle =  \langle \sum_{n \geq 0} q.^n \; t^n \; \rangle = \sum_{n\geq 0} \langle q.^n \rangle \; t^n =\sum_{n \geq 0} q_n \; t^n $$

and

$$e^{-\langle \ln(1-q.t)\rangle} = \exp[\langle \sum_{n \geq 1} q.^n \frac{t^n}{n}\rangle] = \exp(\sum_{n \geq 1} q_n \frac{t^n}{n}) ,$$

which is the e.g.f. for the cycle index partition polynomials of the symmetric groups, a.k.a. the Stirling partition polynomials of the first kind, OEIS [A036039](https://oeis.org/A036039).

The natural generalization of the Stirling polynomials of the second kind is via the umbralization, for $q_0 = 1$,

$$e^{\langle e^{q.t}-1 \rangle} =  \exp[ \; \sum_{n \ge 1} \; q_n \frac{t^n}{n!} \; ], $$

giving the complete Bell polynomials of the Faa di Bruno composition formula, a.k.a. the Stirling partition polynomials of the second kind, [A036040](https://oeis.org/A036040).

Including an extra variable as in

$$e^{x\langle e^{q.t}-1 \rangle} = e^{Bell.(q_1,..,q.;x)t}$$

and

$$e^{-x\langle\ln(1-q.t)\rangle} = e^{Cyc.(q_1,..,q.;x)t}$$

allows better tracking of block sizes and combinatorics within each partition polynomial. (Note $q_n$ could be a commuting sequence of wedge products, curvature forms, or matrices, just as well as integers, giving basic formulas for the Chern and Pontryagin characteristic class polynomials.)

Now for a little umbral mojo,

$$ e^{St1.(St2.(x)) \; t} = e^{St2.(x) \; \ln(1+t)}=e^{x \; (\exp(\ln(1+t))-1)} = e^{xt} \; ,$$

so the two sets of binomial Sheffer polynomial sequences are an inverse pair under umbral composition; i.e.,

$$St1_n(St2.(x)) = x^n = St2_n(St1.(x)) \; .$$

This is reflected in their lower triangular coefficient matrices being a matrix inverse pair. The same umbral compositional inverse and matrix relationships hold for any Sheffer polynomial sequence. For a pair of inverse/reciprocal Appell Sheffer sequences, this is due to their moment e.g.f.s being multiplicative inverses rather than compositional inverse. The generic Sheffer sequence has a mix of these conditions, belonging to the semidirect product of the Appell and binomial Sheffer subgroups.

***Actions of diff op often become more transparent with umbral calculus and/or underlying combinatorics are revealed***:

With $a.$ treated as independent of $x$ and $D = d/dx$ for $f(x)= e^{b.x}$,

$$e^{a.D_x} \; f(x) = f(a.+x) = e^{b.(a.+x)}.$$

For the Bernoulli number and polynomials (or any Appell Sheffer sequence),

$B_n(x) = e^{b.D} \; x^n =  (b.+x)^n$,

$D \; B_n(x) = D \; (b.+x)^n = n \; (b.+x)^{n-1} = n \; B_{n-1}(x)$

$e^{a.D} \; B_n(x) = B(x + a.) = (x+b.+a.)^n = (B.(x)+a.)^n = (B.(a.)+x)^n \; .$

Adopt the additional notational convenience $(:AB:)^n := A^nB^n$. Alternatively, we could use $q.^n = q_n = A^nB^n$, but this would veil aspects/intuitions inherited from the properties of the derivative.

From our previous feat of umbral mojo,

$$St1_n(xD) = n! \; \binom{xD}{n} = ST1_n(ST2.(:xD:) = \; :xD:^n \; = x^nD^n,$$

consistent with the actions

$xD \; [x^n] = n x^n$,

$(1 + a.)^{xD} \; [x^n] = (1 + a.)^{n} \; x^n$,

and

$(1 + a.)^{xD} \; f(x) = \sum_{n \geq 0} a_n \; \binom{xD}{n} \; f(x) =  e^{a.:xD:} \; f(x) = f((1+a.)x).$

The operational definition of the Stirling polynomials of the second kind is

$$(xD)^n = (St2.(:xD:))^n =  St2_n(:xD:).$$

From this the e.g.f. given above for the polynomials can easily be derived, and, consequently,

$$e^{txD} \; f(x) = e^{t \; St2.(:xD:)} \; f(x) = e^{(e^t-1):xD:} \; f(x)$$

$$ =f((e^t-1)x + x) = f(e^t x),$$

a dilation, consistent with $e^{txD} \; x^n = e^{tn} \; x^n$.

The Lah polynomials $L_n(x)$ (the normalized, unsigned Laguerre polynomials of order -1, related to partitions of sets into ordered sets or lists) have several useful Stokes-Rodrigues diff op reps,

$$ x \; :Dx:^n  \; x^{-1} = x \; D^n x^n x^{-1} = x^{-n+1} (xDx)^n x^{-1} = x^{-n} (x^2D)^n =  L_n(:xD:) ,$$

and the e.g.f.

$$e^{L.(x)t} = e^{x \frac{t}{1-t}},$$

so

$$ e^{tx^2D} \; f(x) = e^{t \; :xL.(:xD:):} \; f(x) = e^{:\frac{tx^2}{1-tx}D:} \; f(x)$$

$$= f(\frac{tx^2}{1-tx} + x) = f(\frac{x}{1-tx}), $$

a special linear fractional, or Moebius, transformation.

(The inverse ops to the translation, $e^{tD}$; dilation, $e^{txD}$; and special linear fractional, $e^{tx^2D}$, transformations of SL2 are given by negating $t$, which is equivalent to additive ($t+(-t)=0$), multiplicative ($e^t \cdot 1/e^t =1$), and compositional inversion ($\frac{x}{1-tx}|_{x \to\frac{x}{1+tx}}=x$), respectively. SL2 becomes associated to the underlying combinatorics of the binomial Sheffer polynomials $St2_n(x)$ and $L_n(x)$ via the umbral symbolic calculus.)

***Interpolation methods and results of integral transforms are naturally suggested and expressed in umbral notation***:

Laplace transform of e.g.f. to o.g.f.s with $q_0=1$:

$$\int_{0}^\infty \; e^{q.xt} \; e^{-t} dt = \int_{0}^\infty \;  e^{-t(1-q.x)} dt = \frac{1}{1-q.x}$$

Mellin transform interpolation to continuous indices (related to Ramanujan's master formula, e.g., the Bernoulli polynomials are essentially discrete samples of the Hurwitz zeta function):

$$ q_{-s} = (q.)^{-s} := \int_{0}^\infty \; e^{-q.t} \; \frac{t^{s-1}}{(s-1)!} \; dt$$

Newton interpolation to continuous indices:

$$q_s = (q.)^s = (1-(1-q.))^s = \sum_{m=0}^\infty \; (-1)^m \; \binom{s}{m} \;\sum_{k=0}^m \; (-1)^k \; \binom{m}{k} \; q_k$$

$$= \int_{0}^\infty \; e^{-(1-(1-q.))t} \; \frac{t^{-s-1}}{(-s-1)!} \; dt= \int_{0}^\infty \; e^{-t} \; e^{(1-q.)t} \; \frac{t^{-s-1}}{(-s-1)!} \; dt$$

$$= \int_{0}^\infty \; e^{-q.t} \; \frac{t^{-s-1}}{(-s-1)!} \; dt$$

via analytic continuation. If $q_n = D_x^n$, the action of the integral on $H(x) \frac{x^\alpha}{\alpha!}$, where $H(x)$ is the Heaviside step function, gives a classic fractional calculus in terms of an analytically-continued (AC) Mellin convolution (essentially that for the AC Euler beta function integral) for the interpretation of $D_x^{s}$ for real or complex $s$.

See Boole, Blissard, Sylvester, Cayley, Appell, (Jensen?), Heaviside, Steffensen, Sheffer, Pincherle, Bell, Riordan, Rota, Taylor, Roman, Ray, and Lenart for contributions to and influences on the development of the umbral symbolic calculus.

Answer (score 2):

When I teach topology, I write $A\stackrel{\textrm{o}}{\subset} X$ to mean that A is an open subset of the topological space $X$, and I write $A \sqsubset X$ to mean that $A$ is a closed subset of $X$. I think it would drive me crazy to write the words open and closed constantly.

Comment: I believe this notation (or something similar) is due to Chan-Ho Suh, who used it in his homework in a course Marshall Cohen taught at Cornell, and then Marshall started using it in his classes.

Comment: One could do something more symmetrical for closed sets, like $A\stackrel{\textrm{c}}{\subset} X$, but I suspect it would be easy to mistake c for o or vice versa, maybe especially in handwriting.

Comment: Personally I put a small circle / small diagonal dash on the lower bar of the $\subset$ to denote an open / closed subset. One can do the same for inclusion maps $\hookrightarrow$, this is a relatively common notation in algebraic geometry for open / closed immersions.

Answer (score 2):

To resolve the ambiguity when using multiple instances of $\pm$ within a single expression, I use  $\pm_n$ and $\mp_n$. $\pm_a$ must be equal to $\pm_b$ iff $a=b$.

Answer (score 2):

Since this one is on the front page again: In my personal notes, I have started writing sums/integrals over complicated index sets as $\sum \left( \text{summand} \mid \text{condition} \right)$, rather than a subscript. EG
$$\sum {\large (} \log p \mid p \ \text{prime}, p \equiv 1 \bmod 4,\ p \leq N {\large )}$$
instead of
$$\sum_{\substack{p \ \text{prime} \\ p \equiv 1 \bmod 4 \\ p \leq N}} \log p.$$

I find it a lot more readable. Additional benefits (1) it is reminiscent of set builder notation like $\{  \log p \mid p \ \text{prime}, p \equiv 1 \bmod 4,\ p \leq N \}$ (2) it means that the pairing between differential forms and cycles actually looks like a bilinear pairing.

Answer (score 1):

In algebra, it is very useful to write $J\cap A$ for the inverse image of an ideal $J$ in a ring $B$ under a homomorphism $f:A\to B$, rather than $f^{-1}(J)$. I normally also omit the morphism and write $IB$ for the ideal generated by the image in $B$ of an ideal $I$ in $A$, rather than $f(I)B$.

Answer (score 1):

Many textbooks say that the normal distribution is the one whose density is
$$
x\mapsto \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}} \times \frac1\sigma \exp\left( -\frac12 \left( \frac{x-\mu}\sigma \right)^2 \right)
$$
and the gamma distribution is the one whose density is
$$
x\mapsto \frac1{\Gamma(\alpha)} \times \lambda^\alpha x^{\alpha-1} e^{-\lambda x} \text{ for } x>0$$
and the Pareto distribution is the one whose density is
$$
x\mapsto \frac{\alpha\kappa^\alpha}{x^{\alpha+1}} \text{ for } x>\kappa
$$
etc.

I prefer to say that the normal distribution is
$$
\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}} \times \exp\left( -\frac12\left( \frac{x-\mu}\sigma\right)^2 \right)\, \frac{dx}\sigma
$$
and the gamma distribution is
$$
\frac1{\Gamma(\alpha)} \times (\lambda x)^{\alpha-1} e^{-\lambda x} (\lambda \, dx) \text{ for } x>0
$$
and the Pareto distribution is
$$
\frac\alpha{(x/\kappa)^{\alpha+1}} \, \frac{dx}\kappa \text{ for } x>\kappa,
$$
and so on.

This shows that each scale parameter, or its reciprocal, the rate parameter or intensity parameter, goes with an $\text{“} x\text{,”}$ and suggests a substitution to be used when thinking about integrating.

Answer (score 0):

I recently saw the following notation in the context of divisors on algebraic varieties, and I liked it very much.

Suppose that $D$ and $E$ are reduced divisors on a normal algebraic variety $X$.  One can use $D \vee E$ to denote the reduced divisor with support equal to $D + E$ and $D \wedge E$ to denote $(D + E) - (D \vee E)$.  I could imagine variants on this if $D$ and $E$ are non-reduced (involving taking max's, respecitvely mins, of the divisors component-wise).

**EDIT:**  I'm slightly curious as to why this was downvoted.  I guess it's too common to be interesting?

Comment: It is not me , I do not know algebraic variety, but as a guess may be there is some order there and so you have an inf and sup or even a lattice that would fully justify these notation and be rather common at that.

Answer (score 0):

> Has anyone come across any more
>   similar examples of good notation that
>   should be better known?

Some interesting glyphs:

1. Combinatorial Principles in Set Theory:

   - ♣ ([Clubsuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clubsuit))
   - ◊ ([Diamondsuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamondsuit))
2. Bisimulation:

   - Given two states p and q in S, p is [bisimilar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisimulation) to q, written p ~ 
     q, if there is a bisimulation R such
     that (p,q) is in R.
3. Boxplus operator in Coding Theory

   - ⊞

Comment: I always considered 1. to be a prototypical example of *bad* notation.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek, I think that (2) has to be a still more prototypical example, in the sense that, without additional context, no two people will agree which equivalence relation is denoted by $\sim$ (although I guess we all agree it *is* an equivalence relation?).

Answer (score 0):

I like the notation $A\mathrel{\in\in}\mathcal C$ for objects (rather than morphisms) in a category (not my own invention).

Comment: It looks like a typo.

Answer (score 0):

The notation of $u \mathbin{[\wedge]} v$ for the product of Lie-algebra valued differential forms (I prefer this to another variant  $[u \wedge v]$).

Writing the tangent natural tranformation as $\tau: T \rightarrow \operatorname{Id}$ which expands to $\tau_M : TM \rightarrow M$.

I've seen some category theorists write $\operatorname{Hom}_A[a,b]$ for the homset for a category $A$, which gets a bit long-winded when $A$ is a category with a long name like $\mathrm{Ring}$ or $R\text-\mathrm{Mod}$. It seems much more natural to write $A[a,b]$.

Personally, I like $\bar{\mathbb{R}}$ to write the order completions of the reals. It's less clumsy than $\mathbb{R} \cup \infty$.

Comment: Unfortunately, $u [\wedge] v$ `u [\wedge] v` by itself doesn't space well; you have to manually tell TeX you've still got a binary operator with $u \mathbin{[\wedge]} v$ `u \mathbin{[\wedge]} v`.  I edited accordingly.

Answer (score -2):

Many years ago, I invented the notation $\mathcal{Lex}_{T}(X)$ as the function equal to $1$ if and only if the consideration of $X$ in the theory $T$ entails no contradiction and $0$ otherwise. Lex is both  "law" in Latin and a shortcut for "Logical existence", which in some sense is the only law of mathematics.

Comment: Why the down vote? Could someone familiar with the subject please explain.

Comment: I'm afraid nobody works on this. I got interested in the subject more than 15 years ago,  after a friend of mine starting to study maths told me something like "the integers of the empty set are even" and "the integers of the empty set are odd" were both equally true. I felt shocked and tried to figure out a way to forbid the consideration of "integers of the empty set" and other impossible concepts.

Comment: Isn't this [just](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency#Basic_results) $\operatorname{Con}(T \cup \{X\})$ or am I misinterpreting?

Comment: It seems $\operatorname{Con}$ is a unary predicate, while $\mathcal{Lex}$ is a map with values in $\{0,1\}$. But otherwise, the idea is the same.

Answer (score -3):

I like the notation $f:A\cong\subseteq B$ for "$f$ is an embedding of $A$ into $B$."  The idea is that the relation of embeddability is obtained by composing the relations "isomorphic to" and "substructure of."

Comment: Hmm, others seem to disagree. What do you think of $\hookrightarrow$?

Comment: @David: I tend to use $\hookrightarrow$ for maps that are literally inclusions.  

Comment: I've mostly seen people use $\subset$ or $\subseteq$ for literal inclusions and $\hookrightarrow$ for embeddings (or whatever kind of injection is suitable). Reserving $\hookrightarrow$ for literal inclusions seems kind of pointless when $\subset$ exists.

Comment: ... and then you can decorate the arrow with o or | to incorporate meaning like "open immersion" or "closed immersion".

Comment: @KonradVoelkel, you use $\overset|\hookrightarrow$ for a closed immersion?  Is that standard?

Answer (score -3):

$x\gtrless 0$ to denote that $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$. Or, if $x\notin\mathbb{R}$ but rather $x\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$ for example, then we write $x\in\mathbb{Z}_{\gtrless 0}$. I prefer the $\gtrless$ notation because it is simpler and more understandable when first met with the eye, and I hope it is set in stone sooner or later.

I also came across the following notation: $$\sum_p'f(x).$$ The little dash $'$ on top of the sigma $\Sigma$ denotes that $p$ is prime. I like this, but I don't feel this is necessary because we can write $$\sum_{p \ \text{prime}}f(x)$$ but when looking at both conventions, the former looks a lot neater.

Also, we have notation $>$, $\gg$ and $\ggg$ with $<$, $\ll$, and $\lll$ but I was thinking, *is there a notation to denote that a value $a$ is not much less than a value $b$?* I came up with $$a\overline{<} b\tag*{$a$ is not much less than $b$}$$ $$a\overline{>}b\tag*{$a$ is not much greater than $b$}$$

I have also seen that the symbol for *concatenation* is sometimes $||$, but if I was to see $$A \ || \ B$$ then my first thought would be *$A$ is parallel to $B$*, but that is just me. With some research, I discovered that there is however *some* kind of official notation, such that $A^\frown B$ but I don't like it.

I also went extreme and invented this: $$\mathop{\LARGE\Omega}_{\substack{x=k \\ \\ R}}^{x_0} (x, y)$$ to define a set of coordinates; a *relation*. Here, $x\to x_0$ and $R$ simply denotes the rule, $y = \cdots$. This way, we can write stuff like $$\mathop{\LARGE\Omega}_{\substack{x=36 \\ \\ y = 2x+1}}^{144}(x, y)$$ And then if we don't have a rule, but something like $y\geq0$ for example, then we can write a double index to refer to what value $y$ tends towards, namely $y_0$.

Oh and I almost forgot, I thought that maybe we can symbolise *contradiction*? For instance, I want to prove that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational. I would first suppose it *is* rational, then come to a conclusion that contradicts this statement. Since most of us use $\Box$ in notation of completing a proof, I decided that I could use $\Diamond$ in notation of a contradiction. I thought about it because it is like a titled box $-$ a bit like approaching the proof $\Box$ on a different angle $\Diamond$, if you get what I am saying.

I am not taking this too seriously, for I was just being creative, but I believe there's nothing wrong in trying new things out. Any thoughts?

Comment: Re: your second-to-last paragraph, there are multiple symbols used for proof-by-contradiction - my personal favorite being "$\perp$," but "$\Rightarrow\Leftarrow$" is also common, as is some form of "lightning bolt." I would strongly object to "$\Diamond$," however, given the meaning of $\Diamond$ and $\Box$ in modal logic.

Comment: Is your $\Omega$ thing any different than $ \{(x,y) \colon 36 \leq x \leq 144, y=2x+1\}$?

Comment: @ZachTeitler nah, it's the same thing. The $\Omega$ thing is easier to write, but the "normal way of writing it" is easier to read ;)

Comment: Instead of typing `A\ ||\ B` so that you see $A\ ||\ B,$ if you type `A\parallel B` then you see $A\parallel B.$ Is there anyone to whom that doesn't look better?