# Usefulness of symbolic devices

Tags: big-picture

Each mathematician knows that  good notation or symbolism – which seems to be irrelevant from a purely logical point of view – makes theorems more plausible  and motivates results which would otherwise be overlooked.   Examples abound. Let me only mention such diverse things as decimal notation, $B^A$ for the set of mappings from $A$ to $B$, $\frac{{df}}{{dx}}$ for differentiation, commutative diagrams, umbral calculus, etc. 
I would be interested in a list of examples of the most useful notations or symbolic devices  together with hints for the reason of their usefulness.

Comment: A related MO question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/42929/suggestions-for-good-notation

Comment: Is the other MO question essentially a duplicate or is there a different focus here? 

Answer (score 5):

Group conjugation: $a^b$ means $b^{-1}ab$, so $(a^b)^c$ is $a^{bc}$ and $(a^b)^{-1}$ is $(a^{-1})^b$.

Answer (score 4):

I really like the multi-index notation for derivatives which is quite often found in the theory of PDEs.

$D^\alpha f = \frac{\partial^{\vert\alpha\vert} f}{\partial x_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots\partial x_n^{\alpha_n}}$

Where $\alpha$ is defined as:

$\alpha = (\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_n),$
$\vert \alpha\vert = \alpha_1 + \cdots +\alpha_n$

It makes definining Sobolev Spaces (and their corresponding Norms) so much cleaner and straight forward:

$W^{k,p} = \lbrace f\in L^p : D^\alpha f\in L^p \text{ for all } \vert\alpha\vert \le k \rbrace$

Comment: I was going to mention the differential operator D used in ODEs.  So, for example, $Dy=\frac{d}{dx}y$.  I originally thought it was a useless notation, until I realized that it greatly simplified things.  For example, $(D^4+4D^3+6D^2+4D+5)y=0$ is difficult to solve until you express it as $(D^2+1)(D^2+4D+5)y=0$.

Answer (score 1):

For certain problems, suppression of a common entity or entry and making it understood by other means.  For a lecture involving manipulation of some algebra (ternary groups, maybe?) a form similar to matrix multiplication was used.  Instead of spelling out the matrices with all the entries, those entries that were zero were omitted, giving a more eye-friendly appearence.  I (and many others, I'm sure) use it for small incidence matrices which are not very dense; the symmetry and other relationships seem much more obvious without the clutter of zeroes.  And this is just one example of many.

Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.09.13