# References for the categories: DIFF PL LIP TOP

Tags: reference-request, gt.geometric-topology

Is there any survey paper focusing on the study of DIFF PL LIP TOP categories?

Comment: You might try poking around Ranicki’s website. I am sure their is some material on the categories above. http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/

Comment: What aspects are you looking for? 

Comment: Basic introductions, like differences, examples and open problems list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I learnt of much of their properties when looking at the stuff on microbundles. A very clear source for lots of that is J. Lurie, Spring 2009, Topics in Geometric Topology (18.937) , notes for course 18.937.  Look on Jacob's website and you will find the course notes. After that look back at the Haupvermutung book.

http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/books/haupt.pdf

For the open problems I have not that long ago seen a list from the topology atlas:

http://at.yorku.ca/list/qa.htm

I hope this helps.